# Hitting 495 (Kaprekar)

Tags: code-golf, repeated-transformation

**Input**:

A three digit number

- from stdin or as an argument
- not all digits are the same
- may start with one or two zero's

**Process**

Order the input-digits ascending and descending to form two new numbers.
Subtract the smallest from the largest. Use the difference as new input. NB: This process needs 3 digits, so 10 has to be returned, or taken care of, as 010.

Repeat this process (Kaprekar transformation) until you hit [495](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/495_%28number%29).

**Output**:
The number of steps it took to reach 495.

Example:

Input: 211

```
211 – 112 = 099
990 – 099 = 891 (rather than 99 - 99 = 0)
981 – 189 = 792
972 – 279 = 693
963 – 369 = 594
954 − 459 = 495
```

Output: 6

Comment: May I assume, that the input doesn't consists of three identical digits like in 111 or 222?

Comment: Yes (second bullet: not all digits are the same).

Comment: Complete set of test cases: http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/CG1255/testcases.txt

Comment: Warning: in some programming languages (e.g. JavaScript), numbers starting with zeros (e.g. `077`) are parsed as octals if you're not careful.

Comment: I realize this question might come in a bit late in the game, but... what are we expected to return for 495 itself? 0, 1, any?

Comment: @J B Joey's test set has it as 0; I think he's right.

Comment: @JB: I interpreted »the number of steps it took to reach 495« in that way that if you start with 495 you are already there without executing the algorithm. Might be debatable but arguably it makes the task more interesting since you have to handle one special case.

Comment: @Joey: well it's only a special case for the pattern lookup family of algorithms ;) But originally that's precisely why I asked, seing many "495"s pop up in the answers. I'd go for 0 spontaneously myself as well.

Comment: steenslag: Again, I do appreciate the accepted answer, but I consider it ill-placed. Since this is a code golf there exists an objective measure of a winning answer and that should be the accepted one. I cannot move the checkmark, though.

Comment: @Joey: OK. it's gone to the Golfscript solution.

Comment: Even more interesting question is - why does it always converge to 495?

Comment: I looked at the description and at the wikipedia page, what happens if its a negative number? Input: `123` gives `123-321=-198` Will the next step simply be `198-891`?

Comment: @TeunPronk "subtract the smallest from the largest", so no negative numbers.

Comment: @MartinBüttner how is this question about three-digit numbers a duplicate of the four-digit version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Golfscript, <del>29</del> 26 characters

```
.$)\0=-.5<{7\}4if-\~495=!*
```

Basically a mix of Joey's PS- and my Ruby-solution.

Edit: Thanks [Nabb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/174/nabb) for a suggestion on how to shorten this by 3 characters.

Answer (score 21):

### Windows PowerShell, 61 <s>65</s> <s>70</s> <s>72</s> <s>73</s> <s>82</s>

Evil alternative approach. It becomes apparent if you desperately search for patterns in the input.

Be sure to also check out Ventero's [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/hitting-495-kaprekar/1268#1268) and [Golfscript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/hitting-495-kaprekar/1270#1270) solutions which use the same technique which was sort of a joined work :-)

```
(7..3+1..5)[($x=($a="$args")[0..2]|sort)[2]-$x[0]]*($a-ne495)
```

A little explanation might be in order for this, I guess. Suppose you have a number consisting of three digits. For convenience they are labeled *a*, *b* and *c* here with *c* being the largest. You then are going to subtract *abc* from *cba*.

If we picture that, we are going to get (*c* − *a* − 1), 9 and (10 + *a* - *c*) as the individual digits. This will *always* hold, no matter the input digits. This also means that the middle digit get no say in how long the sequence will be, simply because it always is `9`.

So basically the first and last digit of the *sorted* digits suffice in determining the length of the sequence. One can easily make a list with every conceivable combination of first and last digit (there are only 45) to search for patterns there.

As it turns out, there are at least two. Both play with the first few results of the different digits: `[6 5 4 3 1 2 3 4 5]`. First, taking the *difference* between the largest and the smallest digit and subtracting one gives the appropriate index in the aforementioned list of results. Second, interpreting the smallest and largest digit as a single number and doing modulo 11 yields the same, except that one has to prepend another `6` to the list.

Comment: A rare case of golfing leading to fast code.

Comment: Accepted answer for admiration of analysis.

Answer (score 11):

### J, <s>43</s> 37

```
<:$".@(\:,'-',/:)~@":@((3$10)&#:)^:a:
```

Sample run (note how stripping the 3 leading chars displays a trace):

```
   <:$".@(\:,'-',/:)~@":@((3$10)&#:)^:a:211
6
   ".@(\:,'-',/:)~@":@((3$10)&#:)^:a:211
211 99 891 792 693 594 495
   <:$".@(\:,'-',/:)~@":@((3$10)&#:)^:a:494
1
   <:$".@(\:,'-',/:)~@":@((3$10)&#:)^:a:495
0
```

This version repeatedly (`^:`) converts to decimal (`(3$10)&#:`), concatenates the descending list (`\:`), a minus sign `'-'` and the ascending list (`/:`), and evaluates (`".`).  Until the result is stable (`a:`).  Then it counts the number of returned elements (`<:$`).

I'm as surprised as you it needs fewer characters than the table lookup variant.

Comment: I like how you have made the 495 implicit by stopping at a fixed point.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 89 characters

```
n=input()
c=0
while n-495:s=''.join(sorted('%03d'%n));n=int(s[::-1])-int(s);c+=1
print c
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 40

Using the Joey/Ventero approach.  (go upvote them first)

```
(-&4`(7&-)@.(<&5)".'-'1}\:~y)-'495'-:y=.
```

This doesn't beat Golfscript, but I liked the idea of sorting the number, replacing the middle digit with a `-` and evaluating that.

Answer (score 3):

### Windows PowerShell, <s>80</s> 79

```
for($a="$args";$a-495;++$i){$a=-join($x="00$a"[-1..-3]|sort)[2..0]-+-join$x}+$i
```

History:

- 2011-03-05 00:27 **(113)** Initial attempt.
- 2011-03-05 00:33 **(107)** One `sort` has to suffice.
- 2011-03-05 00:36   **(92)** Inlined the `filter`.
- 2011-03-05 00:41   **(87)** No format string anymore. There are other ways.
- 2011-03-05 00:43   **(85)** Unnecessary parentheses.
- 2011-03-05 01:01   **(83)** `-eq` → `-`.
- 2011-03-05 15:42   **(80)** I no longer need to cast the initial input to `int`. Removed unneeded parentheses.
- 2015-09-11 08:20   **(79)** I can move a `+` and save a space by abusing that `-` can only mean arithmetic and thus always converts both operands to a number.

Side note: [My test cases](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/CG1255/test.ps1).

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby 1.8, <del>64 55 52</del> 48 characters

```
l=gets.bytes;i=l.max-l.min;p /495/?0:i<5?7-i:i-4
```

Note that the input shouldn't contain a line break.

For Ruby 1.9, the solution needs an additional space before the last colon.

- (64 -> 55) Thanks to [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey) for pointing out that the input already consists of 3 digits.
- (55 -> 53) Thanks to [steenslag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/537/steenslag) for pointing out `Array#minmax`
- (53 -> 52) Actually just using `Array#max` and `Array#min` directly is shorter.
- (52 -> 48) Implicitly match a regexp against `$_` to test for 495.

Comment: Rather amazing... is this the same trick as @Joey's evil approach?

Comment: @steenslag: Yes, we both developed it together, kinda.

Comment: I'm by no means a math expert, but this could be a minor mathematical novelty. Can it be expanded to include four digits, or even more?

Comment: @steenslag: There is a similar number for four digits, but I don't know whether such a formula exists. It may be likely, though I suspect in that case it would look more like (3rd and 4th digit) minus (2nd and 1st digit). Feel free to experiment, though. The discovery above was coincidental after looking at the map I created that maps sorted digits to the result :-)

Answer (score 2):

### C - 133

*newline added for appearance*

```
c;main(n,l,h,t,i){scanf("%d",&n);for(;n!=495;c++,n=(h-l)*99)
for(l=n%10,h=l,i=2;i--;)t=(n/=10)%10,t<l?l=t:t>h?h=t:0;printf("%d\n",c);}
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 42 chars/bytes*

```
{⍵=495:⍺+0⋄L←⍵⊤⍨3⍴10⋄(⍺+1)∇10⊥L[⍒L]-L[⍋L]}
```

APL entry was missing from historic golf! Had to rectify. Trivial implementation, nothing fancy. Tested on [ngn/apl](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/).

**Explanation**

The function is initially called with a single number `⍵`. It will recursively call itself `∇` with the number of steps already taken `⍺` and the new number `⍵`.

```
⍵=495: ⍺+0
```

Terminating condition: if `⍵` is 495, return the number of steps already taken (0 if `⍺` is yet undefined—this may differ in other dialects.)

```
L←(3⍴10)⊤⍵
```

Decode `⍵` into a list of 3 digits base 10. Above `⊤` is reflected to save 1 char.

```
(⍺+1) ∇ 10⊥L[⍒L]-L[⍋L]
```

Sort the list both ways, subtract one from the other member-wise, encode the result in base 10 (this works for negative digits too; may differ in other dialects) and recurse, adding 1 to `⍺` (or just 1 if undefined, see above.)

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Comment: 42 characters. Incidental? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Lua 173 bytes**

Going for the longest one:

```
T=table c=T.concat i=1 n=tonumber p=io.read()while l~="495"do l={p:match"(%d)(%d)(%d)"}T.sort(l)k={}k[1]=l[3]k[2]=l[2]k[3]=l[1]p=('%03i'):format(c(k)-c(l))i=i+1 end print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 63

```
f=lambda n:n-495and-~f(99*(int(max(`n`))-int(min(`n`))*(n>99)))
```

A recursive function. Gives `0` for `n==495` and otherwise transforms `n` and increments the counter by `1` with `-~`.

The transformation uses the fact that for three-digit numbers `abc-cba` equals `99*(a-c)`. To account for two-digit numbers, we set the `min` digit to `0` unless `n>99`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 145

This was the best I could do on such short notice:

`for(n=prompt(i=o=e='');!i--|n-495;o+=n+' - '+a+' = '+(n=(p=n-a+e)[2]?p:0+p)+'\n')b=n.split(e).sort(),n=b.reverse(a=b.join(e)).join(e);alert(o+~i)`