# Code Golf: 6174 - Kaprekar's mythical constant

Tags: code-golf, repeated-transformation, sequence

Why is the number 6174 so interesting? As [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar%27s_constant) by Wikipedia

> 1. Take any four-digit number, using at
>      least two different digits. (Leading
>      zeros are allowed.)
> 2. Arrange the digits in ascending and
>      then in descending order to get two
>      four-digit numbers, adding leading
>      zeros if necessary.
> 3. Subtract the smaller number from the
>      bigger number.
> 4. Go back to step 2.
>
> The above process, known as Kaprekar's
>   routine, will always reach 6174 in at
>   most 7 iterations. Once 6174 is
>   reached, the process will continue
>   yielding it.

Write a program which runs the Kaprekar's routine against a given four-digit number (see definition above) printing out each step of the routine.

Rules:

- Submissions must be complete
  programs.
- Input must be read from standard
  input. Piping from *echo* is OK.
- Input should be in numeric form.
- Printing out leading zeros is
  required. (See examples below.)
- Last line should say how many
  iterations were needed. Punctuation is required.

Examples:

```
> 2607
7620 - 0267 = 7353
7533 - 3357 = 4176
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 3.

> 1211
2111 - 1112 = 0999
9990 - 0999 = 8991
9981 - 1899 = 8082
8820 - 0288 = 8532
8532 - 2358 = 6174
Iterations: 5.

> 6174
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 1.
```

Any programming language is welcome. Extra points for esoteric ones + a small bounty.

**Update 1**: There is already a [similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/hitting-495-kaprekar).

**Update 2**: Added example for 6174 as input. Thanks to Peter Taylor for the notice.

Comment: @lunohodov If you already have 6174 as input, do you really need one iteration to reach 6174? I only ask because I'll have to write a special case in my program if you do. :-(

Comment: @Gareth Yes, as the task is, as defined above, to run the Kaprekar's routine against a given four-digit number and 6174 should be treated as such.

Comment: This is the exact same question I had to do in the NCSS challenge. If you're doing this to get other people to give you the answer in the NCSS challenge, then that's pretty bad and it defeats the purpose of a challenge. If you're not, then I apolagize.

Comment: This question was posted in the middle of last year - I very much doubt anyone was trying to cheat for some test or challenge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Perl - <strike>147</strike> <strike>143</strike> <strike>134</strike> <strike>130</strike> <strike>129</strike> <strike>126</strike> <strike>129</strike> <strike>128</strike> 126

```
for($_=<>;$_-6174+!$c;$c++){$_=reverse$d=join'',sort split//,"$_"
|$|x4;printf"$_ - $d = %04d\n",$_-=$d}die"Iterations: $c.\n"
```

EDIT: Now complies with 6174 case, at the cost of a few chars... run with `echo -n <number> | perl kaprekar.pl`

EDIT: Finally back to where I was before :D

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby 1.9, 122 characters

```
puts"Iterations: #{(1..7).find{s=$_.chars.sort*"";puts [r=s.reverse,?-,s,?=,$_="%04d"%(r.to_i-s.to_i)]*" ";~/6174/}}."
```

Example invocation:

```
$ echo 1211 | ruby -ln kaprekar.rb
```

I've counted the `-ln` flag as 4 characters (difference between the normal invocation `ruby kaprekar.rb` and `ruby -ln kaprekar.rb`).

Comment: I saved this script as kaprekar.rb then invoked it with `ruby -lp kaprekar.rb`. Entered a number and pressed <Enter> but the output is the entered number itself. Clearly I am missing something... Please advise how to use the script.

Comment: @lunohodov: I've added an example invocation. It now also generates the correct output for `6174` as input, which unfortunately brings this solution up to 128 characters.

Comment: Using `echo 1234 | ruby kaprekar.rb` raises a warning and ends with an error `undefined method 'chars' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Executing `echo 1234 | ruby -lp kaprekar.rb` issues only a warning and behaves as expected. The output is not as expected, as it contains a warning message `kaprekar.rb:3: warning: regex literal in condition`

Comment: @lunohodov: Fixed the warning and the example invocation.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 141 chars

```
n=input()
i=0
while n-6174:a=''.join(sorted("%04d"%n));b=a[::-1];n=int(b)-int(a);print"%s - %s = %04d"%(b,a,n);i+=1
print"Iterations: %d."%i
```

Comment: +1 for slick padding with %04d. I learned something today!

Comment: A few suggestions: put the whole loop on one line using `;`s. `while n-6174`.  No space between `print` and the quote.

Comment: @keith-randall: thanks, got it down to 141 now.

Answer (score 6):

### Golfscript, 74 characters

```
);:|;{0):0;|$:§-1%" - "§" = ""0"4$~§~-+-4>:|n|6174`=!}do"Iterations: "0"."
```

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <del>197</del> <del>192</del> <del>182</del> 181 characters

```
import List
p=putStrLn.unwords
"6174"%k|k>0=p["Iterations:",shows k"."]
n%k=p[b,"-",a,"=",c]>>c%(k+1)where a=sort n;b=reverse a;c=take 4$shows(read b-read a)"0"
main=getLine>>=(%0)
```

Comment: Inlining `r` and `s` saves 2 characters. Also, "000" is redundant. "0" is enough. This brings us to 188 characters. I'm surprised `interact` does not help here. It usually does.

Comment: Replacing `show x++s` with `shows x s` gains 2 more bytes. 186 now.

Comment: By using pattern guards (`|k>0`) one can get rid of `f`. Further renaming `g` to `%` gets us to 182 chars.

Answer (score 5):

## ><> - <strike>268</strike> 308

```
</&4pff1
v>i86*-:n&1-:&?!
>ao&        v
<v&0pff+1gff
 >&1+:4=   ?v&:a%:}-a,
 v&8[4r::0}~<
 >&1-:?!v&:@@:@(?$}&:&3%1=?}
 v      >~:}}:}@:}$:}
 \:n}:n}:n}:n}' - 'ooo:n}:n}:n}:n}' = 'ooo
 \a*+a*+a*+}a*+a*+a*+-:0&\
 v?       =4&:+1&,a-}:%a:<
/\&~~rnnnnao:29777****=   ?v
voooooooooooo"Iterations: "/
\ffgna'.'oo;
```

Not much of a contender for golf, but it was fun to write. :)

<strike>Run with `./fish.py kaprekar.fish -v <number>`</strike>

EDIT: Now takes input from STDIN.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, <del>189</del> <del>182</del> 165 chars

Credit to DocMax:

```
for(n=prompt(i=o=e='');!i--|n-6174;o+=n+' - '+a+' = '+(n=(p=n-a+e)[3]?p:0+p)+'\n')
  b=n.split(e).sort(),n=b.reverse(a=b.join(e)).join(e);
alert(o+"Iterations: "+~i+'.')
```

Original:

```
for(n=prompt(i=o=e='');n-6174;o+=(i++?n+"\n":e)+(n=(a=n.split(e).sort().join(e)).split(e).reverse().join(e))+' - '+a+' = ',n=n-a+e)while(!n[3])n=0+n
alert(o+n+"\nIterations: "+i+'.')
```

Ungolfed:

```
var i = 0;
var n = prompt();
var out = '';
while (n != 6174) {
    while ((n=''+n).length<4) n='0'+n // pad number
    if(i)out+=n+"\n"

    a = n.split('').sort().join('');
    n = a.split('').reverse().join('');

    out += n + ' - ' + a + ' = '
    n-=a
    i++;
}
console.log(out + "6174\nIterations: " + i + '.');
```

Comment: I think that you can change `n != 6174` to `n-6174` since it will return zero, which is false (at least in C and Python).

Comment: The credit should go to keith-randall who suggested it for my Python solution.

Comment: You can save 5 more characters by replacing `while(n.length<4)` with `while(!n[3])`.

Comment: One more: replace `o+"6174\n` with `o+n+"\n` to save 2 more (down to 182).

Comment: I can't stop staring at this one! The following a) fixes the output when n=6174, b) rearranges when `n+'\n'` is added to avoid the conditional and an extra `\n`, c) uses a temp to avoid a join-split-join sequence, d) takes advantage of the fact that we only ever have to add a single '0' for padding: `for(n=prompt(i=0,o=e='');n-6174;i++,o+=(n=(b=n.split(e).sort(),a=b.join(e),b).reverse().join(e))+' - '+a+' = '+(n=('0'+(n-a)).slice(-4))+'\n');alert(o+"Iterations: "+i+'.')` which should be 172 chars.

Comment: Impressive! According to the spec above though, when n=6174, it has to go through at least one iteration, so I added a check if `i` is 0 (+4) but combined that with the `i++`. Unfortunately, that gives an off by one error, so I switched the increment to a decrement and then used a little bitwise trickery at the end (-1). Then I changed `i=0,o=e=''` to `i=o=e=''` (-2), reformatted the `for` loop to avoid extra parentheses (-1), expanded `(b=...,a=...,b)` bit (-2), and sneaked `a=b.join` inside the `reverse()` call (-1). So 169, not bad!

Comment: ...Couple more! Replaced `n=('0'+(n-a)).slice(-4)` with `n=(p=n-a+e)>999?p:0+p` (-2) and replaced logical OR `||` with bitwise OR `|` (-1) = 166 chars.

Comment: I love sliding something into `reverse()`. I would never have through of it. I'm not seeing much more now, but there *is* replacing the new `n=(p=n-a+e)>999?p:0+p` with an old friend in `n=(p=n-a+e)[3]?p:0+p` (-1) = 165 chars.

Answer (score 3):

#### PowerShell, 125 <s>128</s> <s>130</s> <s>131</s>

```
for($a,$OFS=$input+'';$b-6174;++$i){$a=$b=+($c=''+($x="$a 000"[0..4]|sort)[4..0])-"$x"
"$c-$x = {0:d4}"-f$a}"Iterations: $i."
```

Passes all test cases from the question.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 260 bytes

```
function z(c){for(u=c+y;u.length<4;)u=0+u;return u}for(p=prompt(i=0,r=y="");;)
if(s=(p+y).split(y).sort(),t=s.concat().reverse(),a=s.join(y),b=t.join(y),q=a<b?b:a,
w=a<b?a:b,p=z(q-w),i++,r+=z(q)+" - "+z(w)+" = "+p+"\n",p==6174)break;alert(r+
"Iterations: "+i+".")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scala 276**

```
object o{var i=0;def a(v:String){val c=v.toList.sortWith(_>_).mkString;val b=c.reverse;val d=c.toInt-b.toInt;val e="0"*(4-(d+"").length)+d;val p=c+" - "+b+" = "+e;if(d!=6174){println(p);i=i+1;a(e)}else{println(p+"\nIterations: "+(i+1)+".")}};def main(s:Array[String])=a(s(0))}
```

**Scala 283**

```
object o{var i=0;def a(v:String){val c=v.toList.sortWith(_>_).mkString;val b=c.reverse;val d=c.toInt-b.toInt;val e="0"*(4-(d+"").length)+d;val p=c+" - "+b+" = "+e;if(d!=6174){println(p);i=i+1;a(e)}else{println(p);println("Iterations: "+(i+1)+".")}};def main(s:Array[String])=a(s(0))}
```

diff:

```
else{println(p);println("Iterations: "+(i+1)+".")}};
// to
else{println(p+"\nIterations: "+(i+1)+".")}};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 256 characters

```
(let[i #(Integer/parseInt%)f #(format"%04d"%)a #(->>% f sort(apply str)i)d #(->>% f sort reverse(apply str)i)k #(let[u(d %)l(a %)n(- u l)](println(f u)"-"(f l)"="(f n))n)](while true(println"Iterations:"(count(take-while #(not=% 6174)(iterate k(read)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scala 2.9, 194 characters

```
object K extends App{var(c,s)=(0,args(0));do{var d=s.sorted;var e=d.reverse.toInt-d.toInt;s="%04d".format(e);println(d.reverse+" - "+d+" = "+s);c+=1}while(s!="6174");print("Iterations: "+c+".")}
```

Makes use of the App trait from Scala 2.9.

**Edit:** gives correct output for initial input of 6174.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 215 <del>259</del> <del>276</del> characters

```
<?php echo">";$n=str_split(str_pad(trim(fgets(STDIN)),4,0,0));for($k=0,$z=0;$k-6174;$z++){sort($n);$a=implode($n);$b=strrev($a);$k=str_pad($b-$a,4,0,0);echo"$b - $a = $k\n";$n=str_split($k);}echo"Iterations: $z\n";
```

Ungolfed:

```
<?php
echo ">";
$n = str_split(str_pad(trim(fgets(STDIN)),4,0,0));
for($k=0, $z=0; $k-6174; $z++) {
    sort($n);
    $a = implode($n);
    $b = strrev($a);
    $k = str_pad($b-$a,4,0,0);
    echo "$b - $a = $k\n";
    $n = str_split($k);
}
echo "Iterations: $z\n";
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `abs`, `max` and `min` functions, since the sort will always mean that `$b` is greater than `$a`. That could save you 20ish characters. Also, I think that putting the sort inside the loop at the top will mean you only need to have it in your code once which will save you another 9.

Comment: Wow, I guess I got distracted by the "subtract the smaller number from the bigger number" instruction. Thanks.

Comment: `<?function k($c){echo"> $c\n";$n=str_split(str_pad($c,4,0,0));for(;$k-6174;$z++){sort($n);$a=join($n);$b=strrev($a);$k=str_pad($b-$a,4,0,0);echo"$b - $a = $k\n";$n=str_split($k);}echo"Iterations: $z\n";}`


You can save 12 characters by changing your `for` statement, calling this as a function and using `join` instead of `implode`.

Comment: Also, I hate mini-markdown.

Answer (score 2):

### CoffeeScript, <strike>233</strike> 225 characters

```
o=e='';i=0;n=prompt()
while n!=6174
  n=e+n;q=(n='0'+n if !n[3]) for x in [0..2];n?=q;o+=n+"\n" if i;a=n.split(e).sort().join(e);n=a.split(e).reverse().join(e);o+=n+' - '+a+' = ';n-=a;i++
alert(o+"6174\nIterations: "+i+'.')
```

Try it [here](http://alicebobandmallory.com/kaprekars_constant_golf.html) or with instructions [here](http://alicebobandmallory.com/kaprekars_constant.html).

Comment: My browser freezes - had to cancel the execution of the script.

Comment: What number did you enter? I tried it in Firefox and Chrome for 4711 and 1 and a couple of others.

Comment: Using `0` (as suggested by the prompt) or clicking the cancel button causes Safari to freeze.

Comment: I don't know why it suggested that. You have to enter a number between 1 and 9998 whose digits are not all identical. 0 is the same as 0000 and will cause an infinite loop. It seems most of the solutions here skipped validating input to keep the number of characters down.

Comment: See http://i56.tinypic.com/bhhoqe.png Your output also ends with  "It took 5 iterations to reach Kaprekar's constant." which does not conform to the requirements.

Comment: True. New link in the answer to the actual JavaScript that the CoffeeScript above compiles to.

Answer (score 2):

### GAWK - 152 chars

This is a GNU awk version. It may not work with other non-gnu versions.

```
{for(z=$1;z-6174+!c;++k){split(z,a,"");asort(a);for(b=c=i=0;i<4;z=c-b){c+=a[i+1]*10^i;b=b*10+a[++i]}printf c" - %.4d = "z"\n",b}print"Iterations: "k"."}

$ awk -f k.awk <<< 9992
2999 - 9992 = 6993
3699 - 9963 = 6264
2466 - 6642 = 4176
1467 - 7641 = 6174
Iterations: 4
```

Comment: I receive `awk: calling undefined function asort`. Awk version is 20070501 running on OSX 10.6.7. Don't forget the `.` after the number of iterations.

Comment: lunohodov@: Added missing point. Also, I have used gnu awk (gawk), and that may explain the missing function.

Comment: The subtraction numbers are the wrong way round: e.g. should be `9992 - 2999 = 6993`

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 179 chars but posting anyway

```
s=gets.chomp
n=0
begin
  s=s.to_s.chars.sort.reduce{|s,c|s+c}.rjust(4,'0')
  a=s.reverse
  puts"#{a} - #{s} = #{'%04d'%(s=a.to_i-s.to_i)}"
  n+=1
end while s!=6174
puts"Iterations: #{n}."
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 104

```
{b::();{b,:,k," = ",r:"0"^(-:4)$$. k:(x@>x)," - ",x@<x;r}\[$x];-1'c,,"Iterations: ",$#c:$[1=#b;b;-1_b];}
```

Test cases

```
k){b::();{b,:,k," = ",r:"0"^(-:4)$$. k:(x@>x)," - ",x@<x;r}\[$x];-1'c,,"Iterations: ",$#c:$[1=#b;b;-1_b];}'2607 1211 6174;
7620 - 0267 = 7353
7533 - 3357 = 4176
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 3
2111 - 1112 = 0999
9990 - 0999 = 8991
9981 - 1899 = 8082
8820 - 0288 = 8532
8532 - 2358 = 6174
Iterations: 5
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**PERL**

```
chomp($n=<STDIN>);
    do{
       $t++;
       $desc=join('',reverse sort split(//,$n));
       $asc=join('', sort split(//,$n));
       $n=($desc - $asc);
       for($i=4;$i>length $n;$i--){
          $n="0".$n;
       }
       print $desc." - ".$asc." = ".$n."\n";
       $n="6174" if $n eq "0000";
    }while($n ne "6174");
    print "Iterations: $t.\n";
```

Comment: Thats ~310 chars...

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <del>314</del> 291 characters

This is the program, kaprekar.m :-

```
SetOptions[$Output,FormatType->OutputForm];
x=$ScriptCommandLine[[2]];
f[x_]:=(a=Characters@x;
b=Sort@ToExpression@a;
c=Sort[FromDigits/@{#,Reverse@#}&@b];
{c,{b,a}}=IntegerString[{#2-#&@@c,c},10,4];
Print[a," - ",b," = ",c];c)
x=f@x;
e=NestWhileList[f,x,#!="6174"&];
Print["Iterations: ",N@Length@e]
```

Setting the path prior to running :-

```
$ PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS ; export PATH
```

Running the program :-

```
$ MathematicaScript -script kaprekar.m 2607
7620 - 0267 = 7353
7533 - 3357 = 4176
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 3.
$ MathematicaScript -script kaprekar.m 1211
2111 - 1112 = 0999
9990 - 0999 = 8991
9981 - 1899 = 8082
8820 - 0288 = 8532
8532 - 2358 = 6174
Iterations: 5.
$ MathematicaScript -script kaprekar.m 6174
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 160 bytes

```php
function k($n,$d=1){$o=str_split($n);sort($o);echo$q=strrev($r=join($o))," - $r = ",$n=str_pad($q-$r,4,0,0),"
",$n==6174?"Iterations: $d.":k($n,++$d);}k($argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY49D8IgEIZ3fwUhN0CkpjVNmxRJF5cuLrqbpvRLDVBAF@Nvr9DtzT3v3T1mMuupNpNB0NpRIYGGsfeOXG/n5kL5OrxV52et0JOAYiBFRr@ghfP27sxr9mFKudM2BE15300alkht/yFgxUPPKhLKMEoQ2HAfM1DbvmklgSUBy3KWsjRUdhsTRVbmNW58b9v42lUI5AFXm8F@D5LyX8hRNwiuxyIt/w)

Complete program, input is `STDIN`, run with `php -nF`.

**Output**

```
> echo 2607|php -nF kap.php
7620 - 0267 = 7353
7533 - 3357 = 4176
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 3.

> echo 1211|php -nF kap.php
2111 - 1112 = 0999
9990 - 0999 = 8991
9981 - 1899 = 8082
8820 - 0288 = 8532
8532 - 2358 = 6174
Iterations: 5.

> echo 6174|php -nF kap.php
7641 - 1467 = 6174
Iterations: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust - 375 bytes

```
use std::io::{self,BufRead};fn main() {let mut x=io::stdin().lock().lines().next().unwrap().unwrap().parse::<i16>().unwrap();let mut n=0;println!("Iterations: {}.",loop {let mut v=[x/1000%10,x/100%10,x/10%10,x%10];v.sort();let j=v.iter().fold(0,|a,i|a*10+i);let k=v.iter().rev().fold(0,|a,i|a*10+i);x=k-j;n+=1;println!("{:04} - {:04} = {:04}",k,j,x);if x==6174{break n};});}
```

I present this as a possible "upper bound", I challenge anyone to find a language where a reasonable implementation of this is longer - as in there is nothing superfluous, but also nothing even remotely obvious that would shrink it significantly. The thing about Rust is that it takes about 120 characters just to read from stdin and parse into an integer. "Oh but then just use the string representation"... but im 99% confident that would be even longer

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) -n flag, 105 bytes

```perl6
say "Iterations: "~+.&{{{say $!=.flip~" - $_"," = ",($/=$!.EVAL.fmt("%04d"));$/}([~] .comb.sort)}...6174}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBybMktSixJDM/r9hKQalOW0@turoaJKGiaKuXlpNZUKekoKugEq@ko6Rgq6Cko6Gib6uiqOca5uijl5ZboqGkamCSoqSpaa2iX6sRXReroJecn5ukV5xfVKJZq6enZ2ZoblL7/7@RmYE5l6GRoSEXSOBffgHYxv@6eQA)

I finally got to use my `{}...*` trick, since we need to have at least one iteration for 6174. I'm not sure why I need the extra wrapping `.&{  }` around the sequence though, which kinda sucks.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
    .&{                         } # Call a function on the input
       {                }...6174  # Create a sequence that goes until 6174
        {           }([~] .comb.sort) # Get the sorted digits of the number
         say $!=.flip~" - $_"," = "~($/=$!.EVAL.fmt("%04d"))  # Print the iteration
                        ;$/  # Return the result
say "Iterations: "~+.&{      }     # Print the number of iterations
```