# Find the next 1-sparse binary number

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, base-conversion, binary

A positive integer N is *K*-sparse if there are at least *K* 0s between any two consecutive 1s in its binary representation.

So, the number 1010101 is 1-sparse whereas 101101 is not.

Your task is to find the next 1-sparse number for the given input number. For example, if the input is 12 (`0b1100`) output should be 16 (`0b10000`) and if the input is 18 (`0b10010`) output should be 20 (`0b10100`).

Smallest program or function (in bytes) wins! [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) disallowed.

Comment: “next” as in “next highest” or as in “with least absolute difference” ?

Comment: "next" as in "next highest".

Comment: What range of input needs to be handled?

Comment: I'm going to assume negative numbers don't need to be.

Comment: @articuno Can we create a function, or does it have to be a full program? Functions are pretty standard.

Comment: @mbomb007 you can use standard functions

Answer (score 13):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

- Borrowing the [`x & (x*2) != 0` algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48374/11259) from @alephalpha
- Borrowing [Pyth boilerplate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48357/11259) from @Jakube

My first attempt at Pyth:

```
f!.&TyThQ
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f!.%26TyThQ&input=18&debug=0)

```
               implicit: Q = input()            
f      hQ      find the first integer T >= Q + 1, 
               that satisfies the condition:
 !.&TyT        T & (T * 2) is 0
```

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to DigitalTrauma.

```
l~{)___+&}g
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~%7B)___%2B%26%7Dg&input=12)

### Explanation

```
l~          "Read and eval input.";
  {      }g "Do while...";
   )_       "Increment and duplicate (call this x).";
     __+    "Get two more copies and add them to get x and 2x on the stack.";
        &   "Take their bitwise AND. This is non-zero is as long as x's base-2
             representation contains '11'.";
```

This leaves the last number on the stack which is printed automatically at the end of the program.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 44 bytes

This is a complete python program that reads in n, and prints the answer. I think it does quite well in the readability sub-competition.

```
n=input()+1
while'11'in bin(n):n+=1
print n
```

The test results:

```
$ echo 12 | python soln.py 
16
$ echo 18 | python soln.py 
20
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
f!}`11.BThQ
```

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f!%7D%6011.BThQ&input=12&debug=0).

```
               implicit: Q = input()            
f        hQ    find the first integer T >= Q + 1, 
               that satisfies the condition:
 !}`11.BT         "11" is not in the binary representation of T
```

Comment: You can save a character by turning `"11"` into `\`11`.

Comment: @orlp Thanks, should have noticed this.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>41</s> 30 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to Martin Büttner.

```
#+1//.i_/;BitAnd[i,2i]>0:>i+1&
```

Comment: Could you add a description, please?

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 31

```
#!perl -p
sprintf("%b",++$_)=~/11/&&redo
```

Or from the command line:

```
 perl -pe'sprintf("%b",++$_)=~/11/&&redo' <<<"18"
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 20 characters

A monadic verb. Fixed to obey the rules.

```
(+1 1+./@E.#:)^:_@>:
```

#### Explanation

First, this is the verb with spaces and then a little bit less golfed:

```
(+ 1 1 +./@E. #:)^:_@>:
[: (] + [: +./ 1 1 E. #:)^:_ >:
```

Read:

```
    ]                             The argument
      +                           plus
        [: +./                    the or-reduction of
               1 1 E.             the 1 1 interval membership in
                      #:          the base-2 representation of the argument,
[: (                    )^:_      that to the power limit of
                             >:   the incremented argument
```

> The argument plus the or-reduction of the `1 1` interval membership in the base-2 representation of the argument, that to the power limit applied to the incremented argument.

I basically compute if `1 1` occurs in the base-2 representation of the input. If it does, I increment the input. This is put under a power-limit, which means that it is applied until the result doesn't change any more.

Comment: Nice algorithm! It has the same length in APL: `{⍵+∨/2∧/⍵⊤⍨⍵⍴2}⍣=`.

Comment: @randomra Ah, I see.

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 18 bytes

```
1∘+⍣{~∨/2∧/⍺⊤⍨⍺⍴2}
```

This evaluates to a monadic function. [Try it here.](http://tryapl.org/) Usage:

```
   1∘+⍣{~∨/2∧/⍺⊤⍨⍺⍴2} 12
16
```

### Explanation

```
1∘+                    ⍝ Increment the input ⍺
   ⍣{            }     ⍝ until
     ~∨/               ⍝ none of
        2∧/            ⍝ the adjacent coordinates contain 1 1 in
           ⍺⊤⍨⍺⍴2      ⍝ the length-⍺ binary representation of ⍺.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <strike>25</strike> 19

Using the fact that, for a 1-sparse binary number, `x&2*x == 0`:

```
f=x=>x++&2*x?f(x):x
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 <s>43</s>

No regexp, no strings, recursive:

```js
R=(n,x=3)=>x%4>2?R(++n,n):x?R(n,x>>1):n
```

Iterative version:

```js
F=n=>{for(x=3;x%4>2?x=++n:x>>=1;);return n}
```

It's very simple, just using right shift to find a sequence of 11. When I find it, skip to next number. The recursive version is directly derived from the iterative one.

**Ungolfed** and more obvious. To golf, the trickiest part is merging the inner and outer loops (having to init x to 3 at start)

```js
F = n=>{
  do {
    ++n; // next number
    for(x = n; x != 0; x >>= 1) {
      // loop to find 11 in any position
      if ((x & 3) == 3) { // least 2 bits == 11
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (x != 0) // if 11 was found,early exit from inner loop and x != 0
  return n
}
```

Comment: This `%4>2` looks like some sorcery from Number Theory, can you please explain || provide a link?

Comment: @Jacob (x%4>2) is simply ((x&3)==3), but with the operator precedence is JS you avoid the 2 brackets

Comment: Simple than I thought. Now with the ungolfed version it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 37 bytes

```
f=input()+1
while f&2*f:f+=1
print f
```

Used the logic `x & 2*x == 0` for 1-sparse number.
Thanks to @Nick and @CarpetPython.

Comment: Why the downvote? This works perfectly fine, and is well-golfed as well.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, btw, and nice first answer! I encourage you to continue answering challenges on the site :-)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>75</s> <s>66</s> 62 bytes

Thanks to Martin Büttner for saving 9 bytes and Pietu1998 for 4 bytes!

```js
function n(a){for(a++;/11/.test(a.toString(2));a++);return a;}
```

How it works: it runs a `for` loop starting from `a + 1` as long as the current number is not 1-sparse, and if it is, the loop is interrupted and it returns the current number. To check whether a number is 1-sparse, it converts it to binary and checks whether it does not contain `11`.

Un-golfed code:

```js
function nextOneSparseNumber(num) {
    for (num++; /11/.test(num.toString(2)); num++);
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 40 bytes

```r
n->(while contains(bin(n+=1),"11")end;n)
```

This creates an anonymous function that accepts a single integer as input and returns the next highest 1-sparse integer. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=n->...`, and do `f(12)`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
function f(n)

    # While the string representation of n+1 in binary contains "11",
    # increment n. Once it doesn't, we've got the answer!

    while contains(bin(n += 1), "11")
    end

    return(n)
end
```

Examples:

```r
julia> f(12)
16

julia> f(16)
20
```

Suggestions and/or questions are welcome as always!

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

Try it here: http://repl.it/gpu/2

In lambda form (thanks to xnor for golfing):

```python
f=lambda x:1+x&x/2and f(x+1)or-~x
```

Standard function syntax <s>turned out to be shorter than a lambda for once!</s>

```python
def f(x):x+=1;return x*(x&x*2<1)or f(x)
```

Comment: You can shorten the lambda one to 33 bytes: `f=lambda x:1+x&x/2and f(x+1)or-~x`. It turns out that of you bit-shift right rather than left, you can use `x/2` instead of `(x+1)/2` because the difference is always in zero bits of `x+1`. The spec asks for a program though.

Comment: I asked and he said we can do functions. Most of the answers are already.

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 31 + 3 = 34 bytes

```
1+:>:  4%:3(?v~~
;n~^?-1:,2-%2<
```

Usage:

```
>python fish.py onesparse.fish -v 12
16
```

3 bytes added for the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6), 40

By recursion:

```
g=x=>/11/.test((++x).toString(2))?g(x):x
```

## JavaScript, 56

Same without arrow functions.

```
function f(x){return/11/.test((++x).toString(2))?f(x):x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 65 bytes

```
(n:Int)=>{var m=n+1;while(m.toBinaryString.contains("11"))m+=1;m}
```

(if a named function is required, solution will be 69 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 33 bytes.

Uses the method in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48421/84303)

```java
n->{for(;(n++&2*n)>0;);return n;}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##HcyxDoMgFEDRna94UwNtNK0rqaNbJ8emA1UwWHwYeJo0hG@nptOZ7p3Vrqp5/JTBqRjhoSwmZpF0MGrQ0CXncQLD/6CQma3b29kBIik62L0dYTkq3lOwOD1foMIURWIdmHvBqk3GBy45Xi6n5oyivUohg6YtIKDMRbL@G0kvtd@oXo8FOeSmNvzWCCFZzuUH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
λd⋏[›x
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOu2Tii49b4oC6eCIsIiIsIjEyIl0=)

### How?

```
λd⋏[›x
λ      # Open a lambda for recursion
 d     #  Double
  ⋏    #  Bitwise AND the doubled input with the input
   [   #  If this is truthy (non-zero):
    ›x #   Increment and recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 44

```
->(i){loop{i+=1;break if i.to_s(2)!~/11/};i}
```

Pretty basic. A lambda with an infinite loop and a regexp to test the binary representation. I wish that `loop` yielded and index number.

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab (<strike>77</strike> 74 bytes)

```
m=input('');for N=m+1:2*m
if ~any(regexp(dec2bin(N),'11'))
break
end
end
N
```

Notes:

- It suffices to test numbers `m+1` to `2*m`, where `m` is the input.
- `~any(x)` is `true` if `x` contains all zeros *or* if `x` is empty

Answer (score 0):

**C (32 bytes)**

```
f(int x){return 2*++x&x?f(x):x;}
```

Recursive implementation of the same algorithm as so many other answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 16 bytes

Combining the `x&2*x` from various answers (I think [Nick's](/a/48421) first) with [nutki's](/a/48364) `redo` yields:

```
perl -pe'++$_&2*$_&&redo'
```

Tested in Strawberry 5.26.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
_&ZÑ}fUÄ
```

[Run it online.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=XyZa0X1mVcQ=&input=MTI=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
‘&Ḥ¬Ɗ1#
```

A full program accepting a single, non-negative integer which prints a positive integer (as a monadic link it yields a list containing a single positive integer).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwwy1hzuWHFpzrMtQ@f///4ZmAA)**

#### How?

Starting at `v=n+1`, and incrementing, double `v` to shift every bit up one place and bit-wise AND with `v` and then perform logical NOT to test if `v` is 1-sparse until one such number is found.

```
‘&Ḥ¬Ɗ1# - Main Link: n   e.g. 12
‘       - increment           13
     1# - 1-find (start with that as v and increment until 1 match is found) using:
    Ɗ   -   last three links as a dyad:
  Ḥ     -   double v
 &      -   (v) bit-wise AND (with that)
   ¬    -   logical NOT (0->1 else 1)
        - implicit print (a single item list prints as just the item would)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╦>ù╤x
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=cb3e97d178&i=12%0A18&a=1&m=2)

It works using this procedure.  The input starts on top of the stack.

- Increment and copy twice.
- Halve the top of the stack.
- Bitwise-and top two elements on the stack.
- If the result is truthy (non-zero) repeat the entire program.