# Cases variations of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

For any String that is composed of lower cased alphabetical characters, make a function that returns a list of all of it's variations, empty strings returns empty list

**Test Cases**

```
"" -> []
"a" -> ["a", "A"]
"ab" -> ["ab", "Ab", "aB", "AB"]
"abc" -> ["abc", "Abc", "aBc", "ABc", "abC", "AbC", "aBC", "ABC"]
```

This is Code-golf. Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Should the output follow a specific order?

Comment: In my opinion, it is much more natural if the empty string `""` returns the list `[""]`, because for all other cases, list length = 2 ^ string length.

Comment: To avoid unclear details in the question (example unclear details: ColeraSu comment above), you can consider leaving your question in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for about 24 hours before posting. For now I will temporarily vote to close the question. You may also want to register your profile.

Comment: [Veeeery closely related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80995/8478) (Essentially the same thing, but the input can contain upper-case letters and non-letters.)

Comment: @MartinEnder So should this be closed as a duplicate? Because all answers there can be ported here, and of course very competitive.

Comment: Huh, I was able to recall my answer to that question even down to the variable names... but at least I was able to backport a golf (even better it saves 2 bytes there).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 75 bytes

```
f=([c,...s])=>c?[for(t of s[0]?f(s):[''])for(d of c+c.toUpperCase())d+t]:[]
```

67 bytes if the empty string returns `[""]`:

```
f=([c,...s])=>c?[for(t of f(s))for(d of c+c.toUpperCase())d+t]:['']
```