# Case-fold German

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language, alphabet, text-processing

#### Given a German string and an indication of a case (lower/upper/title), fold the string to that case.

### Specifications

1. Input will consist only of `a`–`z` plus `äöüß-,.;:!?'"` in uppercase and/or lowercase.
2. The target case may be taken as any three unique values (please specify what they are) of a consistent type; either three characters, or three numbers, or three bit patterns. (Other formats are currently not allowed to prevent "outsourcing" the answer to the case specification. Comment if you think that an additional format should be allowed.)
3. Titlecase means uppercase everything except letters that follow a letter (letters are `a`–`z` plus `äöüß`).

### Gotchas

1. When `ß` needs to be uppercase, it must become `ẞ`. Some case-folding built-ins and libraries do not do this.
2. When `ß` needs to be titlecase, it must become `Ss`. Some case-folding built-ins and libraries do not do this.
3. `ss` may occur in the text, and should never be converted to `ß` or `ẞ`.

### Examples

Upper case `die Räder sagen "ßß ss" für dich, wegen des Öls!`
is `DIE RÄDER SAGEN "ẞẞ SS" FÜR DICH, WEGEN DES ÖLS!`

Lower case  `die Räder sagen "ßß ss" für dich, wegen des Öls!`
is  `die räder sagen "ßß ss" für dich, wegen des öls!`

Title case `die Räder sagen "ßß ss" für dich, wegen des Öls!`
is `Die Räder Sagen "Ssß Ss" Für Dich, Wegen Des Öls!`

Comment: What would be the outputs for `Ss`? Also, the example input is missing a `ss`

Comment: @Rod `SS` `Ss` `ss`. Can you tell me why that's unclear?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80995/case-permutation)

Comment: Am I allowed to make the three unique values Python functions? (see my answer)

Comment: No, that's exactly what intended to prevent by specifying that the three unique values must be either characters, numbers or bit patterns.

Comment: May we assume there are no capitals after the first letter in a word?

Comment: May we take input and give output in an ANSI codepage containing these symbols instead of UTF-8 etc.?

Comment: @Οurous Does such a codepage exist? If so, then I guess that's valid by default. At least as long as you program can fit in the codepage and that your interpreter/compiler will run/compile such files.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I think that's a standard loophole actually, taking functions as inputs. I don't remember where the meta is tho

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Oh huh. That would make sense I guess.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/14110#14110) _ConorO'Brien_ was most likely talking about. EDIT: You were actually the first one to comment on that meta post I now noticed.. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. And huh that's interesting. I do remember reading and commenting on that meta post but I guess that the time I was trying to use that as a solution I didn't consider that :P

Comment: But...  gotcha #1 isn’t making sense, uppercase ß is just SS, a friend of mine has a 4 letter lowercase name and a 5 letter uppercase...?

Comment: @StanStrum Encoding has nothing to do with names. ß is a two-letter ligature.

Comment: @Adám not quite what I meant, but i see where you’re going. Just never really see an upper ß

Comment: @StanStrum [It has been in use for over half a century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Oliver*

```
r'ßQ=7838d)u mV,@W¦vW=X ?Xv :X¥Q?"Ss":Xu
```

Whew, that took quite some effort. Input is the string to convert, and a single character: `u` for uppercase, `v` for lowercase, `m` for title case.

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ciffUT03ODM4ZCl1IG1WLEBXpnZXPVggP1h2IDpYpVE/IlNzIjpYdQ==&input=J2RpZSBS5GRlciBzYWdlbiAi398gc3MiIGb8ciBkaWNoLCB3ZWdlbiBkZXMg1mxzIScKJ20n)

Comment: Do you need the `}0`?

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, otherwise it'll... wait, maybe not...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 92 bytes

```python
lambda s,c:[str.lower,str.upper,str.title][c](s.replace("ẞ","ß").replace("ß"*c,"ẞ"*c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVAxCgIxEOx9xZrmLhJFsRP8hK1nEZM9DcYzZCOHH7HUxleIXV7iS847EUQRLLSb3RlmZ9btwnJTDKt8nFVWrudaAgk1mlLwPbsp0YsGbZ17oGCCxdlUzVLqeXRWKkzZ9XxggsUj489dPXWUuFMdxXnlvClCmqeJNgiTeNLogeQCC6il8QhEDPJ48aCNWgoosaE0EsS9pXYiYMB562eT/j9Mui9R6oZEBCZL1lA/r5ArfE/7WdL/LmkuVTc)

Comment: [Oh no!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ9kqurikSC8nvzy1SAfEKi0ogLJKMktyUmOjk2M1ivWKUgtyEpNTNZQOz1fSStZRerhrHpDW1PxfUJSZV6KRpqEOFFHXUdA1BIoBAA) Unfortunately, that's a significant part of the challenge.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer fixed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 50 bytes

```
⁽ñWỌ”ß;y⁸Œu
Ñ⁾SsÇ⁼?€1¦”ß
Œl
Çe€“Ġẹṇṣ‘ỌÇ;Øa¤Œg⁸ṁ⁹Ŀ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwhDsIwFED9TlGmMWAnuAMI9ELLGGkQawjBrZgaDBNkAjISFhQGR2FAsr8dpP8ipWDfe3lzxvnaWpQvuI3Nc4vpEYpgjfLeZksPdijfIwEKZTXAzbVXX/6B12bcA8UcwvTQnMxDG62MPmOauwmoAPKwLtssciOjJUrdfFxsraUxI0MoKUuICCO2ID4UUBAhfDKFKiE0nsy6ZMV@ijJBYM9Fx/a/)

Full program.

Phew, this took much time to golf...

Argument 1: String (may need to be escaped)
Argument 2: `1` for uppercase, `2` for title case, `3` for lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

Uses **0** = lower, **1** = upper, **2** = title

```
•^ŠX•4ôçIiR}`:"lu™"¹è.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOiuKMLIoCUyeEth5d7ZgbVJlgp5ZQ@almkdGjn4RV6Yf//G3GlZKYqBB1ekpJapFCcmJ6ap6B0eP7h@QrFxUoKaYf3FCmkZCZn6CiUp4KkUlKLFQ5PyylWBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>649</s> <s>279</s> <s>275</s> <s>274</s> 246 bytes

Yes, that's <s>123</s> <s>122</s> 94 bytes of imports, which is already longer than every other answer.

```
from StdList import++,map,flatten
import StdLib,StdInt,StdBool,Text.Unicode,Text.Unicode.UChar
$ =fromInt
? =isAlpha
^ =toUpper
@0s=map^s
@1s=map toLower s
@2s=flatten(map(\[h:t]=if($223==h||h> $999)[$83,$115][^h]++ @1t)(groupBy(\a b= ?a== ?b)s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLNbtNAEL7vUwwhUm3FaUkqpCbSpqFApUo5INKc8qNs7HW8YO@anXVLpD4H1154DG55L8z4p4WKy87MNzvzzV@YSqHLzERFKiETSpexNRnMXTRT6EBlubGu1wsykQdxKpyTmjVg82cXkLjRrhJXxqTBrfzuThdahSaSL4zTxftEWNYFXjFQCLsErvBdmieCbYA7s8hzadn0DXJi2yCbDmoNnJmZe2mBkCHytgqPPN5qmYzdmqvY6w6H55wnDw/JBLqj0chfdi/Og@5g8Ha93CTrXg@mA@d7e2uK/OrgrQTsOFwKTs/OR98v26ZeVPxRk1B6j6eL2@sLdnYGYmfuJMSFDp0yGiIjUZ84sPJboawElyhsZxaAcicIXwqaYoEyoi7AFVaDgO3cWcq6BaUJJLvKDv@BLVDTaopP/iHOrblTEWU1Oj2AljLCvxH192097m0A2riGYcueVntNadoywVT5UWUqFTY9BG0L@FxzJr7KmjtSmKfiQAQgBSraFIvHY6/h7E8qBp/F9XIbjDFH/grvTxrEZ47W/OSdO2Edew10fBI4DEnF2kVGJ1ISPh9/RtXaxV5qWHWOj8dHQFx1ID7@slRPmARwLytnJBGOP1J81WEcPGoKqjLaNZLlTWsWn1Q6s2c49lvG8ndIZ7XHsn8zKz8ctMhU2BjNkdfqJzq82NjsDw)

Defines the function `@`, taking an `Int` and a `UString`, and returning a `UString`.
Conveniently, `UString` (Clean's default way of handling Unicode), is just a type alias for `[Int]` - which is a list of `Int` containing unicode codepoints of the characters in the string.
*Inconveniently*, `Text.Unicode.UChar` is really long, and I can't `import StdEnv` because the definitions in `StdChar` conflict with the definitions in `Text.Unicode.UChar` (as they are not intended for use together).

The three values are 0, 1, and 2 for Upper, Lower, and Title case.