# Output the largest number with the fewest digits

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Given a nonempty list of positive decimal integers, output the largest number from the set of numbers with the fewest digits.

The input list will not be in any particular order and may contain repeated values.

**Examples:**

```
[1] -> 1
[9] -> 9
[1729] -> 1729
[1, 1] -> 1
[34, 3] -> 3
[38, 39] -> 39
[409, 12, 13] -> 13
[11, 11, 11, 1] -> 1
[11, 11, 11, 11] -> 11
[78, 99, 620, 1] -> 1
[78, 99, 620, 10] -> 99
[78, 99, 620, 100] -> 99
[1, 5, 9, 12, 63, 102] -> 9
[3451, 29820, 2983, 1223, 1337] -> 3451
[738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010] -> 938
```

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Can the input numbers be on separate lines?

Comment: @seshoumara That sounds reasonable, yes.

Answer (score 14):

## Pyth, <s>7</s> <s>3</s> 6 bytes

```
eS.ml`
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eS.ml%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B9%5D%0A%5B1729%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B34%2C+3%5D%0A%5B38%2C+39%5D%0A%5B409%2C+12%2C+13%5D%0A%5B11%2C+11%2C+11%2C+1%5D%0A%5B11%2C+11%2C+11%2C+11%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+1%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+10%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+100%5D%0A%5B1%2C+5%2C+9%2C+12%2C+63%2C+102%5D%0A%5B3451%2C+29820%2C+2983%2C+1223%2C+1337%5D%0A%5B738%2C+2383%2C+281%2C+938%2C+212%2C+1010%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
e      Still grab the last element
 S      Still sort
  .ml`   But prefilter the list for those with the (m)inimum length.
```

---

7 byte solution:

```
eSh.gl`
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eSh.gl%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B9%5D%0A%5B1729%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B34%2C+3%5D%0A%5B38%2C+39%5D%0A%5B409%2C+12%2C+13%5D%0A%5B11%2C+11%2C+11%2C+1%5D%0A%5B11%2C+11%2C+11%2C+11%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+1%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+10%5D%0A%5B78%2C+99%2C+620%2C+100%5D%0A%5B1%2C+5%2C+9%2C+12%2C+63%2C+102%5D%0A%5B3451%2C+29820%2C+2983%2C+1223%2C+1337%5D%0A%5B738%2C+2383%2C+281%2C+938%2C+212%2C+1010%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
   .g   Group items in (implicit) input by:
     l  The length of
      ` their representation
  h     Get those with the shortest length
 S      Sort the resulting list
e       and grab the last (i.e. largest) element
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DL,NµÞḢ
```

Test it at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REwsTsK1w57huKI&input=&args=WzczOCwgMjM4MywgMjgxLCA5MzgsIDIxMiwgMTAxMF0)**
Or see all test cases also at **[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REwsTsK1w57huKIKxbzDh-KCrOG5hOKCrMK1&input=&args=W1sxXSwgWzldLCBbMTcyOV0sIFsxLCAxXSwgWzM0LCAzXSwgWzM4LCAzOV0sIFs0MDksIDEyLCAxM10sIFsxMSwgMTEsIDExLCAxXSwgWzExLCAxMSwgMTEsIDExXSwgWzc4LCA5OSwgNjIwLCAxXSwgWzc4LCA5OSwgNjIwLCAxMF0sIFs3OCwgOTksIDYyMCwgMTAwXSwgWzEsIDUsIDksIDEyLCA2MywgMTAyXSwgWzM0NTEsIDI5ODIwLCAyOTgzLCAxMjIzLCAxMzM3XSwgWzczOCwgMjM4MywgMjgxLCA5MzgsIDIxMiwgMTAxMF1d)**

How?

```
DL,NµÞḢ - Main link takes one argument, the list, e.g. [738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010]
D       - convert to decimal, e.g. [[7,3,8],[2,3,8,3],[2,8,1],[9,3,8],[2,1,2],[1,0,1,0]]
 L      - length, e.g. [3,4,3,3,3,4]
   N    - negate, e.g [-738, -2383, -281, -938, -212, -1010]
  ,     - pair, e.g. [[3,-738],[4,-2383],[3,-281],[3,-938],[3,-212],[4,-1010]]
    µ   - make a monadic chain
     Þ  - sort the input by that monadic function, e.g [938,738,281,212,2383,1010]
          (the lists in the example are not created, but we sort over the values shown)
      Ḣ - pop and return the first element, e.g. 938
```

Comment: Great use of sort!

Comment: @miles your way was still inspired :)

Comment: Looks like `ÐṂ` and `ÐṀ` (leads to a [6 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231790/66833)) were [added](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/pull/21) *hours* after this answer :P

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
({é¬(
```

Explanation:

```
(      # Negate the list, e.g. [22, 33, 4] -> [-22, -33, -4]
 {     # Sort, e.g. [-22, -33, -4] -> [-33, -22, -4]
  é    # Sort by length, e.g. [-33, -22, -4] -> [-4, -22, -33]
   ¬   # Get the first element.
    (  # And negate that.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=KHvDqcKsKA&input=WzM0NTEsIDI5ODIwLCAyOTgzLCAxMjIzLCAxMzM3XQ)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>48</s> 42 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to @Dennis (use `min` rather than `sorted`)

```python
lambda l:min(l,key=lambda x:(len(`x`),-x))
```

All test cases are at **[ideone](http://ideone.com/IbYFyJ)**

Take the minimum of the list by (length, -value)

Comment: `min` should work instead of `sorted`.

Comment: @Dennis, oh jeez - thanks! Probably different enough to have posted that yourself though.

Comment: Swapping `sorted()[0]` for `min`? I consider that a trivial modification of your original code.

Comment: There's also ``len(`x`)+1./x`` for the same length. Too bad you need the `1.`.

Comment: Well, that's shorter than what I came up with. Good job!

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 34 bytes

```
->a{a.max_by{|n|[-n.to_s.size,n]}}
```

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/643153

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
10&YlktX<=G*X>
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAmWWxrdFg8PUcqWD4&input=Wzc4LCA5OSwgNjIwLCAxMDBd)

Explanation:

```
  &Yl           % Log
10              % Base 10
     kt         % Floor and duplicate
       X<       % Find the smallest element
         =      % Filter out elements that do not equal the smallest element
          G     % Push the input again
           *    % Multiply (this sets numbers that do not have the fewest digits to 0)
            X>  % And take the maximum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <del>24</del> 16 bytes

```
O^`
O$#`
$.0
G1`
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=T15gCk8kI2AKJC4wCkcxYA&input=MQoxMgo5CjYzCjUKMTAy) or [run all test cases](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApPXmBcZCsKTyQjYFxkKwokLjAKIC4rCg&input=MQo5CjE3MjkKMSAxCjM0IDMKMzggMzkKNDA5IDEyIDEzCjExIDExIDExIDEKMTEgMTEgMTEgMTEKNzggOTkgNjIwIDEKNzggOTkgNjIwIDEwCjc4IDk5IDYyMCAxMDAKMSA1IDkgMTIgNjMgMTAyCjM0NTEgMjk4MjAgMjk4MyAxMjIzIDEzMzcKNzM4IDIzODMgMjgxIDkzOCAyMTIgMTAxMA).

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Martin!

The all test is using a slightly older version of the code, but the algorithm is identical. I'll update it to be closer when I get more time.

The trailing newline is significant. Sorts the numbers by reverse numeric value, then sorts them by number of digits. This leaves us with the largest number with the fewest digits in the first position, so we can just delete the remaining digits.

Comment: If you make the input linefeed-separated you can omit the regex from both sorting stages and then use `G1\`` for the last stage.

Comment: Also, the first stage doesn't need `#`. You only care about relative order for a given integer length, and within one length lexicographic sorting of numbers is correct.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks! I've added both your tips. I should have suggested `\w+` as the default for sorting, that way I wouldn't need to struggle as much to make the test suites ;)

Comment: Here is another 16, in case it gives you any ideas for further golfing: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWAkCn4KT15gClJzYH4uKw&input=MQoxMgo5CjYzCjUKMTAy

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
*.min:{.chars,-$_}
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
*\        # Whatever lambda
.min:     # find the minimum using

{         # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  .chars, # number of characters first ( implicit method call on ｢$_｣ )
  -$_     # then negative of the value in case of a tie
}
```

### Usage:

```perl6
say [738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010].&( *.min:{.chars,-$_} ); # 938

my &code = *.min:{.chars,-$_}

say code [78, 99, 620, 10]; # 99
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
Max@MinimalBy[#,IntegerLength]&
```

MinimalBy selects all the elements of the original input list with the smallest score according to `IntegerLength`, i.e., with the smallest number of digits; and then Max outputs the largest one.

*Thanks to Martin Ender for finding, and then saving, 2 bytes for me :)*

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
|/{=/&/\#'$x}#
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxlUNtqwzAMffdXCFp2AY9EVtpYNduPZIHupTA2GJQ9tHTdt+9IbtZ2g/hyLlaks1l9NYfH5qZ5nt3Od8dZCJ+rw3zYf29XGyLalfXHW7lbb15e38uu7Mv2fjzCM0QuPNqpRf3kPmmxzRDTSZaOpIjfMokWcblrlTgRS2HXGP761VdnDMKZPpMqLVM7WS6Itqj+pSaOaUGJ/G9LAZ9qt9ItmJJmeLFDSAmbSF9M8WLoNwmklJnUgDXc2s8kjyE0YeCRHp6Iw6B+UTA2vpO4AEb69UgXSRwIQAaoToEPccCZsKqDYWF7PK2pyBV5YkH3KKcogdEvzNdsW3vUf/xZQNEFpNrKUkxM02QWS6yJ+WEqMoseWh0EjmCxRc8tWnDRkosWXfTsajXJP9wzhD8=)

- `{...}#` set up a filter, returning elements from the (implicit) right argument where the code in `{...}` returns `1`s

  - `#'$x` count the number of characters in the string representation of each input
  - `&/\` generate a two item list of the character counts and their minimum
  - `=/` generate a boolean mask indicating which indices have the fewest digits
- `|/` return the maximum (remaining) value

Comment: `c=&/c:` can be ``=/&/\`` for -1

Comment: Nice! A clever way to avoid the inline assignment.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
DL€İMị¹Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REzigqzEsE3hu4vCueG5gA&input=&args=WzM0NTEsIDI5ODIwLCAyOTgzLCAxMjIzLCAxMzM3XQ) or [Verify all test cases.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=REzigqzEsE3hu4vCueG5gArDh-KCrA&input=&args=W1sxXSwKIFs5XSwKIFsxNzI5XSwKIFsxLCAxXSwKIFszNCwgM10sCiBbMzgsIDM5XSwKIFs0MDksIDEyLCAxM10sCiBbMTEsIDExLCAxMSwgMV0sCiBbMTEsIDExLCAxMSwgMTFdLAogWzc4LCA5OSwgNjIwLCAxXSwKIFs3OCwgOTksIDYyMCwgMTBdLAogWzc4LCA5OSwgNjIwLCAxMDBdLAogWzEsIDUsIDksIDEyLCA2MywgMTAyXSwKIFszNDUxLCAyOTgyMCwgMjk4MywgMTIyMywgMTMzN10sCiBbNzM4LCAyMzgzLCAyODEsIDkzOCwgMjEyLCAxMDEwXV0)

### Explanation

```
DL€İMị¹Ṁ  Input: list A
D         Convert each integer to a list of base 10 digits
 L€       Get the length of each list (number of digits of each)
   İ      Take the reciprocal of each
    M     Get the indices of the maximal values
      ¹   Get A
     ị    Select the values at those indices from A
       Ṁ  Find the maximum and return
```

Comment: How is this 8 bytes? Do all of these characters fit in ASCII?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni [Yes, they do fit](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), although in another codepage.

Answer (score 3):

## J, <s>21</s> 14 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to miles and (indirectly) Jonathan!

```
{.@/:#@":"0,.-
```

This is a four-chain:

```
{.@/: (#@":"0 ,. -)
```

Let's walk over the input `10 27 232 1000`. The inner fork consists of three tines. `#@":"0` calculates the sizes, `,.` concats each size with its negated (`-`) member. For input `10 27 232 1000`, we are left with this:

```
   (#@":"0 ,. -) 10 27 232 1000
2   _10
2   _27
3  _232
4 _1000
```

Now, we have `{.@/:` as the outer tine. This is monadic first (`{.`) over dyadic sort (`/:`). That is, we'll be taking the first element of the result of dyadic `/:`. This sorts its right argument according to its left argument, which gives us for our input:

```
   (/: #@":"0 ,. -) 10 27 232 1000
27 10 232 1000
```

Then, using `{.` gives us the first element of that list, and we are done:

```
   ({.@/: #@":"0 ,. -) 10 27 232 1000
27
```

### Old version

```
>./@(#~]=<./@])#@":"0
```

Still working on improvements. I golfed it down from 30, and I think this is good enough. I'm going to first break it down into basic parts:

```
   size =: #@":"0
   max =: >./
   min =: <./
   over =: @
   right =: ]
   left =: [
   selectMin =: #~ right = min over right

   f =: max over selectMin size
   f 3 4 5
5
   f 3 4 53
4
   f 343 42 53
53
```

Here's how this works.

```
>./@(#~ ] = <./@]) #@":"0
```

This is a monadic train, but this part is a hook. The verb `>./@(#~ ] = <./@])` is called with left argument as the input to the main chain and the sizes, defined as `#@":"0`, as the right argument. This is computed as length (`#`) over (`@`) default format (`":`), that is, numeric stringification, which is made to apply to the 0-cells (i.e. members) of the input (`"0`).

Let's walk over the example input `409 12 13`.

```
   (#@":"0) 409 12 13
3 2 2
```

Now for the inner verb, `>./@(#~ ] = <./@])`. It looks like `>./@(...)`, which effectively means maximum value (`>./`) of (`@`) what's inside `(...)`. As for the inside, this is a four-train, equivalent to this five-train:

```
[ #~ ] = <./@]
```

`[` refers to the original argument, and `]` refers to the size array; `409 12 13` and `3 2 2` respectively in this example. The right tine, `<./@]`, computes the minimum size, `2` in this case. `] = <./@]` is a boolean array of values equal to the minimum, `0 1 1` in this case. Finally, `[ #~ ...` takes values from the left argument according the right-argument mask. This means that elements that correspond to `0` are dropped and `1` retained. So we are left with `12 13`. Finally, according to the above, the max is taken, giving us the correct result of `13`, and we are done.

Comment: Some shuffling plus a hook can save a byte `>./@#~[:(=<./)#@":"0`. I think there might be a bit more to save

Comment: @miles XD I just finished writing explanation. Ah well, let me take a look at this beauty...

Comment: Jonathan found a better method. If we convert it to J, its 14 bytes `{.@/:#@":"0,.-` but the input has to be shaped as a list

Comment: @miles "shaped as a list"? You mean, like `400 12 13`?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51

```js
l=>l.sort((a,b)=>(a+l).length-(b+l).length||b-a)[0]
```

**Test**

```js
f=l=>l.sort((a,b)=>(a+l).length-(b+l).length||b-a)[0]

;[
 [[1], 1]
,[[9], 9]
,[[1729], 1729]
,[[1, 1], 1]
,[[34, 3], 3]
,[[38, 39], 39]
,[[409, 12, 13], 13]
,[[11, 11, 11, 1], 1]
,[[11, 11, 11, 11], 11]
,[[78, 99, 620, 1], 1]
,[[78, 99, 620, 10], 99]
,[[78, 99, 620, 100], 99]
,[[1, 5, 9, 12, 63, 102], 9]
,[[3451, 29820, 2983, 1223, 1337], 3451]
,[[738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010], 938]
].forEach(([l,x])=>{
  var r=f(l)
  console.log(r==x?'OK':'KO',l+' -> '+r)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 39

```
f(l)=sort(l,by=x->(length("$x"),-x))[1]
```

[ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZBNTsMwEIXFsjlFZCGRSAlK7P7EEolgyYITVCyM6kCQ5Va2C0UqJ2HTTQ9VTsNz3AAVG6Q4mXnvm6dxPvbPa9WJ3eHGiFdCSJuotLZL4xKVPbzVm7xJlNSP7ikh5xuSZvkmTeflPchtE4xtszKddkrv167Nq8PFPyOO-Hu7NLHqdIzHSLFAKW1i3aLTaTQSxmRG2tquVIe8Tmckb0gw6jvpxOVKGCsTtOm2kS9CRSPPB_VWOz8N_FpYK7FR25N13atSL8ISu8-zK2wU501cRnPeFzyalzMaal-gzeJvho2zmPUNQ1OhCSQDNy44SIoTiBJI6YeHM4SciEcV8gxxHBFTWvyCT9Ui7Mj_6D8GQiewwipT5k063IyNJ7Apr_wQPt6l1L8Zm4WLgEC4vxpl3qcVJnjf93crhh1YFYW_-AU)able

Comment: Welcome back to code golf! [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU/NaoQwEL77FKOnCComcVdT0FuPfQLpIdbskhKyommxT28npra7VBgz3898zLx/GC3pum2xaZfb7IjJhq92zTs76qt2C1nTtsvXtKev2@U2gwZtYVZyNNqqhaQR4CezAVpQn9IU5EU5WUxyXlRBlsloR3SW5F2SpsE7zdo6Y4mEtoNYBlJfsIW4hWGH977keZ3Um1PjEyQZDMGv7BhhbbgV5B3QqBd7I6Ke1iz0vkGYwa@HVxnwHXAEDYLg5OirSoFOhhUcFC3UDx91hDyQPyzSNcYJjDiz8s78yJZhR/GP/xMw9IRSWOXMvciOy3h1QpmJxg/h41XG/J/zOhyCDgz3pzHuddbghNjxflt57MCbbw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: and you can check [Tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

```js
var solution =

a=>a.map(n=>(l=`${n}`.length)>a?l>a+1|n<r?0:r=n:(a=l-1,r=n))|r

;document.write('<pre>' + `
[1] -> 1
[9] -> 9
[1729] -> 1729
[1, 1] -> 1
[34, 3] -> 3
[38, 39] -> 39
[409, 12, 13] -> 13
[11, 11, 11, 1] -> 1
[11, 11, 11, 11] -> 11
[78, 99, 620, 1] -> 1
[78, 99, 620, 10] -> 99
[78, 99, 620, 100] -> 99
[1, 5, 9, 12, 63, 102] -> 9
[3451, 29820, 2983, 1223, 1337] -> 3451
[738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010] -> 938
`.split('\n').slice(1, -1).map(c =>
  c + ', result: ' + solution(eval(c.slice(0, c.indexOf('->'))))
).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
l=>l.sort((a,b)=>(s=a=>1/a+`${a}`.length)(a)-s(b))[0]
```

For the record, my previous version was more math-oriented but 1 byte bigger:

```
l=>l.sort((a,b)=>(s=a=>1/a-~Math.log10(a))(a)-s(b))[0]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =
l=>l.sort((a,b)=>(s=a=>1/a+`${a}`.length)(a)-s(b))[0]

console.log(f([1]));                              //  -> 1
console.log(f([9]));                              //  -> 9
console.log(f([1729]));                           //  -> 1729
console.log(f([1, 1]));                           //  -> 1
console.log(f([34, 3]));                          //  -> 3
console.log(f([38, 39]));                         //  -> 39
console.log(f([409, 12, 13]));                    //  -> 13
console.log(f([11, 11, 11, 1]));                  //  -> 1
console.log(f([11, 11, 11, 11]));                 //  -> 11
console.log(f([78, 99, 620, 1]));                 //  -> 1
console.log(f([78, 99, 620, 10]));                //  -> 99
console.log(f([78, 99, 620, 100]));               //  -> 99
console.log(f([1, 5, 9, 12, 63, 102]));           //  -> 9
console.log(f([3451, 29820, 2983, 1223, 1337]));  //  -> 3451
console.log(f([738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010])); //  -> 938
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>112</s> 104 bytes

```
int c(int[]a){int i=a[0],j;for(int b:a)i=(j=(i+"").length()-(b+"").length())>0?b:b>i&j==0?b:i;return i;}
```

Different approach to save multiple bytes thanks to *@Barteks2x*.

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/Zo6o2f)

```
class M{
  static int c(int[] a){
    int i = a[0],
        j;
    for(int b : a){
      i = (j = (i+"").length() - (b+"").length()) > 0
           ? b
           : b > i & j == 0
              ? b
              : i;
    }
    return i;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 1 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 9 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 1729 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 1, 1 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 34, 3 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 409, 12, 13 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 11, 11, 11, 1 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 11, 11, 11, 11 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 78, 99, 620, 1 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 78, 99, 620, 100 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 1, 5, 9, 12, 63, 102 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 3451, 29820, 2983, 1223, 1337 }));
    System.out.println(c(new int[]{ 738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010 }));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
9
1729
1
3
13
1
11
1
99
9
3451
938
```

Comment: shorter version: int c(int[]a){int i=a[0],j;for(int b:a)i=(j=(i+"").length()-(b+"").length())>0?b:b>i&j==0?b:i;return i;}

Comment: @Barteks2x Thanks, I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

### dc, 54 bytes

```
?dZsL0sN[dsNdZsL]su[dlN<u]sU[dZlL=UdZlL>ukz0<R]dsRxlNp
```

**Explanation:**

```dc
?dZsL0sN                  # read input, initialize L (length) and N (number)
[dsNdZsL]su               # macro (function) 'u' updates the values of L and N
[dlN<u]sU                 # macro 'U' calls 'u' if N < curr_nr
[dZlL=U dZlL>ukz0<R]dsR   # macro 'R' is a loop that calls 'U' if L == curr_nr_len
                          #or 'u' if L > curr_nr_len
xlNp                      # the main: call 'R' and print N at the end
```

**Run example:** 'input.txt' contains all the test cases in the question's statement

```sh
while read list;do echo "$list -> "$(dc -f program.dc <<< $list);done < input.txt
```

**Output:**

```sh
1 -> 1
9 -> 9
1729 -> 1729
1 1 -> 1
34 3 -> 3
38 39 -> 39
409 12 13 -> 13
11 11 11 1 -> 1
11 11 11 11 -> 11
78 99 620 1 -> 1
78 99 620 10 -> 99
78 99 620 100 -> 99
1 5 9 12 63 102 -> 9
3451 29820 2983 1223 1337 -> 3451
738 2383 281 938 212 1010 -> 938
```

Answer (score 2):

## bash, awk, sort 53 bytes

```
set `awk '{print $0,length($0)}'|sort -rnk2n`;echo $1
```

Read input from stdin, one value per line

## bash and sort, <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
set `sort -n`;while((${#2}==${#1}));do shift;done;echo $1
```

Comment: doesn't work for last sample gave 2383 instead of 938

Comment: @Archemar sorry I misread the question, it is corrected now

Comment: You can remove the space between `while` and `((`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>80</s> <s>77</s> 70 bytes

```
a=>Math.max(...a.filter(l=>l.length==Math.min(...a.map(i=>i.length))))
```

I hope I am going in the right direction...

Comment: Could you replace `a.map(i=>i.length).sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0]` with `Math.min(...a.map(i=>i.length))`?

Comment: @user81655 yup, I can. I thought I had made that edit but apparently I did not

Comment: You could also try negating the minimum so that you can reuse the `Math.max`: `a=>(m=Math.max)(...a.filter(l=>l.length==-m(...a.map(i=>-i.length))))` It seems to save only 1 byte though.

Comment: For another byte the `filter` can be replaced with a `map` that returns `0` for values that do not pass the test: `a=>(m=Math.max)(...a.map(l=>l.length+m(...a.map(i=>-i.length))?0:l))`

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
or:@]feL:la#=,Lh
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=b3I6QF1mZUw6bGEjPSxMaA&input=WzM0NTE6Mjk4MjA6Mjk4MzoxMjIzOjEzMzdd&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
or                 Sort the list in descending order.
  :@]f             Find all suffixes of the list.
      eL           Take one suffix L of the list.
        :la        Apply length to all numbers in that suffix.
           #=,     All lengths must be equal.
              Lh   Output is the first element of L.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 39 bytes

```
snd.maximum.map((0-).length.show>>=(,))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it prefers `34` to `2`.

Comment: oh, thanks. I have to rethink it..

Comment: Works better now!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>38</s> 37 bytes

Includes +1 for `-a`

Give input on STDIN:

```
perl -M5.010 maxmin.pl <<< "3451 29820 2983 1223 1337"
```

`maxmin.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -a
\$G[99-y///c][$_]for@F;say$#{$G[-1]}
```

Uses memory linear in the largest number, so don't try this on too large numbers. A solution without that flaw is 38 bytes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$.++until$\=(sort/\b\S{$.}\b/g)[-1]}{
```

All of these are very awkward and don't feel optimal at all...

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
tV48\&XS0))
```

Input is a column vector (using `;` as separator), such as

```
[78; 99; 620; 100]
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFY0OFwmWFMwKSk&input=WzczODsgMjM4MzsgMjgxOyA5Mzg7IDIxMjsgMTAxMF0) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YAp0VjQ4XCZYUzApKQpEVA&input=WzFdCls5XQpbMTcyOV0KWzE7IDFdClszNDsgM10KWzM4OyAzOV0KWzQwOTsgMTI7IDEzXQpbMTE7IDExOyAxMTsgMV0KWzExOyAxMTsgMTE7IDExXQpbNzg7IDk5OyA2MjA7IDFdCls3ODsgOTk7IDYyMDsgMTBdCls3ODsgOTk7IDYyMDsgMTAwXQpbMTsgNTsgOTsgMTI7IDYzOyAxMDJdClszNDUxOyAyOTgyMDsgMjk4MzsgMTIyMzsgMTMzN10KWzczODsgMjM4MzsgMjgxOyA5Mzg7IDIxMjsgMTAxMF0).

#### Explanation

Let's use input `[78; 99; 620; 100]` as an example.

```
t      % Input column vector implicitly. Duplicate
       %   STACK: [78; 99; 620; 100], [78; 99; 620; 100]
V      % Convert to string. Each number is a row, left-padded with spaces
       %   STACK: [78; 99; 620; 100], [' 78'; ' 99'; '620'; '100']
48\    % Modulo 48. This transforms each digit into the corresponding number,
       % and space into 32. Thus space becomes the largest "digit"
       %   STACK: [78; 99; 620; 100], [32 7 8; 32 9 9; 6 2 0; 1 0 0]
&XS    % Sort rows in lexicographical order, and push the indices of the sorting
       %   STACK: [78; 99; 620; 100], [4; 3; 1; 2]
0)     % Get last value
       %   STACK: [78; 99; 620; 100], 2
)      % Index
       %   STACK: 99
       % Implicitly display
```

Comment: Nice to see the stack states in your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>72</s> <s>41</s> 36 bytes

Rewrote the function with a new approach. Golfed 5 bytes thanks to a suggestion from @bouncyball.

```
n=nchar(i<-scan());max(i[n==min(n)])
```

Explained:

```
        i<-scan()       # Read input from stdin
n=nchar(         );     # Count the number of characters in each number in i
max(             )      # Return the maximum of the set where
    i[n==min(n)]        # the number of characters is the minimum number of characters.
```

```
function(i){while(1){if(length(o<-i[nchar(i)==T]))return(max(o));T=T+1}}
```

Indented/explained:

```
function(i){               # Take an input i
  while(1){                # Do the following continuously:
    if(length(
        o<-i[nchar(i)==T]) # Define o to be the subset of i with numbers of length T,
      )                    # where T is 1 (a built-in!).
                           # We take the length of this subset (its size), and then pass
                           # it to if(). Thanks to weak typing, this numeric is converted
                           # to a logical value. When this occurs, zero evaluates to FALSE
                           # and any non-zero number evaluates to TRUE. Therefore, the if()
                           # is TRUE iff the subset is not empty.
      return(max(o));      # If it's true, then we just return the largest element of the
                           # subset, breaking out of our loop.
    T=T+1                  # Otherwise, increment our counter and continue.
  }
}
```

Comment: Save 4 bytes by not defining `function`: `i=scan();n=nchar(i);max(i[n==min(n)])`

Comment: @bouncyball Thanks! And 1 further byte saved by `n=nchar(i<-scan())`.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 41 bytes

```
($args[0]|sort -des|sort{"$_".length})[0]
```

Takes input `$args`, `sort`s it by value in `-des`cending order (so bigger numbers are first), then `sort`s that by the `.length` in ascending order (so shorter lengths are first). We then take the `[0]` element, which will be the biggest number with the fewest digits.

### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> @(78,99,620,1),@(78,99,620,10),@(78,99,620,100),@(1,5,9,12,63,102),@(3451,29820,2983,1223,1337),@(738,2383,281,938,212,1010)|%{($_-join',')+" -> "+(.\output-largest-number-fewest-digits.ps1 $_)}
78,99,620,1 -> 1
78,99,620,10 -> 99
78,99,620,100 -> 99
1,5,9,12,63,102 -> 9
3451,29820,2983,1223,1337 -> 3451
738,2383,281,938,212,1010 -> 938
```

Comment: [Quick improvement to 36 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY7NCoMwDIDvfYog3bCsjjbVWQ@OvccYMpg/B5nDChuoz941PSQfyReSfKZvO7uhHUfPu3r1KX/OvdvcNC@QvSLXhDfJeWzf/TLs4q4efmeM/6CGVEsWQosIKCRUEjRKuJhAhdQ3eREUVhZVBBlEysaUNFAaG4QhgTaMVrGmLVppJQTd2g4rC19AdoXkBOmRd3BrBNv9Hw "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + coreutils, 58 bytes

```sh
d=`sort -n`;egrep ^.{`sed q<<<"$d"|wc -L`}$<<<"$d"|tail -1
```

Input format is one value per line. Golfing suggestions are welcomed.

**Explanation:**

```sh
d=`sort -n`                             #save the list in ascending numerical order
egrep ^.{                    }$<<<"$d"  #print only list lines having as many chars
         `sed q<<<"$d"|wc -L`                 #as the first sorted line does
|tail -1                                #and then get the last one (the answer)
```

Comment: +1 thank you now I know that `sed q` = `head -1`

Answer (score 1):

## **Python 2 - 41 bytes**

```
lambda l:max((-len(`x`),x) for x in l)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 bytes

-4 thanks to @rak1507.

```apl
f←⌈/⊢×((⌊/=⊢)≢∘⍕¨)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHPR36j7oWHZ6uofGop0vfFsjWfNS56FHHjEe9Uw@t0Pz/qG8qUFmagrmxhY6CkbGFMZC0MNRRsATzDY10FAwNDA24YMqAMqZASaAoUMbMGCRr9B8A)

Comment: `⌈/⊢×((⌊/=⊢)≢∘⍕¨)` works I think

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
DL$ÐṂṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU8rDsJAEPU9xQpkSboz/a1BERSahDSVGNIL4JoaEhQXwIBFItoge5LtRZa3XRZoELM77zMvM/tdVR2MWa5n/Vl3je5qo9uT7m5DfSl1e92s@mOgn4/@ODT3rTGFLMV8IWRQqLFRQSEzcr1tAEPx8XAcCh4BA@QAzsnwxZGCk1DOIWGRdtiXD5mQbxZ0hjiFiJSiH/OUjdyO6o//CghNILlVUrYi@cs4TiCTyu0QPqsS2Zc5c4fAgXB7GrHVKceEGvF4W@R34PwF)

### How it works

```
DL$ÐṂṀ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
  $ÐṂ  - Take the elements of L for which the following is minimal:
DL     -   Digit Length
     Ṁ - Maximum of those elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 25 bytes

```
[ all-shortest supremum ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBboMwDIbvPIX3AJ3ApoVs0q7TLrtMO009IOSpVYFAEtRJVZ@dOZ1IWpUhhYTfn/@f@LuqnTbT58fb@@sT7DUc2HTcgOVh5K5mG0@P/ONMZWE4wnOSnBKQZzieIIMzPMDqBbIgqVlSkSowqP581b7kQDkAzTJFuRQ5@FB0yVMlPigrdGWxLfMh87oPuynHegQKiVUSsMF00eC2nobbq/@IJUTC1wL9XWNDHsP7OVK@FhBV6Y1k8xyifxMVYTACxWg/NCRPYim96vJ9mVV69a9UJufpC6qmWdmdNo6tAzv2htuxha1UerPvHGyh1m2vLQNX9W76BQ)

Get the largest of the shortests.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as an array of integer strings, output as an integer string.

```
üÊÎñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/MrO8Q&input=WyI3MzgiLCIyMzgzIiwiMjgxIiwiOTM4IiwiMjEyIiwiMTAxMCJd)

```
üÊÎñ     :Implicit input of array
ü        :Group and sort by
 Ê       :  Length
  Î      :First element
   ñ     :Sort
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
⁽₍LN∵
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigb3igo1MTuKItSIsIiIsIlszNDUxLCAyOTgyMCwgMjk4MywgMTIyMywgMTMzN10iXQ==)

### How?

```
⁽₍LN∵
⁽     # Next element as a lambda:
 ₍    #  Apply both of the next two elements and wrap the results in a list:
  L   #   Length...
   N  #   ...and negate
    ∵ # Get the minimum of the input by that function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
@Y#_AE-_SKa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLG51bGwsIkBZI19BRS1fU0thIiwiIiwiIiwiLXhwIFwiWzI5ODIwIDI5ODMgMTIyMyAxMzM3XVwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 77 bytes

```c
m,n,i,j;f(*a,l){for(j=99;l--;m=i<j|i>j^n>m?j=i,n:m)i=log10(n=a[l]);return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDJTsMwED3HXzEqAtlpgpL0QEvq8CFVQcaxU0e2U2WhKqW/TpiUpeLkN8tbxjKWVvhqHF3kIxPVuaahiCw76aalNV@tchvHueNmXX@Yon72hXuquYn8o2OG26ZKE@q52Ngty1vVD60Hl5/HG@OlHUoF664vrXm93xWEGN8TJ4ynb40pGTmRYPCdqbwqAUfgIwhFToLOvKuXHqzChhR7IU1/zAkJfjFwSHEN54gSRAJfJ6xtJP3bCWGSaTRKsol82BmrgHZSeE1nt8MsgjvPoICEAQYJjIYrmfPJnWH7ot2qi7hoW3Gk4hoKQg5Z9M8ICRukzudb5Hmsz@i9b/G8ybVEVz0pTOrTtm6Vot8Bfz4P7zmT8WGxhGyxXEC2TGE1FWkGaZImn1JbUXVjbN0YH74A)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>63</s> <s>30</s> 63 bytes

```
lambda a:a.sort()or[`i`for i in a if len(`i`)==len(`a[0]`)][-1]
```

Comment: Bugged for `[1, 99, 620, 10000, 3]`.

Comment: I agree with orlp, doesn't work

Comment: Once again, a wrong anser with an upvote? This should be amended or deleted

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 58 bytes

```
def F(x):l={len(`i`):i for i in sorted(x)};print l[min(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

```
lambda a:sorted(sorted(a),key=lambda x:-len(str(x)))[-1]
```

Uses a lambda in a lambda!

### Python 2, 53 bytes

```
s=lambda a:sorted(sorted(a),key=lambda x:-len(`x`))[-1]
```

Same but with backticks

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
(SNgSK-#_v)
```

Takes input as command-line args. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=KFNOZ1NLLSNfdik&input=&args=MzQ1MQ+Mjk4MjA+Mjk4Mw+MTIyMw+MTMzNw)

First time using the `S`ort-`K`eyed operator! Like Python's `sorted()`, it takes a function that is applied to each item of the iterable and the result used as a sort key. Here's how this program works:

```
 SNg         List of cmdline args, sorted numerically in increasing order
    SK       Sort with key function...
      -#_    ... negative length(x), thus putting the shortest numbers at the end but not
               affecting the relative ordering among numbers with the same length
(        v)  Get the last element (index -1) and auto-print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 63 bytes

```
(reduce #(if(=(quot %1 10)(quot %2 10))(max %1 %2) %1)(sort x))
```

as in:

```
(reduce #(if(=(quot %1 10)(quot %2 10))(max %1 %2) %1)(sort[3 7 121 11 8 2 10 9]))
=> 9
```

Though I'm sure there's a way to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP , 86 Bytes

```
<?$l=strlen($r=min($a=$_GET[a]));foreach($a as$v)if($v>$r&strlen($v)==$l)$r=$v;echo$r;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 7 bytes

```
.#_il)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%23_il%29h&input=%5B1%2C+99%2C+620%2C+10000%2C+3%5D)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 119 bytes

```
int L(int[]n){var g=n.GroupBy(o=>(o+"").Length);return g.Where(o=>o.Key==g.Min(k=>k.Key)).OrderBy(o=>o).First().Max();}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public int L(int[]n)
{
  var g = n.GroupBy(o => (o+"").Length);
  return g.Where(o => o.Key == g.Min(k => k.Key)).OrderBy(o => o).First().Max();
}
```

Magical Linq...

Usage:

```
var a = new LargestNumberFewestDigits();
Console.Write(a.L(new int[] { 738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010 }));
```

Output:

```
938
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, 110 bytes

```
int f(int[]a){java.util.Arrays.sort(a);int i=a[0];for(int z:a)i=(z+"").length()>(i+"").length()?i:z;return i;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int f(int[]a){
    java.util.Arrays.sort(a);                  //sorts the array in ascending order
    int i=a[0];                                //declare output variable, uses 1 less byte than using a[0]
    for(int z:a) {
        i=(z+"").length()>(i+"").length()?i:z; //for each int, if the length isn't longer set as output
    }
    return i;
}
```

Any elements that aren't longer in a sorted array must be a higher value.

Also lambda version (101 bytes):

```
a->{java.util.Arrays.sort(a);int i=a[0];for(int z:a)i=(z+"").length()>(i+"").length()?i:z;return i;};
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# (85 bytes)

It's a full function:

```
int y(int[] t) {int m=t.Min(i=>(i+"").Length);return t.Max(n=>(n+"").Length==m?n:0);}
```

Unriddled:

```
int y(int[] t) 
{
    int m = t.Min(i => (i+"").Length);
    return t.Max(n => (n+"").Length == m ? n : 0);
}
```

Comment: There's an useless whitespace after you function signature and in the parameter list. Lambda statement should also work.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 85 bytes

```
int S(int[] i){var m=i.Min();return i.Where(v=>v<m*10&&$"{v}{m}".Length%2==0).Max();}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(S(new[] { 738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010 }));
```

Output: 938

**Explanation**

Get the minimum value from the array and assume that the minimum value is the value with the shortest length.

Filter the array to remove all values greater than 10 * the minimum. i.e if the value is 8, the first check removes all values greater than 80.

Also filter to remove all values where the length of the combined string is odd.  "8" + "9" is length 2 which is even, "8" + "10" is length 3 which is odd and eliminated.

```
int S(int[] i)
{
    var m = i.Min();
    return i.Where(v => v < m * 10 && $"{v}{m}".Length % 2 == 0).Max();
}
```

Comment: `int[]i` will work.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 72 bytes

```
int S(int[]i){return i.OrderBy(v=>(""+v).Length).ThenBy(v=>-v).First();}
```

Borrowing from some of the other answers, a very efficient way to accomplish this task is to sort by number of digits, then by value descending.  This moves the answer to the first position.  Linq accomplishes this fairly simply with the OrderBy and ThenBy statements.

```
Console.WriteLine(S(new[] { 738, 2383, 281, 938, 212, 1010 }));
```

Output: 938

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 148 bytes

```
(λ(l)(define l2(map number->string l))(apply max(map string->number
(filter(lambda(x)(eq?(string-length x)(apply min(map string-length l2))))l2))))
```

Testing:

```
(f (list 1 5 9 12 63 102))
```

Output:

```
9
```

Detailed version:

```
(define (f sl)
  (define sl2 (map number->string sl))
  (apply max 
         (map string->number
              (filter (lambda(x)
                        (equal? (string-length x)
                                (apply min (map string-length sl2))
                                )) sl2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### SQLite, 49 bytes

```
SELECT n FROM a ORDER BY length(n),n DESC LIMIT 1
```

Of course only if the list is allowed to be in a table. The type of the field should be INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

### C++11, 109 bytes

```
[](auto a){sort(a.begin(),a.end(),[](auto x,auto y){return (int)log10(x)<=(int)log10(y)&&x>y;});return a[0];}
```

a should be a container like vector or list. E.g. (lambda as f)

```
cout<<f(vector<int>{ 10, 13, 19, 100, 12200 });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 136 bytes

Golfed:

```
(defun o(&rest r &aux(s(sort r '<)))(flet((f(x)(floor(log x 10))))(apply 'max(remove-if(lambda(x)(<(apply 'min(mapcar 'f s))(f x)))s))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defun o (&rest r 
      &aux (s (sort r '<)))
  (flet ((f (x) (floor (log x 10))))
    (apply 'max 
       (remove-if (lambda (x)
            (< (apply 'min (mapcar 'f s))
               (f x)))
              s))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>169</s> 167 bytes

A function which takes variable array as input:

```pascal
function m(a:array of integer):integer;var i:integer;begin m:=a[0];for i in a do if(int(log10(i))<int(log10(m)))or((int(log10(i))=int(log10(m)))and(i>m))then m:=i;end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPLboMwELznK/ZoS2kFJg@wS6Wqp957i3IwwYAlwBFxGuXr6Zo8KtIoVg6GXWZmd9bGW7nbyPql2G76/U7tJgCNtJXoi327sdq00BDJZdfJI5gCdGtVqTrKz4H4kR3oa5apUqOCp3IVrEVhEEMJSMgN6IIgjdSmDAOiKX37yxpKqenIGE/HuGxzot8xspUaWmih2lz09rhVaPr762ThY3CawtXx@bu45fwjjlAxmeBkqNHczRw7ecbvVEDiMLTDgad3GK@fnZJWEWTcWLggEAKdPoCTx3C4ZD7G1Ncimk0h8lBipHgazYIEWzFcnmKhs3RZT1A93CV6TNDCggXeumNu8BQ58O73HPmnrVhETsF8@z9HEUtiVx9fTsOYe0bR0mPNHQyLnITFWCQZ8uEQAjcWSin@pQDDdeRpbQ4ko2ANVLqsXJibofyh01bVLWlIttJriiK8YK/9Lw)

(Yes I know, pascal sucks at this, in addition there is no sort function in it's library..)

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org), 56 bytes

This is just a Coconut-ification of the best (currently only) Python 3 answer (as well as some of the other answers), so most of the credit should go to them.
Any valid Python 3 is Coconut which means it's at most the same length. Also, Coconut compiles to Python.

[`lambda a:sorted(sorted(a),key=lambda x:-len(str(x)))[-1]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93416/46603)
can be changed into `->sorted(sorted(_),key=->-len(str(_)))[-1]`. This compiles to `lambda _=None: sorted(sorted(_), key=lambda _=None: -len(str(_)))[-1]` (along with a ton of other stuff like additional Coconut builtins).

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((N,n)=>~(L=Math.log10)(N)!=~L(n)^N>n?N:n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZLLasJAFIahyzzFKRQyQ2NMZrwkSuKqm2LTRZdqMcSxCpqEZAIF0RfpRkr7UO3T9EzG2EoXkzmX7_9zDszbR5otxPF9GXxWctnyvrpxEMZ2IRZVIgiJrJQG4YGMg4dYruxN9uI6lET0OjiMSUqfozAdRYOUavH3VTQ0jLkxcWfQCsE1Jn4d-FjpMx2rAFMLzgzvWMDrhGPiYaJJjlzH8ZFkeDThIuIqcXMak4viqYrlPtr5aNFjzh_4suroGf1_9d8GmnaxpUfpcdVkzWa808U28z0lwkt1GVNfzvt6ESTQXK3GuOozDxV-nde7Oc0M3DPmtizWW0LtMt-sJTGnqUntZVbcxcmKSFFKCELYGQBJlmIysWCd5pW0QLzmIpEzCEBR9jaWKGgT-5Yqa3W36fCsK0RZbdALluT-6TGy87goBamtKD1TeVyWyDRwcPpJY5NthHoSpMZGYE4r1ne6Jgx02EnM83RmK8REG1nQCBQ6J9pULOBmp8M9neOoezrUz-p41PcP)

### Explanation

For any two values `N,n`, we need to decide which to return, this table describes that:

```javascript
         length
        | < = >
     ---+-------
value < | N n .
      = | . ? .
      > | . N n
```

Where `.` will never happen and `?` means either `N` or `n` works.

This looks a lot like an exclusive or (XOR) table:

```javascript
      A
    | 0 1
 ---|-----
B 0 | 0 1
  1 | 1 0
```

Where we XOR `length(N) != length(n)` with `N > n`. The cheapest way (I think) to get the length of a number in JS is using `Math.log10`, then flooring the result with a bitwise operator (in this case `~`).

I also [ab]use the fact that `^` has lower operator precedence than comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `hG`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṡñl
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0Uoa7UuyCpaUlaboWyx7uXHB4Y86S4qTkYqjQgpsK0ebGFjoKRsYWxkDSwlBHwRLMNzTSUTA0MDSIhSgEAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṠñlhG
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKx7uXHB4Y06G-5LipORiqOCCmwrR5sYWOgpGxhbGQNLCUEfBEsw3NNJRMDQwNIiFKAQA)

##### Explanation

```python
ṠñlhG  # Implicit input
Ṡ      # Sort the input, so the minimum item is at the start
 ñ     # Group this sorted list by the following:
  l    #  Length (for integers this is number of digits)
   h   # Get the first group (the minimum digits)
    G  # And get the maximum item in this group
       # Implicit output
```