# How much will this cost?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Given *N* items (0 < *N* <= 50) with prices (which are always integers) *P<sub>0</sub>* ... *P<sub>N-1</sub>* and given amounts of each item *A<sub>0</sub>* ... *A<sub>N-1</sub>*, determine how much the total cost will be.

#### Examples

*N*: 2
*P<sub>0</sub>*: 2
*P<sub>1</sub>*: 3
*A<sub>0</sub>*: 1
*A<sub>1</sub>*: 4
Result: 14

*N*: 5
*P<sub>0</sub>*: 2
*P<sub>1</sub>*: 7
*P<sub>2</sub>*: 5
*P<sub>3</sub>*: 1
*P<sub>4</sub>*: 9
*A<sub>0</sub>*: 1
*A<sub>1</sub>*: 2
*A<sub>2</sub>*: 3
*A<sub>3</sub>*: 2
*A<sub>4</sub>*: 3
Result: 60

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

#### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=95128,OVERRIDE_USER=12537;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: In other words, "find the dot product of two vectors"?

Comment: Will the costs always be integers?

Comment: @Dennis Yes. They will.

Comment: In case it matters, positive integers?

Comment: @xnor No, it can be negative

Answer (score 7):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
*
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Kg&input=Miw3LDUsMSw5CjEsMiwzLDIsMw)

Okay, this is the shortest dot product built-in I could find. >_>

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
æ.
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w6Yu&input=&args=Miw3LDUsMSw5+MSwyLDMsMiwz)

A built-in computing the dot product between two input vectors: if, for each **1 ≤ i ≤ n**, we buy **a<sub>i</sub>** items worth **p<sub>i</sub>** each, the formula for the total cost is **a<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>p<sub>2</sub> + … +a<sub>n</sub>p<sub>n</sub>**, which is precisely the definition of the dot product.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 1 byte

```
.
```

## Usage:

```
{1, 2, 3}.{4, 5, 6}

(* 32 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 12 bytes

```
Prompt L1,L2
sum(L1L2
```

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 17 bytes

```haskell
(sum.).zipWith(*)
```

Multiply the lists entrywise, then sum. Shorter than importing (23 bytes)

```haskell
import Data.Vector
vdot
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```python
lambda*x:sum(map(int.__mul__,*x))
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 3 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/5ZuzRo).

Comment: If you can take input as a list of lists, you can do `lambda*M:sum(x*y for x,y in zip(*M))` and  `lambda*M:sum(map(int.__mul__,*M))`.

Comment: How about `float.__mul__`? Should still be one byte shorter.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks, but we didn't need to handle non-integers after all.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>34</s> 23 + 9 = 32 bytes

+9 bytes for `-rmatrix` flag.

```
->p,a{Vector[*p].dot a}
```

See it on eval.in: https://eval.in/653676

Comment: indirectly you use N as count of arrays

Comment: That's sort of an existential question. If *N* was never defined, would the arrays still exist? If the arrays didn't exist, would *N*?

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
s*V
```

(s)ums the (V)ectorized (*)product of the two input arrays.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB / Octave, 4 bytes

```
@dot
```

This defines an anonymous function.

[Try it at Ideone](https://ideone.com/auIj3a).

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>8</s> 18 bytes

```
sum(scan()*scan())
```

Now takes input from stdin.

Comment: Submissions must either be full programs or functions.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 25 bytes

```
p.Zip(a,(x,y)=>x*y).Sum()
```

Sample program:

```
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;
public class Tests {
    [Fact]
    public void Cost() {
        int[] p = new [] { 2, 7, 5, 1, 9 };
        int[] a = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 };
        int r = p.Zip(a, (x, y) => x * y).Sum();
        Assert.Equal(60, r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org), 13 bytes

Building up on Donat's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220631/101725). Thanks to Chartz Belatedly for pointing out the issue with inputs

```julia
x/y=sum(x.*y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifaBttaG1kbRzLlWQbbWJtam0Wy5WmUaFTqWn7v7g0V6NCT6tS83@aRqJOkmaNXUFRZl5JTt5/AA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia) page for ways you can golf your program. Note that we don't allow [assuming the input is in a variable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), but you can turn this into a function that's 13 bytes long: https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifaBttaG1kbRzLlWQbbWJtam0W@78iptK2uDRXo0JPq1Lzf2JMUo1dQVFmXklO3n8A

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
*s
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=KnM&input=WzIgNyA1IDEgOV0KWzEgMiAzIDIgM10)

```
*     % Element-wise product of two implicit inputs
s     % Sum of array, implicitly displayed
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 67 bytes

```
a->{int p=0;for(int i=-1;++i<a[0];)p+=a[i+1]*a[i+a[0]+1];return p;}
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```
public static int pay(int...a){
  int p=0;
  for(int i=-1;++i<a[0];){
    p+=a[i+1]*a[i+a[0]+1];
  }
  return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 13 bytes

```perl6
{[+] [Z*] $_}
```

Input is a list of two lists

### Example:

```perl6
say {[+] [Z*] $_}(  ((2,7,5,1,9),(1,2,3,2,3))  );
# 60
```

### Explanation:

```perl6
{          # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [+]      # reduce using addition operator

    [Z*]   # reduce using zip meta-operator combined with multiplication operator

      $_   # the argument ( list of lists )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 3 tokens

```
sum(L₁L₂
```

Input in `L₁` and `L₂`, output in `Ans`.

Usage:

```
{1,2,3→L1
{4,5,6→L2
prgmCOST
```

Output: `32`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
øPO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I4A////o6ONdBTMdRRMdRQMdRQsY3UUooE0UMwYQsbGAgA)

```
øPO  # full program
  O  # sum of...
 P   # products of...
     # (implicit) each element in...
     # implicit input...
ø    # with each element from the first sublist paired with the corresponding element from the second sublist
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 5 bytes

```r
`%*%`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/QVVLNeF/moaRlbFOsoahjommJleaRrKGkY65jqmOoY6lJkgYKAlUoKn5HwA)

That's the dot-product built-in in R...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 33 bytes

```js
a=>b=>a.reduce((c,d,e)=>c+d*b[e])
```

Takes input as `([p[0],...,p[n-1])([a[0],...,a[n-1]])`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
f(n,p,a,s)int*p,*a;{for(s=0;n;s+=p[--n]*a[n]);return s;}
```

Input is n: number of elements, p:array 1, a:array 2.

Somewhat un-golfed:

```
f(n,p,a,s)
    int*p,*a;
{
    for(s=0;n;s+=p[--n]*a[n]);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
+.×  ⍝ My code is self-documenting
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20TjBTMFUwVDBUstfUOTzdUMFIwBuH//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 1 byte

```
*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=*&inputs=%5B3%2C2%5D%0A%5B4%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Magic.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 46 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET[a]as$n)$s+=$n[0]*$n[1];echo$s;
```

48 Bytes

```
<?=array_sum(array_map(array_product,$_GET[a]));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>31</s> 25 bytes

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@RX55bmpyhoVnNVZpXnFqiEKyQ9T8tv0ghU0FDpUBTQyNY2zZTKzFaWzsrVlPzfy1Xnq2RdYGthpGCsaZ1oq2GoYKJpjXUEOvU5Ix8BZVgoBpTiBpzBVMFQwVLqEqgHgWwPjT1/wE). <sub><s>[old 31 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@RX55bmpyhoVnNVZpXnFqiEPw/Lb9IIVNBo9pQT08lr1ZTQyNY27YgOjNWKxFIaGr@r@XKszWyLrDVMFIw1rROtNUwVDDRtIYaZJ2anJGvoBIMVGMKUWOuYKpgqGAJVQnUowDWh6b@PwA)</s></sub>

```bash
for i ($p)((S+=i*a[++j]))
```

This is the core function. The challenge didn't say anything about setting up variables or output so that's all external.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 14 bytes

```julia
sum((*).(x,y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifaBttaG1kbRzLlWQbbWJtam0Wy5WmUaFTqWn7v7g0V0NDS1MPzNX8X1CUmVeSk6eRppGokwTkAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 43 bytes

```powershell
function d($a,$b){$a|%{$r+=$_*$b[$i++]};$r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P600L7kkMz9PIUVDJVFHJUmzWiWxRrVapUjbViVeSyUpWiVTWzu21lqlqPZ/ioKGoZ6esaaChomenpnmfwA)

Basically, just calculate the dot product.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
param($p,$q)$p|%{$r+=$_*$q[$i++]}
$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9vyCxKDFXQ6VAR6VQU6WgRrVapUjbViVeS6UwWiVTWzu2lkul6H8tF5caUL2RjrGCoY4JlG2uY6pjqGMJFAGKg/B/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN), 3 bytes

```apl
+´×
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHsrwrTwnZWpw5fwnZWofQoy4oC/MyBGIDHigL80)

dot product