# How many weekdays?

Tags: code-golf

This a simple question.

The start day is a Saturday and let the input be a non-negative number `x`.

The output should be the number of weekdays (Mon-Fri) in the next `x` days inclusive.

For example, if `x = 3` then the output should be 2. For `x` from 0 onwards the output should be:

```
0,0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,...
```

—-—

Now I am regretting not having asked the question for a user specified day of the week instead of just Saturday.  It’s too late to change the question now and a new question would probably be marked as a duplicate. If anyone wanted to add an answer for this extension, I would love to see it.

Comment: I found the title on this really confusing. I assumed it meant "how many weekdays until Saturday" which should never exceed five. But actually you're asking something completely different. I suggest revising the title to "how many weekdays"

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda x:x*6/7-x/7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkLLTN9ct0Lf/H9afpFChUJmnkJRYl56qoapgaYVF2dBUWZeiUKaRoXmfwA)

Found by brute-forcing. `x*6/7` counts non-Sundays, and `-x/7` subtracts the number of Saturdays.

```
all          x       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...

all - Sun  = x*6/7   0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 12 13 ...
Sat        = x/7     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2 ...
all - Sun - Sat      0  0  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10 11 ...
```

Brute-forcing suggests that this is the unique arithmetical solution of this length or shorter, subject to some limitations like not using parens, using only single-digit constants, and not having too-large intermediate results.

---

**19 bytes**

```python
lambda x:x-x/7+-x/7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkK3Qt9cG0T8T8svUqhQyMxTKErMS0/VMDXQtOLiLCjKzCtRSNOo0PwPAA)

Found by brute-forcing. But, it has a nice interpretation. `x` counts all `x` days. Then `-x/7` subtracts the number of Sundays in those `x` days, and `+-x/7` subtracts the number of Saturdays. Note that there's a difference in Python between subtracting `x/7` and adding `-x/7` aka `(-x)/7`, because floor-div is not symmetric around zero since it always round down.

```
all =   x        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ... 
Sun =   x/7      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2 ...
Sat = -(-x/7)    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3 ...

all - Sun - Sat  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10 11 ...
```

---

**20 bytes**

```python
lambda x:x*5/7+x%7/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkLLVN9cu0LVXN/kf1p@kUKFQmaeQlFiXnqqhqmBphUXZ0FRZl6JQppGheZ/AA)

I found this by hand, noting that `f(x)` increases asymptotically with slope `5/7` and seeing that the difference to `x*5/7` (with floor-division) has a nice period-7 form.

Comment: What does +- do?

Comment: @Anush The `+-x/7` adds the term `-x/7` AKA `(-x)/7`, which is different from the earlier term `-x/7` which subtracts `x/7`, since Python's mod isn't symmetric around zero.

Comment: I wonder what you can do in Python 3.

Comment: @Anush That's an interesting question. Since the `/` will need to be `//`, it might be that something with `%` for mod becomes better. I'll see what the brute-forcing gives.

Comment: Do you think using parens could help? Is it easy to add that to the brute force?

Comment: @Anush I suspect parens won't help in this instance. The most likely form would be `(...)/7`, and I can't see a four-character expression working for the `...`. I had added parens but was getting bugs with that with pruning too-long expressions with them and took them out for now. Without pruning, they should be easy to add but make things take way way longer.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for spotting those, edited.

Comment: Can your technique give a short answer for my bonus question too?

Comment: @Anush Maybe? I don't see an obvious extension, but there's probably some way to incorporate an offset corresponding to the starting day.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
+/2≤7|⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1vf6FHnEvOaR72b/6c9apvwqLfvUVfzofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cdWmGgA1RmYgkA)

1-based range is a big win here.

#### How it works

```apl
+/2≤7|⍳
      ⍳  ⍝ 1-based range
    7|   ⍝ modulo 7; 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 ...
  2≤     ⍝ is at least 2; 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
+/       ⍝ sum the booleans
```

---

For the bonus question (let the user provide the day of the week to start):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
+/⎕⍴⎕⌽7↑5⍴1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@2/qO@qY96t4DInr3mj9ommgJ5hiDJ/5l5OZl5qY/aJlQDVfVuBanq3YWsqpZLQz3YNyQ8xC1YXefQCnUrdU0dAwVDBSMFYwUTBVMFM4VHHTP0IMYoGOg86t1sZAAA)

We don't need any fancy arithmetic. Just create a bit vector, rotate it to match the requested day of week to start with, cycle it and count ones (i.e. sum).

Accepts `Sun, Mon, ..., Sat` as the number `0, 1, ..., 6` as the first input, and the number of days as the second (both from stdin). (It actually works for any integers (for the first input) and gives the result as if it was modulo 7.)

#### How it works

```apl
+/⎕⍴⎕⌽7↑5⍴1
      7↑5⍴1  ⍝ 1 repeated 5 times and then overtaken to length 7
             ⍝ i.e. 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
    ⎕⌽  ⍝ Take the starting weekday and rotate ^ that many units to the left
  ⎕⍴    ⍝ Take the number of days and cycle ^ to that length
+/      ⍝ Sum
```

Comment: Thank you for the bonus answer!

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
Ý7%1›O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FxzVcNHDbv8//83BgA)

Very similar to the APL answer

### Explained

```
Ý    | Generate a list between 0 and input 
7%   | Mod each number by 7
1›   | Determine if each number is greater than 1
O    | Summate the list and output it
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 bytes

```javascript
n=>n*20/7+n%7>>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNDkUwFAbQuVXcAUmr8RMGBrRr0aDyXuS7gpg0XXsxOpPzt7c9p@O3XwV4XqLTEdogb@qqU8g6Y5ro@BAgTXVPoIHaT6Uk@YRoYpy8LeXGqxitSD2CfGvqnYAMo@yTEB8)

#### How?

The expression \$\lfloor 5n/7\rfloor\$ gives the correct answer when \$n\bmod 7\$ is less than or equal to \$3\$ but is off by \$1\$ otherwise.

```
 n           | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16
-------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
 floor(5n/7) | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 |  7 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 10 | 11
 expected    | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 11
 difference  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0
 n mod 7     | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  0 |  1 |  2
```

This can be adjusted with:

$$f(n)= \left\lfloor\frac{5n}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n\bmod 7}{4}\right\rfloor$$

which may also be expressed as:

$$f(n)= \left\lfloor\frac{20n/7+(n\bmod 7)}{4}\right\rfloor$$

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 15 bytes

In order to use [@xnor's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206544/58563) without adding explicit floor operations, we have to work with BigInts. So this version expects a BigInt as input.

```javascript
n=>n*6n/7n-n/7n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5PyyxP3zxPF0T8T8sv0shTsFUwyLNWyFOwUTAGM7S1NRWquRQUkvPzivNzUvVy8tM1EhI1VKrzajWBilWq0zTyNGsTNK25av8DAA)

Comment: Does `20/7*n` run the risk of a floating-point rounding error in a way `n*20/7` would not?

Comment: @Neil I'm almost certain it's safe in this case. But since you're right in the general case, I've updated it anyway.

Comment: I really like this answer because I can read it and it comes with math.  More languages have integer division than I had expected!

Comment: @Anush Just to clarify, JS _doesn't_ have integer division (which is why I use a right-shift instead) unless we work with BigInts. I've added a port of xnor's answer to illustrate that.

Comment: How come 20/7 doesn't return a float in that case? Are you assuming BigInts there too?

Comment: @Anush 20/7 does return a float. But the final result is coerced to an integer because of the bitwise operation (the right-shift). [See here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP13DyEDfXJMLXcTOzlDz/38A).

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I wonder if the same trick would work in Python 3. I don't know if you noticed but I also added a bonus question.

Comment: @Arnauld, using bitwise to floor i.e `|0` saves you a byte, and you dont have to take the input as a bigint.
`n=>6*n/7-n/7|0`

Comment: @EliteDaMyth No, that wouldn't work. Each division has to be floored separately. For instance, it would give a(4)=2 instead of a(4)=3.

Comment: oh thanks for clarifying! @Arnauld.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of Bubbler's APL solution so be sure to `+1` them, too.

```
õu7 x¨2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9XU3IHioMg&input=NTEKLW1T) - Includes all test cases

Answer (score 3):

## bc, 29 bytes

```
define f(n){return n*6/7-n/7}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs5DoAwDAXRnlOkTJBQMEsC1wFiicZFBBXi7EbfNK@a2XbVo/ApxbGX8NRy3VWctCnmTmJ@Vdn3oWFPYAAjmMAMEshgAavF/2IP2UR2kW1kH6XwAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
R%7>1S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9I1dzOMPj///@mAA)

Interestingly equal-length in all regards to Lyxal's 05AB1E answer, so I've copy-pasted the explanation, swapping out the commands.

```
R    | Generate a list between 0 and input 
%7   | Mod each number by 7
>1   | Determine if each number is greater than 1
S    | Summate the list and output it
```

Comment: An all-ASCII Jelly answer, isn't that world first? :P

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 18 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n*6/7-n/7;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NDoIwDMfvPEVDQrJJCSACkokX41MIB8KH7uAgwIFIeHasBNRtXdN/9@va3Lrn@TxXTPFRxWoX2KGl7FBM8zOTinEYNaCVP7J2B@0thRhGPRmu@2SILmS@jvAfe/okFkKqHsqhKYe@LBYMRgcddHGPHh7QX3aAIR4xQtfZjrviVd0C@9SQhDqC3Ak6@Srrim1Vub0K9IwLME25dbv93xFLaS6@atOSXjHdKMA6A91GlygaQSJ0SPMREf/almm6spM2zW8)

Port of [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s formula from his [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206544/9481).

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 12 bytes

```java
x->x*6/7-x/7
```

Answer (score 2):

## perl -Minteger -lp, 14 bytes

```
$_=$_*6/7-$_/7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixDYAgFAXA/s1BZULwoYAWjuAMVMSQECDo/H698noaxYmoeKg4eRO0iiaIzCAsFqxw8AjYsIN/ErTgAq6gA/3b@pNbvUWfuT7pSkN0Lx8)

Uses the same algorithm as the Python 2 solution from @xnor. The `-Minteger` switch makes perl use integer division.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, 16 bytes

```
33 DB       XOR  BX, BX         ; clear BX sum 
        MLOOP: 
E3 0B       JCXZ DONE           ; handle x = 0 
8A C1       MOV  AL, CL         ; loop counter to AL
D4 07       AAM  7              ; AL = AL mod 7 
3C 01       CMP  AL, 1          ; AL <= 1 ? 
7E 01       JLE  IS_WEEKEND     ; if so, is a weekend
43          INC  BX             ; otherwise increment count 
        IS_WEEKEND: 
E2 F3       LOOP MLOOP          ; loop until 0
        DONE: 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input in `CL` (unsigned byte) output to `BX`.

[image]

Or **22 bytes** to operate on 16 bit unsigned WORD in `CX`:

```
33 DB       XOR  BX, BX         ; clear BX sum 
        MLOOP: 
E3 11       JCXZ DONE           ; handle x = 0 
8B C1       MOV  AX, CX
33 D2       XOR  DX, DX         ; clear DX (high word of quotient)
BF 0007     MOV  DI, 7          ; set up WORD divisor
F7 F7       DIV  DI             ; DX = DX:AX mod DI
80 FA 01    CMP  DL, 1          ; DL <= 1 ?
7E 01       JLE  IS_WEEKEND     ; if so, is a weekend 
43          INC  BX             ; otherwise increment count 
        IS_WEEKEND: 
E2 ED       LOOP MLOOP 
        DONE: 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 143 Bytes

```
function weekdays(days)
    r = mod(days, 7)
    if r <= 2 r=0
    else r -= 2
    end
    wd::Int64 = floor(days/7)
    return(5 * wd + r)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dCsIwDEbv9xQfu9p0ovMXhnsAH2PYFqI1laxj@vS1tmIuEnL4cshtsjS0rxDMxFdPjjFrfVfDe6y@rS4QS9Dj4VQiDU4Zkon83GML6TeJaDvqyFaR5Z1VmrPqugv74z5qjHVOkmj984j2k3B1wCIGsYTURTwMxgkIxGi7XdY/hdhbrv4PUt2UDcqc/wA)

To use a custom start date, I add an offset argument, and `days += offset` at the start of the function

Comment: [Golfed, 89 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcpBDsIgEADAO6/Y9ASKsa1WEyIP8BnGhWQNLmaF4O@xOud51ES36dN7rHwvlBmaRqPEPzNqtGejKIJc/AziRxXSO4Ds/KwCo2ro3JXL6ehjylk07tcuoVRhWDYNt/JrPWYBAmKY3GFUsHoJcUmsmyZjBwuD@ccv "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: Welcome to the site! These [tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24407/92901) might be helpful. Also note that you should avoid using spaces (where possible) to minimise your byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 22 bytes

```
.+
$*
.(.{0,5}).?
$1
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dci9DkAwGIbR/bkOEn/50rfVYjK6DQaDxSA2ce3ljOfa7@Pcclkta7aWosEqe1wX39pmCmE5O4Qn0BNJDIxM6E8hjwLqUUQJDWhEE959) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
.(.{0,5}).?
```

For each week, match Sunday, then up to five weekdays, then optionally match Saturday.

```
$1
```

Keep just the weekdays.

```
.
```

Count the resulting weekdays.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩΣ…⪫00×⁵1Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8O5Mjkn1Tkjv0DDKz8zT0PJwEBJRyEkMze1WMNUR0HJUElTU0fBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDEwSs//83MvivW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. This is actually 3 bytes shorter than trying to calculate the result arithmetically. Explanation:

```
        1   Literal string `1`
      ×⁵    Repeated 5 times i.e. `11111`
    00      Literal string `00`
   ⪫        Join its characters giving `0111110`
  …      Ｎ  Cyclically extend to the input number of days
 Σ          Sum the digits
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
lf<1%T7S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfjvFhj4PyfNxlA1xDz4//9oAx0FQx0FIx0FYx0FEx0FUx0FMx0Fcx0FCx0FS6AUSNowFgA)

Port of Bubbler's APL solution.

### Explanation

```
lf<1%T7S
l         : length of
 f        : filter on
       S  : 1-based range to input
  <1%T7   : where mod 7 is greater than 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 29 bytes

```
{print int($0*6/7)-int($0/7)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EAYg1VAy0zPTNNXUhbCCr9v9/Ay5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsuSy5DoKAhl6ERl6Exl6EJl6Epl6EZAA)

Port of @xnor's Python 2 answer.

Comment: Shaping the code like this will save 4 bytes: `$0=int($0*6/7)-int($0/7)e`

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93, 12 bytes

```
&:6*7/\7/-.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83KTMtcP8ZcX1fP4f9/Q0MA)

Another port of xnor's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
sm<1%d7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzjXxlA1xfz/f0MDAA)

Port of Lyxal's [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206546/41020).

```
sm<1%d7   
 m        For each number from 0-input:
    %d7     Mod 7
  <1        Greater than 1
s         Take the sum, implicit print
```

Comment: Also 7 bytes: t-Qy/Q7

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 44 bytes

It seems like ranging is too costly here.

```
f :=method(x,if(x>0,if(x%7>1,1,0)+f(x-1),0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z9Nwco2N7UkIz9Fo0InM02jws4ATKma2xnqGOoYaGoDObqGmkCW5v@0/CKNTB0DHUMDAx0uBSBI08jUVCgoyswrycnj0vwPAA)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 46 bytes

```
method(x,Range 0 to(x)map(i,if(i%7>1,1,0))sum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQicoMS89VcFAoSRfo0IzN7FAI1MnM00jU9XczlDHUMdAU7O4NFfzf1p@EVDCQMfQwECHSwEIgEo0FQqKMvNKcvK4NP8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 142 bytes

(Due to number-wrapping problems) The maximum supported input is 255.

```
>,[[>+>+<<-]>[-<+>]<->>>+++++++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>[-]>>+<[<<<+>>>>[-<<<<[-]>+>>>]<<<<[->>+<<]>[->>>+<<<]>>>-<-]>[-]<<[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1LCoVADNu9y/TVE4RcpHShgiCCC8Hz12Ymi9L82u1Zz/t496uK/wgaDfBkOIwJJ2kTCDo122zPEwgkRzYpB2i90d2GVNGcRAkoy7H1Svr8pEujMtrKJ5aq3wc)

If you are not sure whether this output is correct, try [this](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCkJBDEN3XmasJwi5SOlCBUEEF4Ln/yatHwS7GJpJ2r7L63x/3t7Xx7bxmMnFBUQxA4uFILmmkAz6lSkvCkgUO1u0A@hfpVmVfy1rhBNwlt2pJWMueVOP9LTzhS05LI5o5dd1dkkFc@dqtGCY3Wxr0Ft5aR@tPSr0rubunT@NszWs/3EZJ7OK7fAB) link.

### Explanation

```
>,
```

Read input

```
[
```

While the input is nonzero:

```
[>+>+<<-]>[-<+>]
```

`>x 0 0` -> `x 0 >x`

```
<->>>+++++++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>[-]
```

Modulo by 7

```
>>+<[<<<+>>>>[-<<<<[-]>+>>>]<<<<[->>+<<]>[->>>+<<<]>>>-<-]>[-]<<
```

Check if this number is greater than 1

```
[-<<<<+>>>>]<<<
```

Add it to the accumulator (at the first item of the tape)

```
]
```

End while

```
<.
```

Move to the accumulator, print the value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 10 bytes

```
0&1ɧ⑷7%1>⑼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fQM3w5PJHE7ebqxraPZq45/9/Q4P/ukVBAA)

Total not a port of <s>Lyxal's</s> my 05AB1E answer... (spoiler, it is). ;P

### Explained

```
0&1ɧ⑷7%1>⑼
0&              # Store 0 in the register, as this will be used to keep track of the number of weekdays
  1ɧ            # Create a range between 1 and the implicit input
    ⑷           # Map the following to each item in the stack:
      7%1>⑼     # Increment the register by whether or not ((item % 7) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 5 bytes

```
ʀ7%1>
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%CA%807%251%3E&inputs=3&header=&footer=)

Another port of my 05AB1E answer

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, <s>18</s> 16 bytes (No Loop):

Bytecode: `"\xD4\x07\x88\xC1\xC1\xE8\x08\x6B\xC0\x05\x49\x78\x02\x01\xC8\xC3"`

```
0:  d4 07                   aam    0x7          ; eax contains n, with aam 0x7 -> al = n % 7 and ah = n / 7 
2:  88 c1                   mov    cl,al        ; keep result of n%7 in ecx
4:  c1 e8 08                shr    ax,0x8       ; by shifting 8 times ax, ax=al=n/7;
7:  6b c0 05                imul   ax,ax,0x5    ; we multiply by 5
a:  49                      dec    ecx          ; ecx = ecx - 1 -> give 65535 if n was power of 7
b:  78 02                   js     11 <end>     ; if it happened we don't care about the remainder so we can just return n/7*5, the Signed Flag will be set so we can jump 2 bytes forward.
d:  01 c8                   add    eax,ecx      ; if not then we add (n%7)-1 to n/7*5
00000011 <end>:
f:  c3                      ret
```

<s>[obtained from assembling](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly)</s> thanks to `objdump -d -mi8086 dayofweek.s`

```
global dayofweek

bits 16

section .text

dayofweek:
    aam  7
    mov  cl, al
    shr  ax, 8
    imul ax,5
    dec  ecx
    js   end
    add  eax,ecx
end:
    ret
```

Test: main.c

```c
int main() {
    for (short i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        printf("%2d %2d\n", dayofweek(i), (i*20/7+i%7)/4);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0  0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
...
33 33
34 34
35 35
35 35
```

<s>It is not as short as @640KB (16 bytes) but</s> I believe it is still an interesting answer as it provides a better performance (no loop)

edit: Thanks to Peter -2 bits

NB (Peter): Do note that aam only divides AL, not AX, so you might as well declare the arg in C as **uint8_t**, as well as specifying the gcc -mregparm=3 calling convention to put it in the reg you want.

Comment: You say this is supposed to be 16-bit code, and you even used `bits 16`, but you have a `66` operand-size prefix on instructions using 16-bit registers but *not* on instructions like `add eax, ecx`.  That's backwards; that machine code is what you'd get if you assembled for 32-bit mode.  Did you take this machine code from before you added `bits 16` to the source?

Comment: Good point, I got the bytecodes from https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly , how could I get the 16 bits version in local ?

Comment: Just use `nasm -fbin -l/dev/stdout` to get a listing, or `objdump -d -mi8086` to disassemble as 16-bit if you have machine code in an ELF object.  And IDK what good `gcc-multilib` would be for 16-bit code, I guess you actually built that as 32-bit so you could call from C easily.  I was going to say I guess you disassembled that by mistake, but yeah, using a 32-bit-mode online assembler would have the same problem.

Comment: Also obviously use 16-bit (or 8-bit) operand-size as much as possible to save bytes, with your return value only in AX.   (So the C return type is `unsigned short`).  Or just do this in 32-bit code; unless 16-bit lets you avoid high garbage in EAX outside what `aam` deals with.  Also, you seem to be using `dec ecx` after only writing CL, so the sign flag will depend on garbage left in high bytes of ECX.  (And you haven't documented a calling convention, but it looks like `gcc -mregparm=3` so first arg in EAX).

Comment: `xchg al, ah` / `imul ax, 5` might work to leave a valid result in the low byte of EAX (aka AL).  The low bits of a multiply don't depend on the high bits of the inputs (think of it as adding at various left shifts, and adding only propagates carry from low to high).  Or perhaps `xchg ax,cx` (1 byte) / `mov al, ch` (2B) / `imul ax, 5` (3B) to also replace the `mov    cl,al`.  As long as your result fits in 1 byte, you're fine, but that might not be justified.  So perhaps `movzx ax, ch` (3B) to still allow `xchg` but avoid the immediate shift.  That'd allow 32-bit mode.

Comment: yes first param in eax which is the default when compiling with gcc and having ```bits 16``` in the elf file

Comment: *which is the default when compiling with gcc* - no it isn't.  Compiling C with `gcc -m16` is exactly the same as `-m32`, except it puts `.code16gcc` at the top of the asm output.  It still uses `push dword` to push args on the stack, as per the i386 System V ABI doc's calling convention.  https://godbolt.org/z/f5E83W.  Building an asm source file just assembles the instructions *you* wrote, in which case it's up to you to implement a calling convention of your choice, not something the "compiler" (assembler) can do for you.  You should definitely mention that you take the arg in AL.

Comment: (Do note that `aam` only divides AL, not AX, so you might as well declare the arg in C as `uint8_t`, as well as specifying the `gcc -mregparm=3` calling convention to put it in the reg you want.)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```powershell
function x($y){[math]::floor($y*6/7-$y/7)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7RCoJAEAXQ975CYoOMW@3Muq4W9iMiEmEUmJYVFea32zbcAzPch2Gu7avq7qeqrsfx@GwOj3PbBO@5@oR9ftk/TsVmc6zbtvPNIl67pfqsXTiMqqvumYYGgX0MIlifGM4nQQrSgkAsDCgCWRGDnEhAKVgLf4iFAUdgK2KwEwk4hdGCYFgYmAjGTvRqZfV31qsmeweq3E7VXJVhkO0CvzQh/sP/m6uyWFY330yH8Qc)

Fork of Python 2 answer

Comment: Wasif, `$y*6/7-$y/7` = `$y*5/7` :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7NCoJQEAXgvU8hMkXGqe7M9fpT2ItESAurhWVpkGA9u92G88EcZjHMo33XXX@tm2aioRynw@30uh6323PTtt3CbbJlRKfu0kfx9A0C6uq@NDBgiI9FAueTIvPJUYCNYrAoC07ATqXgTOXgAmKUPyTKQhKIUykkUzmkgDWKYUVZ2ATWeYFZr535zEa6l3MaQqp2ES2oisNyH/pyj/Ef/ukDVcdV/fSb6Dv9AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")