# System-defined short forms for function-option combinations in Mathematica?

Tags: code-golf, tips

Several Mathematica functions have system-defined short forms, e.g., /@ for Map. Many of them are listed here:  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html

However, there also exist some system-defined short forms for function-option combinations.  E.g., `Log2@n`instead of `Log[2, n]` and `Log10@n`instead of `Log[10, n]`.  Is there a comprehensive list of these?

Comment: I suggest you ask on [mathematica.se].SE . This does not look on-topic here.

Comment: This would probably be better as a category to [this general tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica). That said, if that does not cover the scope of your question, I would recommend either clarifying this as a [tag:tips] question with a more specific and observable scope, or asking on Mathematica.SE.

Comment: @Wzl  Why are general tips questions, like https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia?rq=1  considered on-topic, but more specific ones are not?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino It's easy enough to add a tips tag, which I did. But I don't follow "more specific and observable scope".  The question seems clear and specific. Indeed, it's more specific than the general MMA tips question, which is allowed.  And what do mean by "observable"?  Finally, maybe, to keep the site uncluttered, the mods want each language's tips confined to a single "catch-all" tips question.  But while it would be great if someone answered this in the gen'l MMA tips ques., I don't know of any mechanism for me to request that, other than by asking a separate question, which I did.

Comment: I think, while this might fit here, it'd be better off on the Mathematica.SE site, under their [code-golf] tag. However, note that list questions like this are generally discouraged on all Stack Exchnage sites, as they promote lots of short answers instead of a few well thought out answers. We generally shy away from this (especially with the "Tips for golfing in" posts), but I think this is, at best, just about in scope here, and at worst, not on topic at all. I'm more inclined to believe this isn't the right site for this, so I've voted to close

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not fit in the scope as defined at meta for this site. If you disagree, and this question does get closed, I'd suggest opening a meta discussion about this, as it is absolutely not clean cut off-topic and could benefit from such a discussion

Comment: Never mind, I think this is probably clear enough. I still feel like this would be better as a list answer to the general tips question as "here are some ways to shorten common function calls based on pre-defined sub-functions". List questions are typically discouraged _everywhere_.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino  "List questions are typically discouraged *everywhere*."  Typically perhaps. However, specific types of list questions of the form 'What is a list of all MMA commands of type x' are both allowed on MSE, and considered useful.  See, e.g.: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149797/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-build-in-system-level-heads  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130049/physical-and-other-constants .  But I can see there's resistance to my question here, so would you like to migrate this to MSE, or prefer I delete it from here and repost there?

Comment: I am basing this on [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139623/361699) here. Granted, this isn't a subjective question like the examples given, but it's still a question that only attracts high amounts of trivial or low-effort answers. This first question you linked isn't _really_ a list question because it asks how to find a list (which is answered with a code solution), and the second one is more of "how do I get the non-alias name of a constant", which has a code answer which also happens to include a list for completeness.

Comment: I would say this question would be more off-topic on Mathematica SE (BTW MSE usually stands for meta.stackexchange.com), and as it is purely a list question (it's just "what's a list of all ___"), I am closing it as off-topic given the concensus on meta. If you do disagree with this, I would recommend opening a discussion on our per-site meta since this could be debatable. Again, I'd say this is probably better as a list of such short-forms on the general tips question that everyone can add to.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino  Ah, with your last comment I think I understand what you were trying to say at the beginning—you were suggesting I add my two examples as an *answer* to the MMA general tips question, and invite people to edit/add to it, right?  [Not sure how I was supposed to get that from "This would probably be better as a category to this general tips question"—I think that sentence was somewhat golfed!]  Sure, I can do that.

Comment: Yep, you're right, my wording was definitely quite bad in my first comment, sorry! But yes, that is what I meant. Glad you did understand from my later comments though.