# How much code would a codegolf golf if a codegolf could golf code?

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a function or program that takes two words as input and outputs variants of the popular English tongue-twister "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?".

The output will use the first word four times

- How much `wood` would a `wood`chuck chuck if a `wood`chuck could chuck `wood`?

and the second word four times

- How much wood would a wood`chuck` `chuck` if a wood`chuck` could `chuck` wood?

with the rest of the output being the same for any inputs.

- `How much`wood`would a`woodchuckchuck`if a`woodchuck`could`chuckwood`?`

The input and output can be in any format that your language reasonably recognizes as dealing with strings of text. The output must be exactly in the indicated format, including capitalization, spaces and lack thereof, and the ending question mark. An optional trailing newline is acceptable.

Ideally your code will handle input containing any printable ASCII characters. However, it is permitted to restrict the input to reasonable subsets of printable ASCII; just indicate this in your answer. Handling larger character sets is of course fine.

Example input-output pairs:

```
"wood", "chuck"
"How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"

"ground", "hog"
"How much ground would a groundhog hog if a groundhog could hog ground?"

"bar", "keep"
"How much bar would a barkeep keep if a barkeep could keep bar?"

"money", "belt"
"How much money would a moneybelt belt if a moneybelt could belt money?"

"rain", "fall"
"How much rain would a rainfall fall if a rainfall could fall rain?"

"hair", "cut"
"How much hair would a haircut cut if a haircut could cut hair?"

"green", "house"
"How much green would a greenhouse house if a greenhouse could house green?"

"jabber", "wock"
"How much jabber would a jabberwock wock if a jabberwock could wock jabber?"

"pine", "apple"
"How much pine would a pineapple apple if a pineapple could apple pine?"

"Rob", "Lowe"
"How much Rob would a RobLowe Lowe if a RobLowe could Lowe Rob?"

"code", "golf"
"How much code would a codegolf golf if a codegolf could golf code?"

"fish", ""
"How much fish would a fish  if a fish could  fish?"

"", "fish"
"How much  would a fish fish if a fish could fish ?"

"", ""
"How much  would a   if a  could  ?"

"  ", "     "
"How much    would a               if a         could         ?"

"would a", "how much"
"How much would a would a would ahow much how much if a would ahow much could how much would a?"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins. Answers are welcome in all languages, even if some other language can do it in fewer bytes.

(Inspired by [this meme](https://www.facebook.com/movieweb/photos/a.10150200043617199/10157150855317199), which uses one input pair better than this rigid pattern does....)

Comment: May we assume the two words will be two *distinct* words?

Comment: ...I guess `"", ""` means no :p

Comment: @dzaima Edited to clarify. I don't want the input character set to be the main focus, so I'll trust golfers for the most part.

Comment: IMHO I think a) the phrase doesn't make sense with "could", since maybe it wouldn't anyway b) you really need the homophone.

Comment: How reasonable is "reasonable"?

Comment: Is input allowed to be taken in reverse order: e.g. `'chuck' 'wood'`?

Comment: I am mildly disappointed that none of the test cases were `"ground", "hog"` (since "woodchuck" is another name for a "groundhog"...)

Comment: @Chronocidal I can't stand to see you disappointed....

Comment: @maxb I guess I don't see any reason to disallow the "wrong" order for inputs ... a tiny bit confusing maybe, but just saying so in the answer seems like enough to me.

Comment: Two. It would golf two code.

Comment: Aw, I was hoping this would be about a short program that can do some simple golfing transformation(s) on other code.

Comment: I am going to have the "jabber", "wock" one stuck in my head, now.

Comment: It doesn't quite fit the pattern, but I'm fond of "How many dice would a dyed die dye if a dyed die could dye dice?"

Comment: Shouldn't the invariant space between "chuck" and "wood" in the example's third form also be `code-quoted`?

Comment: "How much would a would a would ahow much how much if a would ahow much could how much would a?" - ROFL

Answer (score 41):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```python
"How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?".format
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7NCsIwDL77FCGnTYpMvAni1XeoO4x2tUXXjK5lyNiz1zUKHsL3R5JvfEdL/pTN5Z7xRjMMSVlYmhVmSi8NXeHLcYUyzvy14piTZr3iwVAYupg32DaDnsB5kBJnIo0CUNmkntgKiUUxeYS@9yjQUpp6dn4v2fs2wbY97wDG4HysTLXn03WdPw)

I mean, if the shoe fits..

*Thanks to **manatwork** for catching a typo*

*Thanks to **Remco Haszing** for the excellent -3 bytes idea*

I am running off of the assumption that this would still be a valid submission (because man, it's too cool not to try). If OP could clarify whether this is acceptable (because I haven't *written* a function, per se), that would be appreciated.

Update: Blessing received, all is good :)

---

**Previous version:**

```python
lambda a,b:f"How much {a} would a {a+b} {b} if a {a+b} could {b} {a}?"
```

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but the automatic format string is not readily available in python versions prior to 3.6

Comment: @M.Herzkamp So?

Comment: @ruohola I think M.Herzkamp is trying to say the title to this answer should be "Python 3.6" rather than "Python 3".

Comment: Even shorter and Python 2 compatible (67 bytes): `"How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {1}{0} could {1} {0}?".format`. This returns a function bound to the unformatted string.

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but since `print("How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?".format("wood","chuck"))` generates the desired output, I see no reason not to accept it :)

Answer (score 25):

## T-SQL, 82 bytes

```sql
SELECT'How much '+w+' would a '+w+c+' '+c+' if a '+w+c+' could '+c+' '+w+'?'FROM t
```

Input is taken from pre-existing table \$t\$ with columns \$w\$ and \$c\$, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

One byte longer, but for some reason slightly more pleasing:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('How much 1 would a 12 2 if a 12 could 2 1?',1,w),2,c)FROM t
```

This version works on a subset of inputs that *don't* include the numeral `2` in the first word \$w\$.

Because I'm in SQL, I can pre-load all examples into the table, and run them all at once:

[image]

Comment: +1000000 virtual trains for megatrain

Comment: I assume that "w" and "c" stand for "wood" and "chuck" respectively :P

Comment: This can be done in 67 bytes in Oracle as called from SQL*Plus (so no table): `select'How much &1 would a &1&2 &2 if a &1&2 could &2 &1?'from dual`

Answer (score 17):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 50 bytes

```bash
echo How much $2 {would,$1\ if}\ a\ $2$1 could $@?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BI79cIbc0OUNBxUihujy/NCdFR8UwRiEzrTZGITEGKKpiqJAMElZQcbD///9/ckZpcvb/8vz8FAA)

-5 bytes due to help from comments below.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BI79cIbc0OUNBxUihPL80J0UhEchUMVQAosw0GCcZLKPiYP/////kjNLk7P/l@fkpAA)

Comment: [-2 bytes more](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BI79cIbc0OUNBxUihujy/NCdFR8UwRiEzrTZGITEGKKpiqJAMElZQcbD///9/ckZpcvb/8vz8FAA)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: Your edits are clever, but they require reversing the order of the input parameters from the original challenge.

Comment: @Grimy: A good use of $@, but it requires reversing the order of the input.

Comment: You added an unnecessary backslash when adapting Nahuel's golf. [Here's 53](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BI79cIbc0OUNBxVChujy/NCdFR8UoRiEzrTZGITEGKKpipJAMElYAMlQM7f///1@en5/yPzmjNDkbAA).(Though really it should be 50, nothing stops you from taking the first word as $2 and the second word as $1.)

Comment: @Grimy: I see the comment on the challenge from original poster allowing the reversing of the parameters. I'm updating the answer to the excellent answer of 50 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate how this works? The brace expansion and backslashes are doing my head in!

Comment: @roblogic: The backslashes quote the spaces to avoid word splitting on the spaces, and the curly braces are expanded twice to form two words, once with each string inside the braces, and the characters that trail the braces (but part of the word) are added to the end of each string. Adding square braces to help visualize the word splitting: “[a{bc,de}f]” becomes two words: “[abcf] [adef]”. So “[{would,$1\ if}\ a\ $2$1]” becomes “[would\ a\ $2$1] [$1\ if\ a\ $2$1]”

Answer (score 16):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>33</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

-1 thanks to [recursive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/527/recursive)!

```
¢èO∩sP↑å♥|1╧ì}ò♂xb■δå«█Γ╨╦►Q²
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9b8a4fef73501886037c31cf8d7d950b7862feeb86aedbe2d0cb1051fd&i=wood%0Achuck%0A%0Acode%0Agolf%0A%0A%22%22+%22fish%22%0A%0A%22fish%22+%22%22%0A%0A%22%22+%22%22%0A%0A%22++%22+%22+++++%22%0A%0Awould+a%0Ahow+much&a=1&m=1)

Push each component to the stack in reverse order, then join all with spaces.

#### Unpacked (35 bytes) and explanation:

```
X'?+;`IM'`x;+Y`~^$`,y`75\`x`Q)("`LJ
X                                      Set register X to the first word
                                       "wood"
 '?+                                   Append a question mark, popping from the input stack
                                       "wood?"
    ;                                  Peek from input stack and push to main stack
                                       "chuck" "wood?"
     `IM'`                             Literal "could"
                                       "could" "chuck" "wood?"
          x;+Y                         Peek register x. Peek input. Concatenate. Set register Y.
                                       "woodchuck" "could" "chuck" "wood?"
              et cetera, ad nauseam
                                  LJ   Listify the stack and join with spaces
                                       Implicit print
```

Everything between `` is compressed string literal. That comma is vital. The last time I read from the input stack, I must pop rather than peek to avoid an extra "chuck" on the end of my output.

You'll notice that I put both inputs on the same line for a few test cases, and that they're in reverse order. This is necessary in order to take empty strings or strings of spaces as input.

#### <s>27</s> 26 bytes with restrictions on input

```
å▓Zf╢7)╪♪²p╞8ó╪l▼]<¡REïSèΣ
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86b25a66b63729d80dfd70c638a2d86c1f5d3cad52458b538ae4&i=wood%0Achuck%0A%0Acode%0Agolf%0A%0A%22%22+%22fish%22%0A%0A%22fish%22+%22%22%0A%0A%22%22+%22%22%0A%0A%22++%22+%22+++++%22%0A%0Awould+a%0Ahow+much&a=1&m=1)

Just like [@dzaima's SOGL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190327/73884), this will fail if the first input contains the lowercase letter 'y'. Pushes the string "How much b would a by y if a by could y b?", then makes a pair of replacements.

Comment: "You'll notice that I put both inputs on the same line for a few test cases, and that they're in reverse order. This is necessary to take empty strings or strings of spaces as input." 

If you use no input separator, [the input will be undisturbed](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=m%25&i=%0A+%0A+++++++++++++++++++++&a=1), empty strings and all.  It just makes it kind of awkward to show multiple test cases.

Comment: Additionally, it seems the leading `,` in your 31 byte solution can be removed.  The following `+` implicitly pops from the input stack, so the behavior is identical.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript, 70 bytes

Boring!

```javascript
a=>b=>`How much ${a} would a ${a+b} ${b} if a ${a+b} could ${b} ${a}?`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYo7DoAgEESvQogFxOgN0NZjuC7gD12jIoXx7PhpbOZl3swAB2y49suezaRNtCqCKhpV1BUFNnnsWHLCxQJ5pxm8JW2uB0/09hf47Z9@/2UdkeaNnMkdtcIKHog0l4Jj53HkUsYb)

Mildly less boring!

```javascript
a=>"How much 0 would a 01 1 if a 01 could 1 0?".replace(/\d/g,x=>a[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBDoIwEADAr2z21CYI7QOKV/@AHDbbFtDKErCW39dEb5N50IcO3pftfVnFhxpdJdfjTQq8Ms9goEhOHgiMBQtL/It/acFcsd3DloiD6u6@m5rT9TSco64s6yEptEkmFdWARcRjgzxnfuKodf0C)

Comment: Are you allowed to output a curried function like in that first example?

Comment: @Feathercrown, I'm not *outputting* a function, I'm *calling* both (e.g., `f(a)(b)`) as you can see in the TIO. But yes, our consensuses to allow curried functions and I think we're close to a consensus on allowing a function to actually be returned.

Comment: By output I meant the code returns a function when evaluated; no calling is in the given code that counts for bytes. I was just checking to make sure currying was okay, since I've only ever seen noncurried functions returned.

Answer (score 7):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>32</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
^.](9V;⅜‛°@Ε¬tπs%.½Ω‘⁽ b,ŗ y,ŗ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVFLiU1RCUyODlWJTNCJXUyMTVDJXUyMDFCJUIwQCV1MDM5NSVBQ3QldTAzQzBzJTI1LiVCRCV1MDNBOSV1MjAxOCV1MjA3RCUyMGIlMkMldTAxNTclMjB5JTJDJXUwMTU3,inputs=d29vZCUwQWNodWNr,v=0.12)

The first input can't contain the letter `y`, which seems to leave a reasonable subset of ASCII (and unicode) left.

`½ouiīZģ9Ο|ΧyΚ⅞ō÷Jeq(‚7‘` is a compressed string of `"how much b would a by y if a by could y b?"` (characters chosen so the required words are all in the top 512 words of the dictionary which compress better), then `b` is replaced with the 1st input and `y` with the 2nd.

Comment: +2 internet points for one of the most random restrictions I can remember (in your shorter solution)

Comment: @GregMartin Not _that_ random. I don't speak SOGL, but I ended up with the same restriction on 'n' when sequencing two replacements `y -> wood` and `n -> chuck`. A tenth of a Dignity Point says that's the case here as well.

Comment: I think the main spirit of this question is to be open about allowing solutions ... only as an aside might I opine that not allowing an actual letter in an input is a bit sketchy. Anyway: why is `b` not allowed in the first input yet `e` is ok in the second input?

Comment: @GregMartin whoops, I meant to say that the 1st input can't contain `e`, as otherwise it'd be replaced with the 2nd input in the 2nd replacement

Comment: Is it not possible for replacement target to be non-alpha to avoid having to ban an alpha from the input?

Comment: @WGroleau I do have [36 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTkzJTI3JXUyNTY0JXUyMjY0WWJXJXUwM0JFJXUwMzk3JXUwM0I5JXUwMTIzRFcldTAxMTMlQUJEJXUyMTkzJXUwM0Exd0gldTAzQjY2eXgldTAzOTUlQjMldTIwMTgldTIwN0QlMjAlNUQlMkMldTAxNTclMjAlMjklMkMldTAxNTc_,inputs=d29vZCUwQWNodWNr,v=0.12) with the forbidden character being `")"`, but as can be seen, that's 4 bytes longer because `b` and `be` are in the top 512 words, which compress better

Comment: @WGroleau writing that, I finally understood why it was so better - I had thought that SOGL compressed the top 256 words, but the top 512 also has the letter `"y"`, so that's another -2

Comment: In English, the letters ‘e’ and ‘t’ are the two worst to forbid.  ‘y’ is way down the list.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>90</s> <s>77</s> 76 bytes

-13 thanks to Sumner18
-1 thanks to Giuseppe

```r
function(x,y,`[`=gsub)2[y,1[x,"How much 1 would a 12 2 if a 12 could 2 1?"]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc2xDoIwEIDh3ae4dIKkDjBrXB2cXAmJbblCtfYI2BSeHluL292X/3LTpuF03LR36mPIFQtf@aN5nPvZy7JuVl41C2dXCvD2aoAKAnnbgYCqhhqMzpP6YQ3VhbXtpgsWiDrGmRq8erHyEEWKKcILccz7mxyuUSTaT5ZJGBdBC2szDMKkG@X3oJ8QUzGQnzHTU0iJKQr0fzQahxHEONo9upOMcKOw74q6VPRkNSu3Lw)

Comment: Can do a double `gsub` for -13 bytes instead. https://tio.run/##Nc2xDoMgEIDhvU9xYZKEDjg36dqhU98A8FAqckYl6NNbFLvdffkvN@0WHvfdxmAWR6FaxcbbOeqqFps4BylWwV6UYIimAwmJom9AgayhBmfLZE6sQT4Z57utWCJqmGCmi6Zn/JZFqylDjziWfaCAWxaNfikyKRcyWOV9gU6548bEK2gnxKPoKM5Y6Ku0xiNK9H80uoAZ1Dj6K/qQzvCmdO2GmqNoyVvG9x8

Comment: @Sumner18 Thanks. Yeah, `gsub` definitely makes more sense.

Comment: If you feel like using `pryr`, [you can get it down to 73](https://tio.run/##Nc2xDoMgEIDhvU9xYZKEDjiaJl07dOobAB5qRY9gCfXpLYrd7r78lwubhdt182ENTWOrbom6qsUqjkGKr2APSjBF04OERNG1oEDWUMNgy2QOrEHeGed8sxVLRC0TzPTRjIxfsmgVMoyIvuwTzbhm0eg@RYIa5gxWOVegV8N@Y@IZdAFxL3qKCxZ6K61xjxL9H/lhxgzKe3dGL9IZnpTO3VC7Fx05y/j2Aw).

Comment: You should specify that you assume the input `x` doesn't include the character `2`; it fails in this case ([TIO](https://tio.run/##JchBCoAgEAXQq3xmpTAtnHXQtmvUhCVURiXp6Q1q93hn9Wib6tOud4i7yVzsfKXRCBf@4Dgz9fHBlnSBwxPTOmGAEwiC/6VfClxH1lZvSIjpGJRsfQE "R – Try It Online")).

Comment: [76 with aliasing of gsub](https://tio.run/##Nc2xDoIwEIDh3ae4dIKkDjBrXB2cXAmJbblCtfYI2BSeHluL292X/3LTpuF03LR36mPIFQtf@aN5nPvZy7JuVl41C2dXCvD2aoAKAnnbgYCqhhqMzpP6YQ3VhbXtpgsWiDrGmRq8erHyEEWKKcILccz7mxyuUSTaT5ZJGBdBC2szDMKkG@X3oJ8QUzGQnzHTU0iJKQr0fzQahxHEONo9upOMcKOw74q6VPRkNSu3Lw)

Answer (score 5):

## ZX Spectrum Basic, 87 bytes

Just for completeness, straightforward implementation:

```
INPUT a$,b$: PRINT "How much ";a$;" would a ";a$;b$;"  ";b$;" if a ";a$;b$;" could ";b$;" ";a$;"?"
```

Using the `IF` keyword (1 byte) golfes it down by 3 bytes, but breaks the "same capitalization" condition:

```
INPUT a$,b$: PRINT "How much ";a$;" would a ";a$;b$;"  ";b$;" IF a ";a$;b$;" could ";b$;" ";a$;"?"
```

Comment: It's nice to show slightly-cheaty versions too :)

Comment: Oh, Speccy! To be young again...

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 59 bytes

```
{i,j->"How much $i would a $i$j $j if a $i$j could $j $i?"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITP9imG4iGBWvQqWhERxGu9iYcYrV2bJqWmLVL67LH@grCwM98yw2bGKtKuFgqNMSeZVjKbgsW2JH0J8N4co@gjMXctBddR5G9Mg7ySKYbURyt1gujl8Ip@KPka@bo8KS38ziWVRi5IMzHFsizFffaujThabyDCxJRrIdMWRU@t0uz3FCMb3gpFlvnw@X58CPBPJgfO0Xmdc7E912dszfHmdpRjZUz2AA)

Comment: Kotlin sounds like a lot of fun!

Comment: @M.Herzkamp it sure is!

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 72 bytes

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo"How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAko3VUEnVUkmJtVRKL0susU5Mz8pU88ssVckuTMxRUEhXK80tzUhQSgUyVJAUgykyDcZLBMiDRRHsl6////5fn56f8T84oTc4GAA)

Or:

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 72 bytes

```php
How much <?=![,$a,$b]=$argv,"$a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fI79cIbc0OUPBxt5WMVpHJVFHJSnWViWxKL1MR0klUaE8vzQnRSFRQSVRJUkBiDLTYJxksAxINNFeyfr////l@fkp/5MzSpOzAQ)

Input from command line, output to `STDOUT`.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 72 bytes

```javascript
(a,b)=>['How much',a,'would a',c=a+b,b,'if a',c,'could',b,a+'?'].join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7BDoIwDAbgu0@xWyFUziYGvfoOxISuOhkiNcDg8WfH0dBb/@9P044Wmnj03/m4nKKrYkZo8@pSw01W8wncAhLCKqF/GALkigqLFsG7bUXgRKARFXCFe9mJHxrTRJZhkv5Z9vLKXKYXRFvAbeA35Pn58Oct@TF5mPfU@UkfgT3SeNMdMkbR6CSMPw)

The variable assignment actually saves 0 bytes, but I figured I'd keep it in just to make this *slightly* unique.

Comment: But one big template string is 1 character shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrBDoIwDAbgu0/Rg8lYRM8mBr36GJTi3HRaAgwOhmefZd7Memj6/18fOOFAvevG/XSMpooFlo2uzvWVZ3gFsrD94AIzB98CSqAKd80ihyxnftUClDyV6/@ljsTvgf3t4PlemELNzK0qFdlAT6X1afPnFl2/ehhzatxgRXMkddIMAQiCzIrxCw "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online").

Comment: @manatwork I tried this but included an extra space by mistake :P Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>37</s> <s>35</s> <s>31</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
“Howƒ×1€Þ a ÿ0€¬ a ÿƒˆ01?“T$ú‡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMcj/zyY5MOTzd81LTm8DyFRIXD@w2AzENrwMxjk063GRjaA5WFqBze9ahh4f//0Url@fkpSjpKyRmlydlKsQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NY6xTsMwEIZf5eQ5Q/MEWRmYEFvUwXYujambixKMla1i6IyysCAk9j4BCxKWuvAWeZFwrtOb/u/Tf7qjQSqDy8sY3goB82kCUSzz8eOO/GUK7/n8eg6fICH8bDj@nq/xMv2dNnnBtccxD9/z8WvJlrIUnqgSmdCN03uxzaAUSvYs9ohd4gO1OLJRaJ@T6aVpWdTS2iQaaeKOdmth1yPGRkNuwKSepFIYS55uhzrTIgvZdXYtPZBicU9@ZU1VbOzI1knUZmhYJIgvRL5BCgAcIU5iT85WIK/feDg4zQvbfw).

Or alternatively:

```
…a ÿªðì₁“Howƒ×2€Þ65€¬6ƒˆ52?“r‡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyRIXD@w@tOrzh8JpHTY2PGuZ45Jcfm3R4utGjpjWH55mZAqlDa8yOTTrdZmpkD5QuetSw8P//aKXy/PwUJR2l5IzS5GylWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LY6hbsMwEIZfxTIOqtTSkIGCodGowHacxKubi5K6VlhW0AcIKZkmjQxMAXuDSbVUsrfwi2T2NSb3f//9d2foGFdyPvUpJf4yEpr2T7Mfvhhxv7dv9@Mmf37zw/sW7H1015U/T@5jsw7lNm3u499lvUpDu/XD55zMWUYtQE4TKioj9nSXZLRswdTRqqBEg7M20F7KBvEAteyDwaU@otEyVQcumNbIFVNxQJjjsk/KGteZTqLzyjiXMWJhudmoWgZmTaMfkRfggZ/BPlBAHvsl6AK5UF0VGHU8HXHRWAkJisSHaMHonDD8hCUHI0J69w8).

-5 bytes thanks to *@Grimy*.

Takes a list of two items, `wood` as first value and `chuck` as second.

**Explanation:**

```python
“Howƒ×1€Þ a ÿ0€¬ a ÿƒˆ01?“
        # Push dictionary string "How much1 would a ÿ0 if a ÿ could01?",
        # where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with the (implicit) input-list,
        # implicitly joined together to a single string
        #  i.e. ["wood","chuck"] → "How much1 would a woodchuck0 if a woodchuck could01?"
T       # Push 10
 $      # Push the input-list and 1
  ù     # Pad the strings in the input-list with this 1 amount of leading spaces
        #  ["wood","chuck"] → [" wood"," chuck"]
   ‡    # Transliterate the 10 ([1,0]) to these strings in the sentence
        #  → "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)

…a ÿ    # Push dictionary string "a ÿ",
        # where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with the (implicit) input-list,
        # implicitly joined together to a single string
        #  i.e. ["wood","chuck"] → "a woodchuck"
    ª   # Append this to the (implicit) input-list: ["wood","chuck","a woodchuck"]
     ðì # Prepend a space before each string: [" wood"," chuck"," a woodchuck"]
₁       # Push builtin 256
“Howƒ×2€Þ65€¬6ƒˆ52?“
        # Push dictionary string "How much2 would65 if6 could52?"
r       # Reverse the values on the stack
 ‡      # Transliterate [2,5,6] to [" wood"," chuck"," a woodchuck"] in the string
        #  → "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?"
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“Howƒ×1€Þ a ÿ0€¬ a ÿƒˆ01?“` is `"How much1 would a ÿ0 if a ÿ could01?"` and `“Howƒ×2€Þ65€¬6ƒˆ52?“` is `"How much2 would65 if6 could52?"`.

Comment: [31](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f69Aqw8O7HjU1PmqY45FffmzS4elGj5rWHJ4HJB41LDMzBdKH1kA5xyadbjM1sgcqLXrUsPD//2il8vz8FCUdpeSM0uRspVgA)

Comment: [30](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMcj/zyY5MOTzd81LTm8DyFRIXD@w2AzENrwMxjk063GRjaA5WFqBze9ahh4f//0Url@fkpSjpKyRmlydlKsQA)

Comment: @Grimy Very nice! I really like both of those. Ingenious idea of using the `$ù` like that to save the additional byte, thanks.

Comment: [Alternate 30](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyRIXD@w@tMjy861FT46OGOR755ccmHZ5u9KhpzeF5ZqZA6tAas2OTTreZGtkDpYseNSz8/z9aqTw/P0VJRyk5ozQ5WykWAA). I'm not finding any 29, so your explanation is safe for now ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 78 bytes

```
"How much "p1btpt" would a "ptpz2btp" "ptbtp" if a "ptpbtp" could "ptbtp" "ptp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/1/JI79cIbc0OUNBqcAwqaSgREmhPL80J0UhEShQUlBlBBRTAjHBdGYaVBzMSwYrhMmBhP///1@en5/yPzmjNDkbAA)

Takes the input as command-line arguments.

### Bonus: 91 bytes

```
"How much "p1bztp" would a "p1bztp2bztp" "p2bztp" if a "p1bztp2bztp" could "p2bztp" "p1bztp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/1/JI79cIbc0OUNBqcAwqaqkQEmhPL80J0UhESZgBBFVgjEy0zDkksE6lBBKwZL///@H0GBhAA)

Gives output resembling itself when given inputs `1bztp` and `2bztp`

Comment: Said this out loud, now I need to clean all the spit off my monitor.

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```rust
|a,b|print!("How much {} would a {0}{} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?",a,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY29DsIgFIX3PsXpnSBhqLMxrr5GpcU2UjAVwkB5doRqHHun8/Pl3NW/XVYGSz8bxhEblNOjg8Ilb724b691Nq5ldLMBi5cTYkKwXg/oEbtUXDwlzOpni5Z7W1UJriTKCs/nfVkxCtYOJEBy8vJJ/JvvT7RpGf9z0g5j5R5WqwOsIgc1UIFqUKkm5Q8)

Using [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188625/85842), which let's you skip the formatting index once per item to format.

Also using `print!()`, because it's one byte shorter than building a string with `format!()` and returning it.

Answer (score 4):

## Applesoft BASIC, <del>77</del> 76 bytes

```
1INPUTA$,B$:?"How much "A$" would a "A$B$" "B$" if a "A$B$" could "B$" "A$"?
```

The above may not look like proper BASIC, but Applesoft allows for a few shortcuts when using the `PRINT` statement:

- Use of `?` in place of `PRINT` when entering the statement
- Concatenation characters (either `;` or `+`) may be omitted
- If the statement ends in a quoted string, the final quote may be omitted *Thanks, [Mark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/19365/mark)!*

The line number is required, or the `INPUT` statement will cause an `?ILLEGAL DIRECT ERROR`

Comment: Can you omit the trailing quotation mark?  Applesoft Basic is a Microsoft Basic derivative, and many versions of Microsoft Basic let you omit the closing quote on a string if it ends the line.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks for tip!

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 65 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)"How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a`?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcxBCsMgEAXQfU4xhKHTQvEGpdseoxMTUaoYTAcXoWe32liYxfz34a8xL2mzi/cFzW0vKycOZ@QrTpfxETME0RaQIUfxM3B9cYJ6zvyD/jVN@Xkfy2cYTmiAcowzAWkr@kUHWXapkbw7GLfZCj1RhyNJUEpR26nzVL4)

The only thing of note is that you have to escape the question mark because those can be valid parts of a PowerShell identifier

Answer (score 3):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), <strike>165</strike> <strike>148</strike> 133 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.Write("How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?\n",a[0],a[1]);}}
```

Thanks to [Andrew Baumher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77057/andrew-baumher) for telling me about interpolated strings!! 

EDIT: Full class now added
EDIT: Thanks to [Kenneth K.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3505/kenneth-k) for giving me a few tips for shortening it
EDIT: Thanks to Andrew again for telling me that using interpolated string is actually longer in this scenario.

Comment: Using modern C#'s '$' ([interpolated strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)), you can save a few bytes by replacing {0} with {a[0]}, or better yet, taking two variables instead of an array so you can just use a and b. So as to not steal your thunder, so to speak, I'll add it as a different version of c#

Comment: Wow didn't know about that! Thanks for the info

Comment: @canttalkjustcode generally, functions are accepted. For C#, this includes lambdas: `a=>System.Console.WriteLine($"How much {a[0]} would a {a[0]}{a[1]} {a[1]} if a {a[0]}{a[1]} could {a[1]} {a[0]}?")`

Comment: This IS true but it's only in C# Interactive that you can use lambda expressions like this. In full C# you need a full lamda statement. A simple void statement would be faster as shown in the following snippet:

Comment: `void M(string[]a){System.Console.WriteLine($"How much {a[0]} would a {a[0]}{a[1]} {a[1]} if a {a[0]}{a[1]} could {a[1]} {a[0]}?");}`
`System.Func<string>M=a=>System.Console.WriteLine($"How much {a[0]} would a {a[0]}{a[1]} {a[1]} if a {a[0]}{a[1]} could {a[1]} {a[0]}?");`
`System.Action<string>M=a=>System.Console.WriteLine($"How much {a[0]} would a {a[0]}{a[1]} {a[1]} if a {a[0]}{a[1]} could {a[1]} {a[0]}?");`

Comment: And to as why I am doing classes instead of functions? Just because most people using C# on this site do it too. Its just to keep fair competition

Comment: @JoKing It takes it from standard input.

Comment: `int M` instead of `void M` saves you a byte. And you don't need the `public`--neither class nor function. Also, `Console.Write` with a trailing `\n` saves a couple of bytes.

Comment: But int M requires me to have a return value right?

Comment: Ooh, sorry, you're correct.

Comment: Learned about interpolated strings from other code golfers myself, actually. Just doing my part, i guess, lol. Though if you're using a[0] and a[1], it might actually be shorter to use {0} and {1}. You'll save 24 bytes in the text section, then lose 10 bytes defining those values, for a net gain of 14. It works better with single character variables.

Comment: It's crazy. Have learned so much on this site in 3 days. Using {0} and {1} is indeed shorter. Why did the byte count decrease in the first place then?

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 107 bytes

```
Function q(a,b)
b=b&" "
c="ould "
q="How much "&a&" w"&c&"a "&a&b&b&"if a "&a&b&"c"&c&b&a&"?"
End Function
```

Should run as VBScript too, I used two shortcuts: "ould " is repeating and "chuck" never appears without an additional space.

Comment: You can get this down to 75 bytes by converting to immediate window function as `a=[A1]:b=[B1&" "]:o="ould ":?"How much "a" w"o"a "a b b"if a "a b"c"o b a"?`. Takes input from `[A1]` and `[B1]`. We have [Tips for golfing in VBA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba) that you consider taking a look into.

Comment: Then you could take input named range `[A]` and `[B]` as inputs bringing it down to 73. I don't quite understand how yours goes through though, feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: That unfortunately goes against how STDIN and STDOUT are defined for Excel VBA - you can use any unnamed range on the activesheet, but are not permitted to use named ranges per an earlier decison by the community

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```haskell
a?b=a++" "++b
a!b="How much"?a?"would a"?a++b?b?"if a"?a++b?"could"?b?a++"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcw9DoAgFAPg3VNg48YZyFsd3DzBA0GN/BiVcHzExa3tl3Tj@7De18qkFUsJASl1x71WGFMRIZsNxISSsl8Et9ycNGF3f4P5EG39Hgg18B7VmZ/5uaY4NF4seqzJO9QX)

First try, so I hope I didn't break any rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 80 bytes

```python
lambda n:'How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?'.format(*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZ6tenp@foq6jnpxRmpytzpVmG/M/JzE3KSVRIc9KPSO/XCG3NDlDodqgVqE8vzQnRSERxK42rFUA4cw0BD8ZLA2WMai1V9dLyy/KTSzR0MrT/F9QlJlXopGmkaep@R8A)

when in rome, use str format.

**Edited** using squid's trick.

Comment: Wouldn't this be invalid? It's a snippet - not a function or a program, right?

Comment: Yeah; needs a `lambda n:` before it, and can drop the `print()`.

Comment: You should change your code to print `How much ...` instead of `how much ...`.

Comment: It should suffice to just define an anonymous function as `'how much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?'.format`.

Comment: @xnor Still pretty new, what would the TIO look like for that then? I'd think that without some way to pass in an arg it would be runnable.

Comment: @Tryer [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzXz0jv1whtzQ5Q6HaoFahPL80J0UhEcSuNqxVAOHMNAQ/GSwNljGotVfXS8svyk0s@V9QlJlXopGmoV6en5@irqOenFGanK2uqfkfAA "Python 3 – Try It Online"), see also [my tip about object methods](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260)

Comment: I didn't even know you could define a function in that way to have it take arguments without using lambda. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>$"How much {x} would a {x+y} {y} if a {x+y} could {y} {x}?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqOAwoHQdnZptv8rbO0qbe1UlDzyyxVyS5MzFKorahXK80tzUhQSgWztylqFaiDOTINzk8GSIEGgUnul/9ZcAUDTSjTSNJTK8/NTlDQ1lJIzSpOzlTQ1kaSC8pNAMj755akgif8A)

same as everyone else, except C#. 
-1 byte by using currying strat a=>b=>c instead of (a,b)=>c

Comment: Change function signature from `Func<string,string,string>` to `Func<string,Func<string,string>>` and change `(x,y)` to `x=>y=>`

Comment: Seems like a cheap tactic, but meta discussion says it's fair game, so might as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPKŒP“µkþ¿µ‘ị“þ>Æƈ)taJṖ;ạʂ\4S%dñl»Ỵ¤ż”?
```

A full program accepting a list of two strings.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWAAn/9qZWxsef//xZJQS8WSUOKAnMK1a8O@wr/CteKAmOG7i@KAnMO@PsOGxogpdGFK4bmWO@G6ocqCXDRTJWTDsWzCu@G7tMKkxbzigJ0/////Wydncm91bmQnLCAnaG9nJ10)**

...Or (also a full program accepting a list of two strings)

```
⁽4ṀDBịs€2ṭ€€⁶“þ>Æƈ)taJṖ;ạʂ\4S%dñl»Ỵ¤ż”?
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R416ThzsbXJwe7u4uftS0xujhzrVACoQatz1qmHN4n93htmMdmiWJXg93TrN@uGvhqaYYk2DVlMMbcw7tfrh7y6ElR/c8aphr/////2j19KL80rwUdR0F9Yz8dPVYAA)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

```
StringRiffle@{How,much,#,would,a,c=#<>#2,#2,if,a,c,could,#2,#<>"?"}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxC8MgFATgPT/jCZleKWROrGPH0o6hg33RKom1BMVB/O3WFG657@CcDEY5GSzJqqf6CLv9vO9W602JfPUJXSSDDJOP24ISaWIjZwO2WH10pP9y0MjhAqWvt/YRZnbiWgj27M8idxmS9wsgkIm0QsEmL7k3WJX6QulK/QE)

Answer (score 2):

# [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 78 bytes

```c
#define f(a,b)"How much "#a" would a "#a#b" "#b" if a "#a#b" could "#b" "#a"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYkxDsIwDEV3TmE5SyKFE3Rg5Rquk7SR3BhBowyoZw8tSGX5T/89vrJQmXo3IaZcIiRLfnR41wZL5RnQEELTKgHoOGbEHfvk9Bf87fhrhDfsuaywUC7WwfsCj7q@bLJzFFHf9CnBueHUrCH6SSUdcusf)

Using stringification

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 85 bytes

```c
f(a,b){printf("How much %s would a %s%s %s if a %s%s could %s %s?",a,a,b,b,a,b,b,a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUxLCoMwEN17imGgkEB6Ahfd9hpxYjQwOqKGLMSzp9PQ8obH@wyPnhNRrdF4N9hr29N6RoNvKbBkmuFxQJHMAbxKNXop/g21pqUvdF4xKH5s@7vqGCw@rcbC1YHuziOzoAMssnNA23ew5fMw2KQ@kIQRHU7C8Rvd9QM)

Thanks to @ErikF suggestion to use gcc, btw I've seen that clang accepts f(*a,*b){ // which is 2 Bytes expensive anyway

Saved 2 thanks to @ceilingcat.

Comment: For the second submission, if you use gcc instead of clang you can remove the parameter types (85 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUxLCoMwEN17imGgkEB6Ahfd9hpxYjQwOqKGLMSzp9PQ8obH@wyPnhNRrdF4N9hr29N6RoNvKbBkmuFxQJHMAbxKNXop/g21pqUvdF4xKH5s@7vqGCw@rcbC1YHuziOzoAMssnNA23ew5fMw2KQ@kIQRHU7C8Rvd9QM "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: You could also use `printf` positional arguments [TIO](https://tio.run/##bYy9DoMgFEZ3n@LmRhJI6NCuDl37GvYiaopeIxIG47NTIOnW7fs5OXQbiVKystdvdW77vB5W4osjLIEmEB4iB2egB3Fvfa7i0XqY7W8ojSpRY9meqIusu1KWwdLPq1RwNpC9kdmgBqQp0AdV18AWDi@xxvxPg3NcgMi7M38AYjOgxpGdLdOVvg) (but it's still 85 bytes). Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 95 bytes

```r
function(a,b)cat("How much ",a," would a ",a,b," ",b," if a ",a,b," could ",b," ",a,"?",sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCoAgEEWvIrMZhbmCtO0aOiVK5UQlHt9EWrT58N7//2rBtlAyP0myduQNu0fDLFUdhaMCcgSqStkX5Qb5zjAyhZ/iMYGv7qcJ6F5Pi2ha0FhFFiTkWHjr5gU)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your TIO link seems to link to the wrong code? In addition, as far as I can tell, you've assumed the input to be in the variables `a` and `b`, which is disallowed under our [Default Input/Output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: Thanks @cairdcoinheringaahing for the comment. I rewrote it in function form, hope it complies with the rules now.

Comment: [Using `stringr` saves you a few.](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEEWvErNRcU4QRNtuUdOEJZUDpnh8s0W799/nxeqG6nLg5CVowhUXuwxPij7sse8bzGyYkoZJSndnPgAJoUi@to4a27U14N0/gL8LmiQLI5jqtCoim0LFR@ZTmfoC)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>56</s> 59 bytes

```apl
{∊'How much '⍺' would a '⍺⍵' '⍵' if a '⍺⍵' could '⍵' '⍺'?'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdAxagMxEAXQPqdQN5WrHCBFGhsCBjsXkLTSSrG8I9YWwhhXBhMMa5LC50iVxmWOootsZpQE0ozm6QsNjIxh0uxkwHYc9@X1DFPMYp20E1CGG4iMKTRCVpXhE7ih6u3/O10fwV9@gwc4jLac3spwKZfrbF7Ox6@P@3J6Jy0Xj1Sfp7PlCBmxAQvaJb2CO1CyJ62MiYQ1dmZHVCZsib30HcnKEEhOen6qE0dtbwxnDtPGkF@kUobjjPXb6DtDkjEGjheoSE@YGRobzloMlmT9xpGo41GM2lEVdAghqPvdSJ33syr4Bg)

Pretty straightforward dfn. Saves a byte by cutting `∊` if we're allowed to return an array of strings instead of a single string.

3 bytes added because I'd forgotten to add the question mark.

Comment: Did you count the Greek letters as one byte?

Comment: @TomášZato yes. Dyalog APL's glyphs can be represented in a single byte using [Adám's Single Byte Character Sheet](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS) which is standard for APL answers here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>44</s> 39 bytes

```
[`How Û2`U`Ùd a`N=¬V`if a`N`Öd`VU+'?]
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=W2BIb3cg2zJgVWDZAmQgYWBOPaxWYGlmIGFgTmDWAmRgVlUrJz9d&input=Indvb2QiCiJjaHVjayI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```
⁾be,y“Ø[gœıJ9°m.OṚuHlh3Ƥ⁾$ɲ0øḲʂṇHẎṆȥ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVcAqP9qZWxsef//4oG@YmUseeKAnMOYW2fFk8SxSjnCsG0uT@G5mnVIbGgzxqTigb4kybIww7jhuLLKguG5h0jhuo7huYbIpcK7////Indvb2QiLCJjaHVjayI)

A full program taking a pair of strings as its argument and printing the processed string. A monadic link could be formed by adding a `F` to the end (thanks to @JonathanAllan for pointing this out).

I’ve now switched to using "b" and "e" as placeholders, inspired by [@dzaima’s SOGL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190327/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too! This does mean that the first word can’t include the letter e.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 116 bytes

```forth
: x 2over type ; : y 2dup type ; : f ." How much "x ."  would a "x y ."  "y ."  if a "x y ."  could "y ."  "x ." ?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBDoMgDIbve4o/XHbaDh71sOteQxGGUQdBmPL0DgpGE0L7fYW0qdTWqcdHprDvNTZU@icsXDACDWoEVL03J0s8Gd56xey5AtsSYtV@6tEmDCRYDoO8Sk6vSin/fLEmNjW4M4h5cNfmh1pMy086hzkMt3GmeMXT3BYWZ9E9Q0y48nxkMEl2rSU3CmGKmvVXBJKdmFyRxCXPcJAcFnWtUp6lyW1pBaRVWU8s7X8)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
\ x = output the first word
: x               \ start a new word definition
  2over type      \ copy the "first" word to the top of the stack and print it
;                 \ end word definition

\ y = output the second word
: y               \ start a new word definition
  2dup type       \ copy the "second" word to the top of the stack and print it
;                 \ end word definition
  
: f               \ start a new word definition
  ." How much "x  \ print "How much " followed by the first word   
  ."  would a "x  \ print " would a " followed by the first word
  y ."  if a "x   \ print the second word followed by " if a " and then the first word
  y ."  could "y  \ print the second word, then " could " then the second word again
  ."  "x ." ?"    \ print a space followed by the first word, followed by "?"
;                 \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 82 bytes

```lua
a,b=...print((('How much x would a xy y if a xy could y x?'):gsub('.',{x=a,y=b})))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchBCoAgEADAr@xNBfEBgXTtG2qUkmVUiy7R2zeo2zAZHbPT3hpj9iNtl5RSDKXCiiFCg1owj@CgERCk6Vf4kqD1QnXziV4KI/TdrNNk/aOUYuZaysghYlhe)

Full program, take input as arguments.

Nothing special here. Hope that there's shorter version, but no obvious ways to shorten this at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), 58 bytes

```
echo "How much $1 could a $1$2 $2 if a $1$2 could $2 $1?"
```

Takes input as command line arguments.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BySO/XCG3NDlDQcVQITm/NCdFIRHIVDFSAKLMNBgHIgMSNbRX@v//f3l@fsr/5IzS5GwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), 56 bytes

```
@echo How much %1 would a %1%2 %2 if a %1%2 could %2 %1?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 67 bytes

```
'How much {0} would a {0}{1} {1} if a {0}{1} could {1} {0}?'.format
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX90jv1whtzQ5Q6HaoFahPL80J0UhEcSuNqxVAOHMNAQ/GSwNljGotVfXS8svyk0s@V9QlJlXopGmoV6en5@irqOgnpxRmpytrqn5HwA)

Point-free Python

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'd recommend you add a link to an online interpreter (like [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX90jv1whtzQ5Q6HaoFahPL80J0UhEcSuNqxVAOHMNAQ/GSwNljGotVfXS8svyk0s@V9QlJlXopGmoV6en5@irqOgnpxRmpytrqn5HwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")), so that others can verify your program!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion/link @cairdcoinheringaahing. I added the link, and I'll spend some time to familiarize myself with TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 56 bytes

```perl
/ /;$_="How much $' would a $'$` $` if a $'$` could $_?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQd9aJd5WySO/XCG3NDlDQUVdoTy/NCdFIRHIVElQAKLMNBgnGSyjEm@v9P9/ckZpcjZQbX7Kv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 61 bytes

```php
<?=strtr('How much 1 would a 12 2 if a 12 could 2 1?',$argv);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEhD3SO/XCG3NDlDwVChPL80J0UhUcHQSMFIITMNwkoGCxopGNqr66gkFqWXaVr///8/OT8l9X96fk4aAA)

Taking advantage of PHP's [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) array replacement mode. In `strtr`, when second parameter is an array, it replaces array keys with the corresponding value for that key.

PHP's `$argv` index/key `0` is always filled by PHP and starting from index `1`, command line arguments are put in it. So I pass the two words as command arguments which will be placed at index `1` and `2` in `$argv` and then the 1s and 2s in the string will be replaced by those values.

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 62 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>strtr('How much 0 would a 01 1 if a 01 could 1 0?',$a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs7CoUwEEbhPqv4i8BEsEhqX617EAuJjhHUCT5w@fFy7Q4fnBhiKpsYolKaq8S70UNW1ed1XIehVh5stw@weOReRwywDg4Lf@X/6GAbyn9fKpSafBBoNh15GSfKQbOsTH1WpBc)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/) (7.4), 63 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b)=>"How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlLCoAwDAX3OUWQQC14A61uvUZbGyuoyUZ6/PoB4S1m5mnWOkyaFYDYVT5b8h0F68ZmloLHFTOSxyLXvqB/kAI@2/iX@D1v9VNTe4AUsyBxa6IsyXRoVtnZ2L7e)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>69</s> 71 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{"How much #{a} would a #{a+b} #{b} if a #{a+b} could #{b} #{a}?"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6laySO/XCG3NDlDQbk6sVahPL80J0UhEcTRTqoFUkAiMw0hkAyWBwuD1Nsr1f4vKC0pVkiLVirPz09R0lFQSs4oTc5Wiv0PAA)

Comment: I'm afraid you misread the challenge. The 1st modal verb is “would”.

Comment: Noooooo my beautiful byte saves...

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
；⁸⁸⁷⁷“UＮｑＯ1Uŗ７_ＷW７eV↷:７⁹`3ｕ5G!oａ⁷⁴ｄ：⌐Ｑ‟
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjFCJXUyMDc4JXUyMDc4JXUyMDc3JXUyMDc3JXUyMDFDVSV1RkYyRSV1RkY1MSV1RkYyRjFVJXUwMTU3JXVGRjE3XyV1RkYzN1cldUZGMTdlViV1MjFCNyUzQSV1RkYxNyV1MjA3OSU2MDMldUZGNTU1RyUyMW8ldUZGNDEldTIwNzcldTIwNzQldUZGNDQldUZGMUEldTIzMTAldUZGMzEldTIwMUY_,i=Y2h1Y2slMEF3b29k,v=8)

Canvas's compression unfortunately currently doesn't have an English dictionary mode as I'm lazy.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 49 bytes

```
AQjd["How much"G"would a"J+GHH"if a"J"could"H+G\?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3zEwKyVaySO/XCG3NDlDyV2pPL80J0UhUclL293DQykzDcRUSgYJKnlou8fY//8fDVSTn6Kko5ScUZqcrRQLAA)

```
AQ:  Take the two-element list Q (input) and assign the first element to G, the second to H
jd:   join on d (=" ") the following list
[:    starts list definition, ends implicitly with the end of the program.
      All following values are elements of the list
J+GH: concatenate G and H so it won't be joined with a space between, save it to J
\?:   One-character string consisting of "?"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 77 bytes

```
func[a b][rejoin["How much "a" would a "a b" "b" if a "a b" could "b" "a"?"]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxDsIwDAXQvaewfIwurMysUQbXjmloiFFElOMHw1AxWPr/fbck85YkxEVXmNorB4IthpYelmvAqw14dt4BCWFYLwLkGTYE9Mt6Vv6NX/TXC8Y4Xy3XNyjgMBNn3jsfuJzcKFdnpVL@lE2S692K4vwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 79 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("How much 0 would a 01 1 if a 01 could 1 0?",0,A1),1,A2)
```

Simple substitution.  First string cannot contain `1`.

Comment: As it turns out, this is the same length as the more straightforward approach which has no restrictions on input: `="How much "&A1&" would a "&A1&A2&" "&A2&" if a "&A1&A2&" could "&A2&" "&A1&"?"`

Comment: Not if you use named ranges `A` and `B`. `="How much "&A&" would a "&A&B&" "&B&" if a "&A&B&" could "&B&" "&A&"?"`

Comment: @user3819867, would that not be `="How much "&A:A&" would a "&A:A&B:B&" "&B:B&" if a "&A:A&B:B&" could "&B:B&" "&A:A&"?"`

Comment: Named range, you can define the name in names manager (`Ctrl+F3`). You can enter any non-reserved string, including 1 char length.

Comment: Have toyed with named ranges before.  Don;t think its in the spirit of CodeGolf.  Do we add bytecount for the naming?

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 61 bytes

```
f(a,b)=>"How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck7CoAwEATQWk@xLBYJeANRW6@x@WHwEwmGFOLZowkIwhQz8xT5MyXDqBW8H3ByEbYgZ2gIogurAnprI@CNNd@QRfJLI3ZpI7szDlddHd7uJzMMo3MKW0A5B7kg593PBPlMi9ZHkTs9)

Comment: You can move the function name to the header and omit it from the byte-count.

Comment: @Oliver I'm curious where this has been specified, I haven't read anything regarding that anywhere and always assumed function names had to be included

Comment: [Anonymous functions are accepted by the community, unless the challenge specifies otherwise](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1503/61613)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```scala
(a:String,b:String)=>s"How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc@9DoIwFAXgnac4aRwg4QlI1Li5OBkn43BbilRLS0oRiPHZsfiTGEw63HO@2@E2gjSNll@k8NiRMrhHQC4LVCHE5M5Nho1zNBz33ilzPiUZDkZ5LF@bwI00@pDGmLL3Sso/Q7JcNWxrO1StKLEgdLbVOSiMC47wVPEN4iVTS2s21uG31ybuY9ZZm7OUibIVV5Yk0Q9xckGuUtYzqKyRQyAutZ9RoZoyyKz9bwCWgk33YZLo8Rif)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 40 bytes

```
▌_l@lll╩Bßx¬╩5╩♦Γ╫¬╩-╩♦?ß¬╩à╩e?ß¬]─ uδ'?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtJ74HIecnJxHU1c6HZ5fcWgNkGEKxI9mLjs3@dHU1WABXYiA/eH5YO7hBUAiFcyLfTSlQaH03BZ1@///1cvz81PUFdSTM0qTs9UB)

Probably suboptimal. Relies on manipulating the stack, and generating the sentence starting from the end. I might write an explanation if someone really wants it, nothing magic is happening.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 76 bytes

```java
a->b->"How much "+a+" would a "+a+b+" "+b+" if a "+a+b+" could "+b+" "+a+"?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZKxboMwEIb3PMXJU2gS1K5NQ7eqQ7s0Y5TBGBtMDEbYDooinp3ahiYxHcD677s73/FT4jPelNlp4FUjWw2l1bHRXMTM1ERzWcdP2wURWCn4xryG6wKgMangBJTG2h5nyTOoLFvudcvr/HAE3OYq8qkAH1Oft5Gu53o8kgQY7Aa8SdJNgj5lB5UhBaAVXiHopBEZYK9Sq5F/c/YQIj4FTdgWvaNh6@//G8qOpanSCnbTYABXQJ2UGVoDIoUhJwT9@o5S3DpyorQJQSVrenEopUKHqLWfwRGGhQhJgblvR8ysJG8p9TWFNIqGrMRpSn1ZJ@fjNbymjuCmEbOyH5k68iW7GSAy8zW5FCwkjKvCkTDqV3HkXzSMALiYVyGYnBvXGz29JfSjP0y29x/HOfQ6@hTdbNpflKZVLI2OG5unRb1ksVv7snSZh@dj9ChfjlE0tu4X7umHXw)

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lips, 79 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(a b)(concat"How much "a" would a "a b" "b" if a "a b" could "b" "a"?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 61 bytes

```perl
$_="How much 0 would a 01 1 if a 01 could 1 0?";s/\d/$F[$&]/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbJI79cIbc0OUPBQKE8vzQnRSFRwcBQwVAhMw3CSgYLGioY2CtZF@vHpOiruEWrqMXqp///X56fn6KQnFGanP0vv6AkMz@v@L9uYgEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
a/b="How much $a would a $a$b $b if a $a$b could $b $a?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1E/yVbJI79cIbc0OUNBJVGhPL80J0UhEchUSVIAosw0GCcZLAMSTbRX@u9QnAHUpVSen5@ipK@UnFGanK30HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## **Python 2, Python 3 - 78 bytes**

```
lambda a,b:' '.join(('How much',a,'would a',a+b,b,'if a',a+b,'could',b,a))+'?'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xDoMwDEX3nsLKYltYXbohVV17iC5JUJS0kCAKAk6fEkpVT/@9P3z36@hTvGR3feRWd6bRoMXUCHh@phCJ8J5m6CbrUbTgnKa2Ab3lyogRDO4HaEuFm9TMFd4wuzTAIrBCiECk5pQaJaCsn@xLsQCpgt/kwtv/qaTd7HRsFumPXxRzfYLt@iHEkRyVHeb8AQ)

no format strings, a tad shorter than @Tryer 's format

Answer (score 0):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 46 bytes

```
iHow much ò would a aò b if a òò could b ò?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9Mjv1whtzQ5Q@HwJoXy/NKcFIVEBaFEIEcoSSEzDcg5vAnISQbLAIUOb7L///9/elF@aV7K/4z8dAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 6948 6f77 206d 7563 6820 f220 776f 756c  iHow much . woul
00000010: 6420 6120 1261 f220 1262 2069 6620 6120  d a .a. .b if a 
00000020: f2f2 2063 6f75 6c64 2012 6220 f23f       .. could .b .?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 64 bytes

```
$0="How much "$1" could a "$1$2" "$2" if a "$1$2" could "$2" "$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWySO/XCG3NDlDQUnFUEkhOb80J0UhEcRRMVICUkAiMw0hAJFXgsgZ/v9fnp@fopCcUZoMNA0A)

I tried being clever with string substitutions and/or print statements, but I couldn't make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [SAP ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP), 95 bytes

```
FORM f USING a b.WRITE:'How much',a,'would a',a && b,b,'if a',a && b,'could',b,a &&'?'.ENDFORM.
```

Input should be of type string to preserve spaces/not add any extra ones. Example program:

```
REPORT z.
PARAMETERS:
    a TYPE string LOWER CASE,
    b TYPE string LOWER CASE.
PERFORM f using a b.
```

---

Rather boring code, not much to golf. Removing spaces where they are not needed. String concatenation using `a && b` is obviously shorter than doing `a NO-GAP,b`.

While modern ABAP can do string interpolation (`WRITE:|{ a } { b }|.`), it doesn't save a single byte, because as per usual there are too many mandatory spaces. The boring alternative (`WRITE:a,b.`) even implicitly appends a space to the output after each `,`, making  the choice an easy one...

For comparison:
`WRITE:|How much { a } would a { a }{ b } { b } etc...|.` 
`WRITE:'How much',a,'would a',a && b,b,'etc...'`

Comment: I could lose 10 bytes here if it's legal to use the variables defined in the surrounding program (this allows me to remove `USING a b`). But then my subroutine depends on the correct naming of these two variables in the calling program, which leads me to believe that it's probably not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 102 bytes

```clj
(#(println"How much"%1"would a"(str %1%2)%2"if a"(str %1%2)"could"%2(str %1\?))(read-line)(read-line))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/X0NZo6AoM68kJ0/JI79cIbc0OUNJ1VCpPL80J0UhUUmjuKRIQdVQ1UhT1UgpMw1FRCkZpEhJ1QgqFGOvqalRlJqYopuTmZeKzNT8/788Pz@FKzmjNDkbAA)