# 1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

When I was a kid, there was a "really cool" shortcut to count to 100:

`1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100`

Output the exact string above, in the fewest characters possible, without using these characters: `0`, `1`, `2`, `9`

Comment: When you say `0`, `1`, `2`, `9`, do you mean source is only restricted to not contain ASCII/codepages `48`, `49`, `50` and `57`?

Comment: I take it trailing whitespace is not allowed?

Comment: @79037662 Exact string, so no extra whitespace allowed

Comment: @640KB To put it simply, one should not be able to see those numbers in your answer.

Comment: This is a nice challenge, but be aware that [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/79857) is discouraged because it's often very similar to other challenges with the same premise

Comment: This does belong on this site, and is on-topic. Redwolf was simply pointing out that Do X without Y often leads to low-quality challenges or duplicates, so it isn't always the best "approach" to have when thinking of a challenge

Comment: Is [`x=>'１，　２，　ｍｉｓｓ　ａ　ｆｅｗ，　９９，　１００'.normalize('NFKC')`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k79/Z6J7/f0PG5oeL9nEpSxt/f93s73eycDEZjbCCbb3u9tfb93OkzxTDCCsIEmTAAidb28/KLcxJzMqlQNdT83b2d1zf/J@XnF@Tmpejn56RppGpqa/wE) a valid submission as it using `１` not `1`?

Comment: Anyone else grow up with "*skip* a few"?

Comment: @tsh I would argue I can "see" those numbers (see my previous comment).

Comment: @MooseBoys no, we simply use binary :)

Comment: I came up with an entry based on an assumption (I know...) that passing "" on STDIN was acceptable.  Mostly since GAWK need tedious boilerplate `BEGIN{}` stuff if there's no input.  But I should have clarified whether or not it's OK to pass input to the program or not.  So in "better late then never" category, I'm asking now.  I can update the entry if the answer is no, but it's not clear from the question or other comments.

Comment: To clarify, GAWK needs `\n` minimally passed to the entry to make it realize there's a "record" to process.

Comment: @MooseBoys I remember i used to say ```'1,2 whooooo 99 100 and what's up with you?'```

Answer (score 23):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Browser only.

```javascript
_=>atob`MSwgMiwgbWlzcyBhIGZldywgOTksIDEwMA`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxNC4IwHIDxu5/ijxeVSisiqNBIipCQDgZBETl1W9ZysU3Fvry9nLw9l99zRxWSqchfalDwDLdI8QRckOB64JeEYGETwZ@mhB4YRh@MBEk8nRiWrXikRF5Q01poGnHbq@v9cBxGNQ3zmiZH9k4b/xZsTyxraro/PGSw3tThKm5TXkjOsM04NZ3zcDSeXRxbYalM0vlasAQ9KCrE8gwkL0WKdZiDHv0T9jvd0ron8iXtBw) (with a polyfill)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```javascript
_=>[4-3,5-3,'miss a few',33*3,5*5*4].join`, `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoIwFEV3v@KlC4VAUYEBE3Q2Dg6MhEgDLSnBPtNW/PzaODnc5OQk5y5843Y06uUyjZPwsvGP5tyVWZFWYdFTWQscpPhEaVEkwSZVUvZsQaWHFAY/ora4CrbiTPNufzjWfc6csI5K5rB1RumZxjFcgFz1xlc1gcW3GQWBE5D2h3C/kXj3/yRD4r8)

Comment: I tried to see if I could come up with some thing shorter, but I'm out by quite a lot (and not got splice working as I'd hoped), but I wonder if you could do anything with [`_=>[..."45x67"].map((c,i)=>i>=3?+(6+c)+33:c-3)`](https://tio.run/##TcyxDsIgFEDR3a8gTBDsq4qt2gQ6GweHjk1jCLYNppYGkPj3aJzc7nLuQ0XltTNLyOIxDSLdhGwBAO@Ld3nAHTzVQoheGyqkkYLXjJRMU8Z5pTNOk7azt1MPkx1J3m62u1OXQ@h9IAME2wRn5pFQimqEz3NUk7kjb19O9xhVCDe/RNcLpqv/0/Al6QM)

Comment: @Pureferret Still far too long, but [here](https://tio.run/##Tcy9DsIgFEDh3acgTBDTW/@qtQntbBwcOjbVkGtpMAgNYOPbo3FyO8t3HnKWAb2eYjaXSYl0E3UHAHRXvPcH2sNTTgxFjXXRMLyWJV8WFWZbntDZ4MwAxo0s71brzbHPIQ4hMgXRtdFrOzLOSUPoyc7S6DsJ7uVxoKQitP0luZwpX/yf1JekDw) is a shorter one.

Comment: wow that's neat, thanks. Another idea was to use `charPointAt`  on the string 'miss a few' or use pi for strings, but again too long.

Answer (score 17):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 40

```bash
tr 3-? /-:<<<"5, 6, miss a few, ==, 544"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwVjXXkFf18rGxkbJVEfBTEchN7O4WCFRIS21XEfB1lZHwdTEROn/fwA)

Comment: I really like this.

Comment: Looks like wildcard expansion on '?': what's the environmental constraint?

Comment: @Will: And if I have a file called `3-1`?

Comment: …or multiple matching files, like `3-W`, `3-i`, `3-l`.

Comment: @Joshua, there is an [Assumptions about the working directory](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12821) answer in the [What assumptions about the file system layout can be made?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/what-assumptions-about-the-file-system-layout-can-be-made/12821) meta discussion, saying “The present working directory may be assumed to be empty.” So we ignore the possible presence of such files.

Comment: @Joshua I guess `3-@` would work with the same byte count and no filesystem assumptions.

Comment: [39](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwVjXXkFf18rGJoLLVEfBTEchN7O4WCFRIS21XEfB1lZHwdTE5P9/AA)

Answer (score 15):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```r
cat(T+F:T,"miss a few",3*33+F:T,sep=", ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCNE280qREcpN7O4WCFRIS21XEnHWMvYGCxanFpgq6SjoKT5/z8A)

`T` and `F` are equal to `TRUE` and `FALSE`. They get coerced to integers `1` and `0` by the operators `+` and `:`.

Comment: You can save another 2 bytes by writing `99:100` as `66:67+33`

Comment: @KirillL. Thanks! I was editing in something similar as you commented.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>54</s>, <s>51</s>, <s>47</s> 42 bytes

Saved **2 bytes** thanks to Digial Trauma's suggestion to replace `8*8+35 = 99` with `33*3 = 99`.

Saved **1 byte** by realizing that I could replace `8*8+36 = 100` with `4*5*5 = 100`.

Saved **4 bytes** thanks to dingledooper's suggestion to use `sep=', '` in the `print`!

Saved **5 bytes** thanks to  ovs' suggestion to use `bytes` objects.

### New Answer

```python
print(*b"","miss a few",*b"cd",sep=", ")
```

```python
The b"" is equivalent to b"\1\2".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQytJiZFJSUcpN7O4WCFRIS21XEkHKJacoqRTnFpgq6SjoKT5/z8A)

### Old Answer:

```python
print(f"{4-3}, {6-4}, miss a few, {33*3}, {4*5*5}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI02p2kTXuFZHodpM1wRI5WYWFyskKqSllgOFjI21wFImWqZaprVKmv//AwA)

Comment: You can replace `8*8+35` with `3*33`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: Use print separators for [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew0TXWMdM10RHPTezuFghUSEttVxdx9hYy1jHRMtUy1SnOLXAVl1HQV3z/38A)

Comment: You can save a few more bytes with `*b"\1\2"` and `*b"cd"`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQytJiZFJSUcpN7O4WCFRIS21XEkHKJacoqRTnFpgq6SjoKT5/z8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Didn't realize `byte` objects could be used that way. That's an odd feature. Just messing around with this I realized that you need the unpacking operator, `*`, to force it to print as an `int` even if there is only one character in the `byte` object.

Comment: I've got `miss a few, 99, 100` only.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Oh, I see. The `b"\1\2"` charcaters don't show up in the answer becase they are unprintable. I'll see what I can do to fix this. The Tio links still work though.

Comment: I had no idea `print(*b'stuff')` produced that output, nice trick!

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
3Ṗ,³ṭ’¤j“¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»W¤j⁾,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//M@G5lizCs@G5reKAmcKkauKAnMKkbcmXyoLJoOG6ieKBvsK7V8KkauKBviwg//8)

### How it works

One thing to note: Jelly has the `Ṙ` atom, which prints a string Jelly representation of it's argument. Lists in Jelly do not use `[` and `]` as open/close markers, instead they consist of comma-separated values:

```
1,2,3,4,5Ṙ
```

prints `1,2,3,4,5`, unfortunately, without spaces.

```
3Ṗ,³ṭ’¤j“¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»W¤j⁾,  - Main link. Takes no arguments
3                       - Yield 3;
 Ṗ                      - Pop from 3, yielding [1, 2]
      ¤                 - Group the previous links into a nilad:
   ³                    -   100
     ’                  -   Decrement; 99
    ṭ                   -   Tack; [99, 100]
  ,                     - Pair; [[1, 2], [99, 100]]
                  ¤     - Group the previous links into a nilad:
        “¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»       -   The compressed string "miss a few"
                 W      -   Wrap; ["miss a few"]
       j                - Join; [1, 2, ["miss a few"], 99, 100]
                   j⁾,  - Join with ", "; "1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100"
```

Answer (score 10):

## HTML + CSS, 118 bytes

```html
<c>, <c>, miss a few, <d><d><c>, <c><style>c:before{content:counter(a);counter-increment:a}d{counter-increment:a 48}
```

Comment: `&#57` and `&#48` may works for `9` and `0`. But I'm not getting a shorter solution with these escape sequence.

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
$><<[3/3,6/3,'miss a few',33*3,5*5*4]*", "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxibaWN9YxwyI1XMzi4sVEhXSUsvVdYyNtYx1TLVMtUxitZR0FJT@/wcA)

-4 from Jonah. Borrows from Arnauld's answer.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>46</s></sup> 44 bytes

```ruby
$><<"cd".bytes.insert(2,"miss a few")*", "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkaJkSk5RUkvqbIktVgvM684tahEw0hHKTezuFghUSEttVxJU0tJR0Hp/38A)

The three unprintables for codepoints 1, 2 and 3 are in the string  containing "cd".

-2 from manatwork. [Other version with same bytecount](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9hWiZGJOTlFSS@psiS1mKs42ijWVik3s7hYIVEhLbVciUvFzsamWEtJR0Hp/38A)

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxibaWN9YxwyI1XMzi4sVEhXSUsvVdYyNtYx1TLVMtUxitZR0FJT@/wcA "Ruby – Try It Online").  99 / 100 trick thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: For replacing a single “3” `.sub()` is enough, no need for its **g**lobal brother.

Comment: BTW, without regular expression would be 1 more character shorter, though still longer than Jonah's. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9hWiZGJOTlFSS@psiS1mKs42ijWVik3s7hYIVEhLbVciUvFzsamWEtJR0Hp/38A "Ruby – Try It Online") or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkaJkSk5RUkvqbIktVgvM684tahEw0hHKTezuFghUSEttVxJU0tJR0Hp/38A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks for your help! @Jonah manatwork

Answer (score 8):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>57</s> <s>56</s>  53 bytes

```php
printf('%c, %d, miss a few, %d, %o',7*7,5-3,33*3,64);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkC4oy80rSNNRVk3UUVFN0FHIzi4sVEhXSUsshfNV8dR1zLXMdU11jHWNjLWMdMxNN6///AQ)

A `printf`, some spices, stir

EDIT: -1 byte thanks to Digital Trauma

EDIT 2: -3 bytes thanks to Michael Dorgan for octal, thought about 153 with `%x` for hex but it has a 1..

**Also, less fun but 2 bytes shorter by manatwork, improved by BadHorsie (it seems that `<?=` can also take multiple arguments with comas):**

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```php
<?=5-4,', ',5-3,', miss a few, ',33*3,', ',5*5*4;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WVNdER11HQV3HVNcYxMjNLC5WSFRISy0HCRobaxlDpbVMtUys//8HAA)

Comment: `5-3` (with %d) is 1 shorter than `47+3` (with %c).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma good catch!

Comment: An `echo` with simply enumerated parameters would be shorter. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkU5Mz8hVMdU101HUU1HVMdY1BjNzM4mKFRIW01HKQoLGxljFUWstUy8T6/38A "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: From my answer, think "octal" for the 100 (64) :)

Comment: @MichelDorgan thanks, great suggestion!

Comment: @manatwork shorter but less fun, if you want to post as a separate answer I'll edit it out

Comment: Use `<?=` instead of `echo ` to save a couple of bytes.

Comment: @BadHorsie I didn't know `<?=` took multiple arguments with comas, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), <s>124..120</s> 114 bytes

```
>> Each 5 57
>> Then 7 3 6 3 4 3 54 3 8
> ", "
> "miss a few"
>> "L"
>> #3
>> #5
>> 53*6
>> #4
>> 8-7
>> Output 56
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxDoAgFEN3T9HgZnQRPjqxuZm4eAFjMDBojEg8PvIZ@po3tJ/z4bZP6FMyBtO2OxBoqLKszl4YIKFzVA4xxspAtBBcpw8BGw77CR6IuVQtC4lJstHFFHPsyvES3zu@IJ3SDw)

**Explanation:**

I use the fact that each line with the line number \$x\$ can be called with \$x + k \cdot n \$, where \$k \in \mathbb{N} \$ and \$n\$ is total number of lines of code.
Example from code with 11 lines: the reference to line `1` can be replaced by `12`, `23`, `34`, and so on.

[Try the translated version online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fzk7BNTE5Q8FUwYgLyA7JSM1TMFcwVjADYhMgNjQAEhZcdgpKOgpKICo3s7hYIVEhLbVcCaRByQdMKRuDSVMQaallBuaYgEgLXXMQ5V9aUlBaomD4/z8A)

**Line by line:**

As always in Whispers, we run the last line first:

```
>> Output 56
```

This line outputs the result from line 56. Since the code does not have 56 lines it actually outputs line \$ 56 \mod 11 = 1\$:

```
>> Each 5 57
```

Applying the same trick again we can replace this line with:

```
>> Each 5 2
```

In line 5 we can expect a function and in line 2 an array. The function will be applied on each element of the array and it replaces the element with the result. Let us first look at line 5:

```
>> "L"
```

`L` is an argument from the `Each` statement in line 1. `L` is converted to a string.

Now line 2:

```
>> Then 7 3 6 3 4 3 54 3 8
```

`Then` creates an array with the arguments as its elements. If we would print this line we get the following array:

```
[1, ', ', 2, ', ', 'miss a few', ', ', 99, ', ', 100]
```

**Explanation of the arguments:**

Line 3 and 4: simple strings

Line 6: Returns the length of line 3, so we get `2`

Line 7: Returns the length of line 5, so we get a `1`

Line 8: Returns the result of line 53 (actually 9) raised to the power of the result of line 6, so we get `100`

Line 54 (actually 10): Subtracts result of line 8 with the result of line 7, so we get a `99`

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>54</s> 56 bytes

```c
l(){printf("%c, %d, miss a few %d, %o",7*7,5-3,'c',64);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpJqU1ySkpmvl2HHlZlXopCjoWkNZuQmZuZpaFaD@ApFqSWlRXkKBta1/4H86oIioII0DSXVZB0F1RQdhdzM4mKFRIW01HIwVzVfScdcy1zHVNdYRz1ZXcfMRBOo8T8A)

Let's save a couple bytes using Octal for the 100.  Thanks to Sheik Yerbouti for saving a byte and point out the no commas issue.

Comment: Using C, I looked at a putchar() alternative, but it isn't all that short, unfortunately: `for(char x[]="4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433",*y=x;*y;)putchar(*y++-3);`

Comment: I tried really hard to loop, but it just gets too big.  Hence using printf qualifiers carefully.

Comment: @will it is 66 bytes, longer than this one `main(i){for(i=5*5;i--;)putchar("334#/<<#/zhi#d#vvlp#/5#/4"[i]-3);}`

Comment: @tsh Nice improvement. I somehow completely overlooked passing the string directly with an index to putchar. Well combined with default int and reverse/decrement indexing too.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan you are missing the commas in the output. Anyway you can save 1 byte by printing `'c'` instead of `33*3`

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 52 bytes

```r
cat(chartr("@-K","/-:","B, C, miss a few, JJ, BAA"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCM5I7GopEhDyUHXW0lHSV/XCkg66Sg46yjkZhYXKyQqpKWW6yh4eekoODk6Kmlq/v8PAA)

Encodes numbers as uppercase letters and then applies character range translation. Since we can't directly type `0-9`, we expand the range by 1 character in both directions resulting in `/-:`.

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 146 bytes

```
-[----->+>+>+>++>++<<<<<]>>>--.-----.------------.<-.------.>.>+++++++.>+++.<++++++..<.>>--------.<<.>>+++++.-.<++++.<<.>.<<++++++..>.>.<+++++.-..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtRCoBgCIMPFO4EsotEDxUEEfQQdH77pzlFnPvcnvW8j3e/Imw2iVOV2qWFpBkyrPkL3h7EoFO5wH8Dh56bl6vACsnTGI1TrglEfA)

A fairly straightforward 255/5=51 loop giving ASCII 51 and ASCII 102 as `333ff` in 5 consecutive cells, followed by hunt and peck strategy.

Comment: 145 bytes: [`-[>+>+>+>++>++[<]>-----]>>>--.-----.------------.<-.------.>.>+++++++.>+++.<++++++..<.>>--------.<<.>>+++++.-.<++++.<<.>.<<++++++..>.>.<+++++.-..`](https://tio.run/##RYtdCoBACIQPFM4JZC6y7EMFQQQ9BJ3f/NmlUWRGP7dnPe/j3S8zaVyqopt2SqiTbpC@5hB0ZhD@kUoDHQEK8ucj1UEKyZWPiTPSJGD2AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

```perl
$,=", ";say!!3,5-3,"miss a few",3*33,4*5*5
```

Sets the record separator, and prints a few numbers and a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZJR0HJujixUlHRWMdU11hHKTezuFghUSEttVxJx1jL2FjHRMtUC6j2X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 bytes

```perl
say"C, D, miss a few, KK, CBB"=~y,A-L,/-:,r
```

Translates B-K to 0-9 (extended by one more ASCII code on each side of the range) and prints.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJWUfBRUchN7O4WCFRIS21XEfB21tHwdnJScm2rlLHUddHR1/XSqfo//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
$,=", ";say unpack"c3/acc","
miss a fewcd"
```

Sets the record separator, and unpacks values to be printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZJR0HJujixUqE0ryAxOVsp2Vg/MTlZSUeJkYkrN7O4WCFRIS21PDlF6f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
()->join([b"";"miss a few";b"cd"],", ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvtfQ1PXLis/M08jOkmJkUnJWik3s7hYIVEhLbVcyTpJKTlFKVZHSUdBSfN/QVFmXolGmoam5n8A)

the first string is `"\1\2"` which is allowed if I understand the challenge correctly

`b"str"` converts the string in an array of the value of each character so `b"\1\2" => [1,2]` and `b"cd" => [99,100]`

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 31 bytes

```
mȯ←←←"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@kdtEyBIyURf2VRfuSCnrEw5RTkzo0pf2cZGX9nE2Pj/fwA)

Explanation:

```
m                                 Map the function...
 ȯ←←←                             Decrement character 3 times
      "4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433  desired string "ASCII-shifted" by 3
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
³ḊĖ.ịṚj“¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»W¤j⁾,
```

A full program that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9qZWxsef//wrPhuIrEli7hu4vhuZpq4oCcwqRtyZfKgsmg4bqJ4oG@wrtXwqRq4oG@LCD//w)**

#### How?

```
³ḊĖ.ịṚj“¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»W¤j⁾,  - Link: no arguments
³                      - 100
 Ḋ                     - dequeue -> [2,3,...,99,100]
  Ė                    - enumerate -> [[1,2],[2,3],...,[98,99],[99,100]]
   .                   - 0.5
    ị                  - index into -> [[99,100],[1,2]]
     Ṛ                 - reverse
                 ¤     - nilad followed by links as a nilad:
       “¤mɗʂɠẉ⁾»       -   dictionary compression of "miss a few"
                W      -   wrap in a list  -> ["miss a few"]
      j                - join              -> [1,2,"miss a few",99,100]
                   ⁾,  - ", "
                  j    - join              -> [1,", ",2,", ","miss a few",", ",99,", ",100]
                       - implicit print    -> `1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100`
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <strike>20 19</strike> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

saved 2 bytes thanks to Razetime

```
ü←φr5╧wL'•↔♦$▒ò╠‼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=811bed7235cf774c27071d0424b195cc13&i=)

Original brain-dead solution for reference purposes only:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü2Φÿßbÿ»f╙m¡6¿₧|░╘;┬u»
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8132e898e16298af66d36dad36a89e7cb0d43bc275af&i=)

Comment: [-2](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=811bed7235cf774c27071d0424b195cc13&i=)

Answer (score 4):

## C++, 56 bytes

```
[]{for(int x:"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433"s)putchar(x-3);}
```

Inspired by a [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/219495/1-2-miss-a-few-99-100#comment511335_219544).

Usage:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto k = [](){for(int x:"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433"s)putchar(x-3);};
    k();
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](http://cpp.sh/3lefr)

Comment: save 2 bytes by eliminating optional () as `[]{for(int x:"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433"s)putchar(x-3);}`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

I don't think this would be shorter with `0`, `1`, `2` and `9`.

```
XY…š§€…†Óт<т„, ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/IvJRw7KjCw8tf9S0Bsh61LDg8OSLTTYXmx41zNNROLz3/38A)

```python
X                # push 1
 Y               # push 2
  …š§€…†Ó        # push compressed dictionary string "miss a few"
         т<      # push 100-1
           т     # push 100
            „,   # push string ", "
               ý # join the stack with this string
```

Comment: Nice, the solution I came up with was the same but starting with `≠x` instead of `XY`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Barrel](https://www.github.com/LorenDB/barrel), <strike>31</strike> 34 bytes

```
+n, +n, 'miss a few, '#44+#45+n, +n
```

This is my own esolang, follow the link for more info.

Increments the accumulator, prints it, implicitly prints some strings (`,` and `miss a few,` are implicitly printed), does a loop on accumulator incrementation, and finishes as it started.

Edit: I realized that "97" used a "9". *smacks forehead*

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19367/66833) deadlineless bounty that offers reputation for showcasing new and interesting languages

Comment: Hi! As caird said, I've got a bounty for new and interesting languages. I'd be willing to give this answer a bounty of +100 reputation, or if you think you could demonstrate more of the language's features in another answer I could award it to that instead.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: Cool! <strike>I'd golf [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) but I'm not sure about it because I'd have to add a feature. Hmmm....</strike> I'm working on something.

Comment: @LorenDB Sounds good, let me know when you've got an answer chosen/posted!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: here you go :) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223430

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
B, C, miss a few, JJ, BAA
T`L`d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy0lHwVlHITezuFghUSEttVxHwctLR8HJ0ZErJMEnIeX/fwA) Explantion:

```
B, C, miss a few, JJ, BAA
```

Replace the empty input with the literal string.

```
T`L`d
```

Transliterate upper case letters to digits.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell (ASCII answer)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 128 bytes

```powershell
$k=3-3;((@(46+3),@(53-3),@('miss a few'),@(57,57),@((46+3),48,48))|%{$k++;if($k-eq3){$_}else{($_|%{[char]$_})-join''}})-join', '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXb1ljX2FpDw0HDxEzbWFPHQcMUKACi1XMzi4sVEhXSUsvVweLmOqbmIAZUpYkFEGlq1qhWq2Rra1tnpmmoZOumFhprVqvE16bmFKdWa6jEA2WjkzMSi2KBYpq6WfmZeerqtTCWjoL6//8A)

## [PowerShell (Base64 one)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 135 bytes

```powershell
[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64string('MQAsACAAMgAsACAAbQBpAHMAcwAgAGEAIABmAGUAdwAsACAAOQA5ACwAIAAxADAAMAA='))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxCsIwFEU/p3bppA4Fh5tYo0OQoJ2Kg7aPWmiTkgTTv4@BTPdwDnc1gaz70jzH2D1p81WjezNMenzVdaunxFQJ8g9vk9t13OgfWZ/ixZqFvR0d9y63Qio4cECOeT@KrbhK9AEjRIMb2ALRYgi53xUO4CF5bDinH3AqyjLGPw)

Comment: @Arnuald edited the code to 3-3

Comment: A few bytes less? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NE11hTR8MURKrnZhYXKyQqpKWWq@toGGsZg2RMtEy1TDV1s/Iz89R1FNT//wcA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Or even less bytes (but a far less interesting answer, unfortunately): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFw0TXWFNHQUXDFEznZhYXKyQqpKWWg8SMtYwhkiZaplqmmkr//wMA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman thanks, but that is straight copy of Arnauld answer

Comment: Sorry, I did not see Arnauld had come to the same answer before me, I just golfed that down from yours.

Comment: Base64 in 100 https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzoktaJEzzUvOT8lMy891soqtCTNQs89tSS4pAgooBHtnJ9XllpUApRxK8rPdUosTjUzKYbIqfsGl6f7ZpanJ4XnVCVXOmV4ukflpFSWp/uHZBd7uriW@zra2qprav7/DwA or am I completely overlooking a 0,1,2 or 9?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
“×ƤṪ5Ġpṃ:Ƒ5ṫȷØJkxXp⁺¥ġ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4oCcw5fGpOG5qjXEoHDhuYM6xpE14bmryLfDmEpreFhw4oG6wqXEocK7//8)

Same length as caird's answer, much more boring.

Comment: I'm glad I found a way to golf from 25 to 23, it would've been disappointing if flat compression won this!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
print ', '.join(map(str,(4-3,5-3,'miss a few',33*3,5*5*4)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQV1HQV0vKz8zTyM3sUCjuKRIR8NE11jHFIjVczOLixUSFdJSy9V1jI21gKJaplommpqa//8DAA)

Thanks to @arnauld for js answer

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EXUdBXS8rPzNPIzrBRNc4QSfBFESq52YWFyskKqSllqvrJBgba4FltEy1TBJiNf//BwA) with `\`\`` instead of `str` and [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM68kwUTXOEFbXUddJ8EUwlLIzSwuVkhUSEstB4kaG2vBFWiZapkk/P8PAA) by manually placing `,`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
3ɽ÷«eeȮǒḋp«₁‹₁W‛, j
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3%C9%BD%C3%B7%C2%ABee%C8%AE%C7%92%E1%B8%8Bp%C2%AB%E2%82%81%E2%80%B9%E2%82%81W%E2%80%9B%2C%20j&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```python
3ɽ÷      # stack = [1, 2]
«eeȮǒḋp« # stack = [1, 2, "miss a few"] 
₁‹₁      # stack = [1, 2, "miss a few", 99, 100]
W‛, j    # join stack on ", "
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
j+\,d[=hZhZ"miss a few"t=*TTT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P0s7Ricl2jYjKiNKKTezuFghUSEttVypxFYrJCTk/38A)

---

Python 3.8 translation:

```
Z=0
T=10

print(", ".join(map(str,[(Z:=Z+1),Z+1,"miss a few",(T:=T*T)-1,T])))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 48 bytes

```php
<?=join(', ',[!'',~-3,'miss a few',33*3,45^73]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Kz8zT0NdR0FdJ1pRXV2nTtdYRz03s7hYIVEhLbVcXcfYWMtYx8Q0ztw4VtP6/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 37 keystrokes

```
i3, 3, miss a few, 8, <esc>|<C-x><C-x>l.l<C-a>ylp$pp<C-a>
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <strike>58</strike> 54 bytes

```php
<?=join(', ',[$i=3/3,++$i,'miss a few',$i=33*3,++$i]);
```

PHP doesnt really want to be typed short, but I liked coming up with this :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 45 bytes

```perl6
say join ", ",5-4,5-3,"miss a few",3*33,4*5*5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhKz8zT0FJB4hMdU2A2FhHKTezuFghUSEttVxJx1jL2FjHRMtUy/T/fwA)

Comment: You can save 1 by dropping the ; at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*Two bytes off thanks to [@Lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal), and one off thanks to [@Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)!*

```
XY"miss a fewc")i_)]", "*
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyJSKTezuFghUSEttTxZSTMzXjNWSUdBSev/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
X              e# Push contents of variable X (predefined value): 1
Y              e# Push contents of variable Y (predefined value): 2
"miss a fewc"  e# Push this string
)              e# Detach the last character from that string
i              e# Convert to integer: gives 99
_)             e# Duplicate, increment: gives 100
]              e# Concatenate stack contents into an array
", "           e# Push this string 
*              e# Join the array entries with the specified string
               e# Implicit display
```

Comment: [26 bytes (I golfed my golfing suggestion xD)](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyJSKTezuFghUSEttVzJ0VErXiMmVklHQUnr/38A "CJam – Try It Online")

Comment: Maybe `XY"miss a fewc")i_)]", "*` for 25? Or also `XY"miss a few"9B*_)]", "*`

Comment: Oops, my bad, you actually have to use the first one because the second one has a `9` in it (facepalm)

Comment: @Lynn Heh, I didn't remember that requirement. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 65 bytes

```ml
print(String.map(fn c=>chr(ord c-3))"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/@/oCgzr0QjuARIpevlJhZopOUpJNvaJWcUaeQXpSgk6xpraiqZ6Cub6isX5JSVKacoZ2ZU6Svb2OgrmxgbK2la//8PAA)

`"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433"` is `"1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100"` shifted by adding three to each ASCII code. `String.map(fn c=>chr(ord c-3))` reverses this shifting by substracting three of each char's `ord`inal number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 46 bytes

```
?5-4,", ",5-3,", miss a few, ",33*3,", ",5*5*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/395U10RHSUdBScdU1xjEyM0sLlZIVEhLLQcJGhtrGUOltUy1TP7/BwA)

<strike>Replaced calculated numbers for 1 and 2 with \x hex codes for ASCII 49 and 50 and saved 3 bytes!</strike>

(Can't do the above because it results in \x31 and \x32 which of course contain 1 and 2...)

Answer (score 2):

#### x86_16 machine code, 146 bytes

Thank's to @mik for tips and trick :))

Replace : `add al, "0"` / `add dl, "0"` with `add al, 2fh` + `inc al` and `add dl, 2fh` + `inc dl` to avoid `"0"` in the source code.

```
B3 04          MOV BL, 4
B1 03          MOV CL, 3
2A D9          SUB BL, CL
B4 0E          MOV AH, 0EH
8A C3          MOV AL, BL
04 2F          ADD AL, 2FH
FE C0          INC AL
CD 10          INT 10H
B0 2C          MOV AL, ","
CD 10          INT 10H
80 C3 2F       ADD BL, 2FH
FE C3          INC BL
FE C3          INC BL
8A C3          MOV AL, BL
CD 10          INT 10H
B8 2C 0E       MOV AX, 0E2CH
CD 10          INT 10H
B4 09          MOV AH, 09h
BA 7A 01       MOV DX, OFFSET TXT
CD 21          INT 21H
B8 2C 0E       MOV AX, 0E2CH
CD 10          INT 10H
                                      
B8 20 0E       MOV AX, 0E20H
CD 10          INT 10H
               
B0 21          MOV AL, 33
B3 03          MOV BL, 3
F6 E3          MUL BL
B3 0A          MOV BL, 10
33 C9          XOR CX, CX
           LOOP1:
33 D2          XOR DX, DX
F7 F3          DIV BX
52             PUSH DX
41             INC CX
85 C0          TEST AX, AX
75 F6          JNZ LOOP1
    PRINT_DIGIT1:
5A             POP DX
80 C2 2F       ADD DL, 2FH
FE C2          INC DL
B4 02          MOV AH, 02H
CD 21          INT 21H
E2 F6          LOOP PRINT_DIGIT1
                                      
B8 2C 0E       MOV AX, 0E2CH
CD 10          INT 10H
B8 20 0E       MOV AX, 0E20H
CD 10          INT 10H
                                      
B0 04          MOV AL, 4
B3 05          MOV BL, 5
F6 E3          MUL BL
F6 E3          MUL BL
B3 0A          MOV BL, 10
33 C9          XOR CX, CX
           LOOP2:
33 D2          XOR DX, DX
F7 F3          DIV BX
52             PUSH DX
41             INC CX
85 C0          TEST AX, AX
75 F6          JNZ LOOP2
    PRINT_DIGIT2:
5A             POP DX
80 C2 2F       ADD DL, 2FH
FE C2          INC DL
B4 02          MOV AH, 02H
CD 21          INT 21H
E2 F6          LOOP PRINT_DIGIT2
            EXIT:
B8 00 4C       MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21          INT 21H
                                                                              
20 6D 69 73 73 20 61 20 66 65 77 24   TXT DB " miss a few$"
```

Run is DOSBox :

[image]

Comment: 0 appears in the code (ASCII 30)

Comment: the goal of this challenge is to avoid such constructions, you can e.g. add 2fh and then increment

Comment: @mik Thank's for tips and trick :)) I edited my answer now

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <s>58</s> 49 bytes

```
[?b-?a,?c-?a,"miss a few",?c,?d]|>Enum.join(", ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/2j5J1z5Rxz4ZRCrlZhYXKyQqpKWWKwGFdOxTYmvsXPNKc/Wy8jPzNJR0FJQ0/9fYefrrFZSWFP8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), 70 bytes

Old 75:

```
a=8-7;b=8-6;c=8-8;d=4+5;_=>`${a}, ${b}, miss a few, ${d}${d}, ${a}${c}${c}`
```

New 50:

```
_=>[8-7,8-6,'miss a few',(4+5)*(5+5)+4+5,(8-7)*(55+55-5-5)].join(', ')
```

by far not the best js answer, ill widdle.

Answer (score 2):

## [factor](https://factorcode.org/), <del>66</del> 61 bytes

Shaved 5 bytes thanks to @Bubbler!

```factor
4 3 - 5 3 - 33 3 * CHAR: d "%d, %d, miss a few, %d, %d"printf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp1Cnr5eWmFySX6RblKxgY6Pg6u/GFRrsaqVQkFhUnFqkkFhakq9bWpzKBZKAaSnOLy1KToVqhOr6b6JgrKCrYAomjY2BlJaCs4djkJVCioKSaoqOAgjnZhYXKyQqpKWWQ/iqKUoFRZl5JWn/Qcbr5xeU6EMMhVLodv0HAA)

Original version:

```factor
4 3 - 5 3 - 33 3 * dup 3 - 4 + "%d, %d, miss a few, %d, %d" printf
```

My first factor line. Probably can be shorter…

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp1Cnr5eWmFySX6RblKxgY6Pg6u/GFRrsaqVQkFhUnFqkkFhakq9bWpzKBZKAaSnOLy1KToVqhOr6b6JgrKCrYAomjY2BlJZCSmkBmGuioK2gpJqiowDCuZnFxQqJCmmp5RC@aoqSQkFRZl5J2n@QHfr5BSX6EJOhFLqF/wE)

Comment: You're using 0 in `0x63` and `0x64`.

Comment: @Bubbler ha I missed it.. fixed now, but it is even longer..

Comment: You can use `CHAR: d` for 100, and [you can omit a space after string literals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78356/78410). ([61 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp1Cnr5eWmFySX6RblKxgY6Pg6u/GFRrsaqVQkFhUnFqkkFhakq9bWpzKBZKAaSnOLy1KToVqhOr6b6JgrKCrYAomjY2BlJaCs4djkJVCioKSaoqOAgjnZhYXKyQqpKWWQ/iqKUoFRZl5JWn/Qcbr5xeU6EMMhVLodv0HAA))

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 47 bytes

Not very creative. Oh well.

```
echo $[3/3], $[6/3], miss a few, $[##c], $[##d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX0El2ljfOFYHSJuB6dzM4mKFRIW01HKQmLJyciyETon9/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
”'3?Sxv7´Ｄ｜λ*§ξ¬Ｅ‹Ｄαg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJUEfBSEchN7O4WCFRIS21XEfB0lJHwdDAQEnT@v///7plOQA) Compression again. Best I could do without compression is 23 bytes:

```
⪫⟦ＬψＬχmiss a few℅c℅d⟧,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPI9onNS@9JEOjUlNHAco0NACylXIzi4sVEhXSUsuVdBT8i1Iy8xJzNJSSlTSReClKmrFApUCkqWn9//9/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>187</s> 178 bytes

```
{iiiii}dcdddddc{d}ddc{ii}ddcddddddc{d}ddc{{i}dd}dddcddddc{i}cc{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiiic{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}ddd}cdc{i}{i}ddc{{d}iii}dddddc{d}ddc{ii}iiiiicc{d}dddc{d}ddc{ii}dddcdcc
```

The previous version was bad.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5LDoBACENP5KEM1TjrWZKeHfmNRrsg4bV8cOw4x7w2Mx0hQhASBaMGafQwDUY09wzFIZjZ5SN6VzvlvS4lB7NZEf4v14IC34/8tIjZDQ)

Comment: 184 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5LDoBACENP5KFMq5G1y0nPjiBkNNoQEl75cVu523ks7sNSIpjCoDKbIthw0puJzbMLAamcnz6zDrVT3uMKr/Xdov/tWlHo@1WcB9wv "Deadfish~ – Try It Online")

Comment: @astonearachnid This was made using my old generator, which was bad. Thanks! I fixed some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```
`<0x01>, <0x02>, miss a few, `I,[o]H{n` ,`ooHn
```

Replace <0x01> and <0x02> with ascii codepoints 1 and 2.

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=%60%01%2C%20%02%2C%20miss%20a%20few%2C%20%60I%2C%5Bo%5DH%7Bn%60%20%2C%60ooHn&stdin=)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 30 bytes

This contains unprintables so the link is to a Bash program that reconstructs the file and validates it.

```php
<?=~.........................;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY@xDoMwDET3fMVtTEZAJJo0afstwUlEh6qoqQRTfz1NBQMLfYNl2Xcne3BpzMviQS9c0VJHj3tK5CiGmbSmtmnqaZxgrUWVm40zJMsI6U8BHLyEj@zhpY/Qne6hWHGZ6QDY2@VT7xBrQlsyikBDO6VWJ/fcb13gUqIcsLL31yZXRswM4uNzjWD3/rcOPD6N@D12LMpf)

### Explanation

`print`s the bitflipped (`~`) string `1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 68 Bytes

```rust
fn main(){print!("{}, {}, miss a few, {}, {}",4-3,5-3,66+33,63+37)}
```

This is my first attempt at code golf
Yahoo!
[Try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=016de1744e1a761bf05ec23b2fbf3b49)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 56 bytes

Cutting out the main{} on tio saves 12 bytes

```rust
print!("{}, {}, miss a few, {}, {}",4-3,5-3,66+33,63+37)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM31v6AoM69EUUOpulZHAYRzM4uLFRIV0lLLIfzqWiUdE11jHVMgNjPTNgaSxtrG5pr/a/8DAA)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Rust](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74096/tips-for-golfing-in-rust) page for ways you can golf your program, and we hope you enjoy your time on the site!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I'm just having fun with restricted source, I'm not looking to be very competitive!

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 53 bytes

```
$a=++x", "++x", miss a few, "(z=(++y y)-x)z", "++z--y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fJdFWW7tCSUdBCULlZhYXKyQqpKWWA4U0qmw1tLUrFSo1dSs0qyCKqnR1K///V1ICAA)

This abuses a couple of AWK language features, including that all variables are initialized to blank/0/False (context sensitive), that it will happily convert strings to numeric values to make an arithmetic operator work, and it will also convert numeric values to strings in order to append characters to it.

First it gets `1,`  by incrementing variable `x`

```
++x", "
```

then `2, miss a few,`  just does the same thing again...

```
++x", miss a few, "
```

getting a `9` is a bit more work,

```
(++y y)-x
```

which works by getting a `1` with `++y` then appended it to itself to get `11` then subtracting `2` with `-x`.

Using that to set the variable `z` means we can appended another `9` on the end with,

```
(z=...)z
```

That just leaves the last bit `, 100` which we can get by incrementing the `9` and appending to that `1` decremented.

```
", "++z--y
```

I'm pretty sure there are other ways to do this in AWK that are shorter, but I like that this doesn't use any numbers.

One last thing I forgo to mention...  The string is printed since,

```
$a=...
```

is interpreted as `$0=...` which evaluates to True, causing AWK print the value of `$0`, which was just set to the output we want.

Comment: I think assuming input to be `""` is not correct, you can only assume an empty input.

Comment: That might have been a bad assumption on my part (that it was OK to send empty input), so I asked a comment to clarify.  I don't see anything about input in the original question or the comments added.

Comment: but you are passing two quotes as input, and not an empty string

Comment: An empty string works too, I don't know how to do that in TIO

Comment: for me empty string does not work

Comment: GAWK seems to need a `\n` minimally to run the code, meaning this will work...

    `gawk 'BEGIN { printf "\n" }' | gawk '$a=++x", "++x", miss a few, "(z=(++y y)-x)z", "++z--y'`

Comment: But this won't work `cat /dev/null | gawk '$a=++x", "++x", miss a few, "(z=(++y y)-x)z", "++z--y'`

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 45 bytes

```apl
(5↓7⌽∊'miss a few, ',⍨(', ',⍨⍕)¨5↑(3-5)⌽⍳77+!4)

 5↓ ⍝ Drop the first 5 elements
   7⌽ ⍝ Rotate left 7
     ∊'miss a few, ', ⍝ Concatenate and enlist
       ⍨ ⍝ Swap arguments
         (', ',⍨⍕)¨ ⍝ Encode as character and concatenate after swapping arguments
           5↑ ⍝ Take the first 5 elements
             (3-5)⌽ ⍝ Rotate right 2
               ⍳77+!4 ⍝ Create range from 0–100 inclusive
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGIBaQ1jB91DbZ/FHP3kcdXeq5mcXFCokKaanlOgrqOo96V2ioQxmPeqdqHloBVDtRw1jXVBOkvnezubm2oonm//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 34 bytes

```
!.)', ':c.@\'miss a few'3c\33*.c\)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X1FPU11HQd0qWc8hRj03s7hYIVEhLbVc3Tg5xthYSy85RvP/fwA)

```
!                                   Push 1 to the stack.
 .)                                 Copy the 1 and increment.
   ',':c                            Define c as ', ' to save characters when commas are needed.
        .@\                         Copy the ', ' and move stuff around into the right order.
           'miss a few'             Push the string to the stack.
                       3c\          Push 3 and ', ' then swap them.
                          33*       Multiply 3*33 to get 99.
                             .c\)   Copy the 99, push ', ' then swap them and increment the last 99.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [22 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
˜▒çc>åžî¼#(¸“├)øW§Ò┴Ì"
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=IjEsIDIsIG1pc3MgYSBmZXcsIDk5LCAxMDA=&input=&flags=)

## Explained

Just the string literal. Pretty boring, the next-shortest I could get without this was 29 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 69 bytes

```
<?=55-54,', ',floor((5*4)/7),', ','miss a few ',64746/654,', ',5*5*4;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 110 bytes

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/514536287/)

Easy sauce. Alternatively, 12 blocks.

```
when gf clicked
say(join((4)-(3))(join[, ](join((5)-(3))(join[, miss a few, ](join((3)*(33))(join[, ]((66)+(34
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 49 bytes

```
END{print++x", "5-3", miss a few, "3*33", "4*5*5}
```

Assuming empty input (otherwise change `END` to `BEGIN` for a 51-byte answer).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@luqAoM69EW7tCSUdByVTXGEjlZhYXKyQqpKWWA4WMtYxBYkomWqZaprX//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda:f"{3//3}, {8//4}, miss a few, {3*4*8+3}, {4*5*5}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNykl0SpNqdpYX9@4Vkeh2kJf3wRI52YWFyskKqSllgPFjLVMtCy0wdImWqZaprVK/wuKMvNKNNI0NDX/AwA) Uses basic math and an f-string to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 23 bytes

```
[o#k"miss a few"h+vh]Jk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Ol85Wyk3s7hYIVEhLbVcKUO7LCPWK/v/fwA)

having a builtin for `,`  is sadly not enough

-3 bytes from DLosc.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Cì p`ÚÍ a few`#cL qSi,
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Q%2bwgcGDazSBhIGZld2AjY0wgcVNpLA)

```
Cì p`...`#cL qSi,
C                     :12
 ì                    :To digit array
   p                  :Push
    `...`             :  Compressed string "miss a few"
         #c           :  Charcode of "c" (99)
           L          :  100
             q        :Join with
              S       :  Space
               i,     :  Prepended with a comma
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
p=pred
main=putStr$p.p.p<$>"4/#5/#plvv#d#ihz/#<</#433"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8C2oCg1hSs3MTPPtqC0JLikSKVADwhtVOyUTPSVTfWVC3LKypRTlDMzqvSVbWz0lU2MjZX@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
)└"miss a few"♀┐\]û, u
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/z0ZQpSrmZxcUKiQppqeVKj2Y2PJoyISb28G4dhdL//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
)                      # +1 (since the stack is empty, it'll use an implicit 0)
 └                     # Push the top of the stack + 1 (without popping)
  "miss a few"         # Push string "miss a few"
              ♀        # Push 100
               ┐       # Push the top of the stack - 1 (without popping)
                \      # Swap the top two values on the stack
                 ]     # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
                  û,   # Push string ", "
                     u # Join the list with this ", " as delimiter
                       # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Even if we were allowed to use `0129`, the byte-count would remain the same (the `)└` could simply be `12`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 52 bytes

```java
i->4-3+", "+(5-3)+", miss a few, "+(33*3+", "+5*5*4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC7bsMwDNz9FUQmy6mdwfEUpHuGTgG6FB0YWXaZypKgh4ugyLe7st2q4ULieDzyeMURy2v7OXGJzsELkoLvLIMYux3wD1S9wIsUQMoL2yEXS89YGtE/oHCKY7DG2VtSPaAx8pa/amqBeqWtYIeFcV/lTbhI4uA8@pjGmTbM2/N1/O0d0PaO/ctCKuJlTvhgEnACp2XwpBUcE/jA7rXsRAtct2Ki8nlf1tvNE2y2eVPWbC4HiuYROvG1wHVd/DKaoin2bDpkSfZ8c14MlQ6@il9QXqr8b3m1WlZBSpbM3qcf)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 44 bytes

```
68*:77*' ,>'5-:' ,wef a ssim ,':6+' ,':5+>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38xCy8rcXEtdQcdO3VTXCkiXp6YpJCoUF2fmKuioW5lpq4MoU227fJv//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 50 bytes

```
O+++++++''-6 5', '-6 4', miss a few, 'A'c'', 'A'd'
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVjZcts2FH3vV9BsahEiTcuZNJ1Ipj2J63QybeQ0dptpJSUCQUhiQoEKF9upxP56ei@4gdqc@sGWgIO74dwF/khvacwif5EcidDjX1lA41j7VfjTWXIZRWGk8fuECy/W5LdllgPe0CjmzX3lTIl6m4rEnz@Mu04iTudLFoo4iVKWhJFByTKZ@bEdh2nEuEMz2PEX72Z@wuMFZdwo9uc0YTPj@L0xGI6Gg2EM61l3ZK6@H7wfilHbGIrVI0LaxyRbcP4JdiOepJHQFOGDzmi1EmkQZLkw12JOhywDnmjUcW1@z5mhwEmvEIFHHMeh5/ihq0Ic5bMdpy7YblBQYwdcTJMZseiAjUiWhOC4L6ZbrcoyGQ7t5q83l9fOYNTLQ/UnDVK@jBOa@Exb4C0YLlm69kZ4ehOI4i2NwIdOj55KMYX@HjXN3D/myPUBHdmlrJ4/MRgp7GGZ4msWpUKGPQrvNMHvckZkHnfT6Zb1Hd5JIXa9Cbh@Ond5tANXbgLuRRgGnIodwGo3K1j1GwQjokFFvDx0aySL0wVKt6SoDx5NKHAtd1RRssWZ4nt9bpsnxfcmaMONckGF8c8BmlcgqOaD1VQwHk5yrxU3Dg8V44GP@acyCii8CkERkg3@lFyvs@nm5YgMnh/9PWofWycV5enhIV4wyjT0Gx21kcxL54vKmXHpzCOZnxkZZ0Eyq105qG09PKSNa5uqOE3FHTSBWU7mRRrPDFwlvTxVLvt/vnp71X992b9xllmRMK88LpI1Djzk/oAe/fNhhL87R88@QAjWAyCFgrHZPjb5CAI2NeMjj/oTH3B5iHIcBgrM9acC5SieDGrMqKJmbvAOFGbwbeh7WucA76e0vFcnqFqXjfEf4pMI74TmV5ZprYZprXEz5tIFUsZXie630mvomZshhYAW6ULJOqmKjZpT1PMUrpTna86YVCkdJIMavBd@1ITP02AvvN2Ee/6t6mW9hTfRuIRS1GuazGzgjWCK1GPwe9cl6RdUiDDRQBXcieZ@0f7hUaiDqaH3P3XXCn@gD@oD8WkQKvoW4d1@fbX41erAoKcd8k3Ot9vf4D2/X4QCSUoTLg3SkhBqo@BT4Nst18A4HoGRwY5Kcqre2856c9ZANYhf074PDXE/75XqXRG/X5RUknMehTRKSFlBsN2u5YCOYIPo@zqDlFc4/0AoWTgHM7k8YutVMP7nKTU4uFZGB5rjg8FBCrkOVXqO3hoRmOPi4fWofU6GJ8fWY0krjAYwy1WJBBpwWMmHGGrnwx2C9Ra2JbZatfQWfiC1S/XQikUPrJr7ApjkaZ/TEAjFBQtTXOZeV3u0pNl4W0uX9jfzyDrpkNWqs1azigFhX81CJ8YFoFC4WXoQVOuyI77gFHqPWoEeYHw1au1lfIVSLxUWi@4Kp6h3/UWwLs2ciH9O/Ygb@iTWibXEEVluucoWm/mB92ERhYzHiHr5R//i5tVV/7ruzS@hBuxrzQpL8guGybwSM3CVTidvWplVewqvzrsy68yVTY5zxnCcp3E@xi8ezMfeKStnY6@cjSeOtMguTUFlB5MddHrtQ@8WU41G03SOA8ejpWeeZBoo0SboJXRUFxtpj@eBnZBMuWMMhMEs1@JrIwUssbWxAsU5NP8s6Jw7bv4ZVMcO25xd5QHDtu0KVVWWvIrrqD3xQ2HoZiW1Co@rlSOnPEpNR7c03XTtXEbVxU19ozZduR85S2w/lvy1YFzKJoUqLeJTP064dJEsIbQn2KvKB9LaW8LQ@2CSNk9hyHMhUe8pS4IvGvQCjc1oBN9gZglCMYWa1KsJQkeOq2iEwFSdS73aIsngBWq4Sh4QtfbUY1T@3uhtpYHeD7VblAyFMg08tFWq8A6gVipZhQEnVhUC/Y1uGcQ5K55kum65zot0MuGRTYMgZAYM4F6IQaJGBxjRgYncAsq78KQkLhj@qcdMcPUOMo4bJ9CF5Y58ydmYW@98SHx9KHRCmMPsOPDhhdixtKN6si8rDSOZatnb3LJG654EIfj65PGzJ8@e/vT42dO2XI2o8MI5hk09f6lb1DnDkNFGaGtI63kLIVWi5@EtrHLV7gYGnJdm5pLsSRTOL4ABF6EHg2bxdiLd0lz1Om1W4J4nOLOpRr6QRlJ16SJfKh6X8re6PZbbVR9qOrfDUf13eagoiDa/99eruII9qBTIt1bzAdRA/lYh0WPVkDKZVPTPyK2zanxrBLu0LE68ME3suwgaNwjM85xYtBGzq6agWmshTR8O5fOw/PcHUO18h4IC0bHK9Acs6W4Fj7FLfjcmVjU9qTaZQFYsJ/XFYcstvGyE4WgDiS@Ebcj2BhI79Dbk8QZSvgu2IH/YlBlut/P9BlLO31uQpxWyIk15BGeD6oh65mz3memuM@e7z2Dx33rmsDpj0DLDG/@xOS@OdRs5uHrwGO26m7nZU47lu9a2gDkKrFFl8HG7WoFK5aHfTGlqFy9116n0uw3h7yrhS@yjvUb69sha4m0l86tcBLR/54xuDRbb9P0X5ZAMWm235TaeaxY2AuVrWcuqdEQhq5WuN6N2XSjwpIry0AOqPMfb1FyBy6zHAf@cmjBf1hXBJSYza5NMD7ty3Tr@bam1r/mIBxxEZ/z1ysx/Wq2jp9qPLUvDv0/g7xxGNng@TfgdrD1vsVZL/vVaX8fwOvWxlfW@/gc)

Probably not optimal but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 41 bytes

```
Kzn[, ]nzzn[, miss a few, ]n33z*dn[, ]n+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@7Ki9aRyE2rwpM52YWFyskKqSlloPEjI2rtFIg0tp5//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 74 bytes

```
using System;Console.Write($"{4-3}, {5-3}, miss a few, {33*3}, {64*4:X}");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), <s>60</s> 54 chars

```
=a)commaſspace=b$48+›#a+›#a#"miss a few"#a+7››#a-8›-››
```

if you're wondering, this is a pretty stupid esolang I made a while ago in Node.JS

Answer (score 0):

## TeX, 41 bytes

In TeX you can print the ASCII-value of a character using `` \number`CHAR ``.

```latex
\def~{\number`}~^A, ~^B, miss a few, ~c, ~d
```

Replace `^A` and `^B` in the above code with SOH and STX.

Using just the printable range of ASCII, the following works as well without modifications (4 bytes more):

```latex
\def~{\number`}~^^A, ~^^B, miss a few, ~c, ~d
```

Complete TeX file:

```latex
\def~{\number`}~, ~, miss a few, ~c, ~d
\bye
```

---

<sup>To copy the code above (the complete file), hit on the edit-button, so that you can copy the unprintable ASCII-letters, which are displayed in the editor.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**C++17**

```
#include <iostream>
main()
{
  std::cout << 4 - 3 << ", " << 5 - 3 << ", miss a few, " << 33 * 3 << ", " << 5 * 5 * 4 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. Note that `return 0` contains zero, which is one of the restricted characters. I don't know much about C++ but I think your code might work without the return statement anyway?

Comment: It will. Also, `using std::cout;` doesn't save any bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 129 bytes

```
Cat<Cat<Cat<Cat<Cat<T,St<44,' '>>,Add<T,T>>,St<44,' ','m','i','s','s',' ','a',' ','f','e','w',44,' ',57,57,44,' '>>,T>,St<48,48>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/v/fObHEBh2H6ASX2JiY6KgrqNvZ6TimpABFQoAsuKiOei4QZwJxMRSDxBKhdBoQpwJxuboOVLmpOQjBTQyBGGWhY2JhZ/f/PwA)

Tries to represent each character as its ascii value. If that contains a forbidden number, replace it with its char literal. This only leaves `1` and `2` to deal with.

`1` is replaced with `T`, which evaluates to `I<1>` which is cast into string `1` when concatenated.
`2` is replaced with `Add<T,T>`, which evaluates to `I<2>` which is cast into string `2` when concatenated.

```
Cat<
 ...
     T,                                                                    # "1"
     St<44,' '>>,                                                          # ", "
    Add<T,T>>,                                                             # "2"
   St<44,' ','m','i','s','s',' ','a',' ','f','e','w',44,' ',57,57,44,' '>>,# ", miss a few, 99, "
  T>,                                                                      # "1"
 St<48,48>>                                                                # "00"
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86 opcode, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
BE 8F 81 04 08 29 C9 B1 | 1A AC 04 6E AA E2 FA C3
BE B2 C4 BE B2 FF FB 05 | 05 B2 F3 B2 F8 F7 09 BE
B2 CB CB BE B2 C3 C2 C2 | 92
```

```
fun:	mov esi, src
	sub ecx, ecx
	mov cl, srcEnd-src
x:	lodsb
	add al, '1'-0xC3
	stosb
	loop x
src:	ret
	db ', 2, miss a few, 99, 100', 0
srcEnd:
repeat srcEnd-src-1
	load a byte from src+%
	store byte (a-'1'+0xC3) and 0xFF at src+%
end repeat
funEnd:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNT4QwED23v2IuGzRAhP3KLurJ7J5MTIx309LBkBRKaFH21@NAcV2jsQeYvpl5781UWIuV1Ke4ELYaCtNWwsHh8QjYY945ITXCivNX60TrMs4q8w6oyggq@8ZZLrSGoqtnXPQRrOdYUpzOcd7P9b6bbrbND7WK6RencAvPSBmEw9ML9o6zsnYwnaTfJRfcKYf5nCWSMzQ2TfXASQuUhOVmC6prIBnIYuZpbDmJc2Y76Y3Rx0vk@tIX7zOmjbKSM6EUCEoGaRAn/cOKmp0ZE9qYBnpO1RlrkYyTaBDBkqYtrQUBBX5EsN@T8yQJRrOeP@MtNkiLvlzDSCdICOTJIRStqcZ0uJjUWvTwlYjJRTi6uAZRK5r4eATPRKVIiKfmNPKoNMxK/hpPb/VLh9BwMTqQcE@JG0i39AgFyLuU1s9UaRstTiDD9Y4z1BZ/gJsNgSRcFl8ElVH/UESwWv5JMyc81fcowyc)

Function that output to [esi] assuming enough space, should be placed on right place such that `src` contain no invalid chars

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.1.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.1.1), 145 bytes

```
func main:
push 4
push 3
sub
push ", "
add
push 5
push 3
sub
add
push ", miss a few, "
add
push 33
push 3
mul
add
push ", "
add
push 5
dup
mul
push 4
mul
add
print
ret
end
```

**Commented:**

```
func main:
    ; Push 4 - 3
    push 4
    push 3
    sub
    ; String concatenation:  1 + ", "
    push ", "
    add
    ; Push 5 - 3
    push 5
    push 3
    sub
    ; String concatenation:  "1, " + 2
    add
    push ", miss a few, "
    ; String concatenation:  "1, 2" + ", miss a few, "
    add
    ; Push 33 * 3
    push 33
    push 3
    mul
    ; String concatenation:  "1, 2, miss a few, " + 99
    add
    push ", "
    ; String concatenation:  "1, 2, miss a few, 99" + ", "
    add
    ; Push a 5 and multiply it by itself
    push 5
    dup
    mul
    ; Push 25 * 4
    push 4
    mul
    ; String concatenation:  "1, 2, miss a few, 99, " + 100
    add
    ; Print the value on the top of the stack:
    ;   Stack: [ "1, 2, miss a few, 99, 100" ]
    print
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 32 bytes + Content: 4 bytes = 36 bytes, depends on ASCII-compatible.

- Filename (escaped unprintables): `\001.n.e\002.n.emiss a few.p.ec.n.ed.n`
- Content: `, .p`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhtV9pI9/v@imEWyQwQEhBbyzi6irbLrlJX3W4rUE@EINGQRBIUBPrX@9w7SRCsz9mX01NmcufOfX8be1Y4@P4zGURRENYM48aJBuPrUtcfGh9@1S8Cy35vPT7ZnhFM7GEp8ENn4oRD49r1r42h5cRwp1QpDR1vefxTaEdEt8diPLTCO2KalYqwJ4E/ishx/Wr/@FjWBYumgU1u7Kjre/1cTn0B16Hl9fiu0bMfDG/suqSymyvncsnl0/2LXyXNsgSP6EFKQB3x7AyXQm0Rb/QFTdn@2Wx8vjq/OJQV09xMgacfzxufj79c1T@enR3VL2RZtIjuEZqdHeyf/3r16ejsvPGxWQMypJPLzYjSyidKS4EfhQOxWN65fO2KPRy7VmSTcIAX/CCC3aM/6oWB60TCch0rJPoN0bKzcoFmf6ELTWq4aqL55/Fx/eRQ1hQLUBoZ9kQ4cPqRYt4jiJgA7O7AJ9mfOSWSlJE1U5BwYIMNI98nvtvbzaEXnIiUubAfLJfQDOlbbmjT@fwVdLKKryRQOJN5aPeIFhoTY2qIEH6eDE3xfSKd@RxUVpQA5we2oAlYwH2Q794JcGHguDbjrC9N0bVCGziUKXE8wvp5TvrgDWGHVldYYWgPr90pOt4Hn@97RH@IxuV5NCJ6PSRmubJZ3Xrzdvsd0VptL9/R5jcjOyClufV4R7SDow@N5swFJj1ZfSPAuiwYOV7UJ1pw6n/0mk7jqlsPzx8@9d/bR6Ozx78mn6dfni6t/ehieNI7LOiZ7MaGNv8PrLOmpPUWJVmT0I5sUwomcf1He8TCWARGN7q0mDU5J7RNBRVgSE2FBqO0eF6kNcoFit6XoaRU9P0RExDxruPZpL9rCj5z@iwFhDvS5AoPgCFasp7L9aXs8dkR40KxJPVW2BELG7xOEEudPg7QE/H@mPU5shMvCccnSEg50xSLxZLNjwwUh/jKMQs5ABBj0R973cjxPXLMukr2bgbk5WFkde9abqHQkd0VJLiCOC6fJR6jbmIDF3R3dZ2ncPiX0NDLnUQQsMNioSlP6A/Eh/BRwUfTkIi1TnTcBQW9gjRaj5PpU8fQDctAC3g7ZsKclixyUCWlGIHOadeCiIbYpsvgVnjgaxZTsTrGHiW/gGheAcjVQE8k6SudjJ6Ry2U8ntgyhvDZWHp6WcSSebvjVfcqHySixEKQR8MnJetVWV7qEgtHrUQewFDu8/4FydTtEKMisftG2G5j7UtTlM5Zi8RmJrobkQpWIqA0T71gSRMXCNJsn@JuAAAtzIPJAt/rhg@jqGPkmbVT5gWjVYDM0@PvCgf/2JNILIzAmAEZEUKBWIQ7ZQH/k6MB7AageGTkMxlLLGahzBitvp14Q1hoFOeqYxQMF6g23@vAhlngexCgC4Zq@V4IAgBwgEBjaOhwXIZdKotYlCFJX6i5uaamNjttOQWzI7Pg10JBBBK@9QokRfANAjiXA@azGCSDOHTH12E0YlmzuMlFz3ZtaBinLV13OiJWDC5@dUnrK@kU8H7XmMEVRhUgS4s0R3K0GJP8WwJZpBAaM0eXlRe4/@emm9xQPMmS6T/m@Cx4akUIffB4dgN3gMiIOSdmjMazlM98tB1Uz0BMZLb5XpCpzMbuEitCrIoScMT3MZEmO3LKZ1dyApenYiqvxGLN2hC5zGgXjL1JYVoDp@9NdFgzsOZh3YB1Y1qD5va6XkfNwxmWoFsIwdsdR9wWCnEVArTbDmZH2h8h1Ur5rGFoMcAAc4ANDQObJkqeN05ZjgvjBr4JDF7iGvqjygPnCjKhb4@iYQfsbuSgchoiEmlCAyiuEHDAZ@rEQuBCbXu4xS6HLbu/nAdUV9Ywh5nJtfk8/u4B6ZEdjUcedp6YSwEJWL1eylXH7/A6Sr8z@A1jTfrdziKg5zykgA2F4KcEQqOUN/66eM9oDiogmOOFZMt2HJfl89adhOSBBE/74CDugxpMCVFaeTQ09Hx5ddkybHbAZ3eQdUCmI@EH@wH66wAoHuwgVByAy2BTPEgQYPOCOIoODLjq8z0CRY4LSO2wO3KCSCaCYvez7d43WoIGNoJxVH2uNrlTdshRn@LvjHfkoZIJRFtvcLH5M7@vtcfflgcEDnbLK0e/Px8pbZ5PLtZOkCkq/3z@mZ3x2ZkENCWJrieuJ2crSGNWT3oC08s7MEDUdypbb/hevYb9dIn2AWmBBcbeN6NkINmxJ8YeDh/PRJPdssXuZc2avqrLn8gMbtVXYPvsJG1K@9cwpdcgZU9e60fLGwFLR5gMGJSP2Wf4XTn34zHi9UOPNYr3xcOi@4wzu5eABHOXa3s30YDdcxVBDWg4jR3pigbEz5ixQ5nU7ftio1jm/Bttmfq7Dt07LFS3a9UtHHqWbByQ4ZR9WOd9xU6K9eJl8QufnUhauqqRph9hfbJv7BEVdQn44hLYqpknHvaqb2OnbG3z65Ft3WHFq0OtrbY2tzpYOy9ltarXk8sxCnZ6th3fK1ehu9Wl3MSOGiPB@ylyvLEtFmj7GLu@U91GxN2tt5wrsJLhmXvMgH@RXwir64As0JnilF3mv6zq2F0x/im7WDdAuHL4eS0BHsAtt8VPXNVaML0J2X4rVUiDE27BFp8weYuNjlALjo64uY2/b3W9Iz@tOmC0wgo3I3jF@Z47zeVAJpyt9hktjWoEthTVwARQSc3zGDFrznx8TjQgB2UIMDJAYkX@CfujeB9zhFzmCXZZ/KFCKw6wBPjHzv3Kxem/uLi7evFpKRSLr6ZyJeIvEaMVSwywSq5bfhgf3@FgPwCXIcrqeQ89s4qSdEnEE3dQVNY8pkpUA@tuAWoRw9QBuW7jJa6HnMeOkwoJPfrMTLUh5PWbCh@QtPAif7ExNZYokGPAGlB0RNsx9/RGrbHmO9W41ijmX1DETnaf1IPfkmhhyvAwJrpqlUm8ZGvk0h75mWXE3O@6e/eGW3ONe85XuUI3/Ic0N16luQE0NxRNbO3f3zf3T46k1jbNcskr2bBWcB06YUgsAhNvKSjZXQT1Sp72U/1j8@KoeSG1IikF2vf01ZRVZOg8eYuTPvx41tCGoewFxmOX6F2ovisnCc3n21hGbC96DeXH60vL9MEbyxf5ypX/9txunqkRD6ZHmLrwTzz6HSl7o2I5Hcq@qhqdJ21Wyrd5FkawdhmHEr6g8KzBBi7V6KR3ifob1BhrgD/EOQWAox@Az2L2qkRvVtcQcEAJ4dwngdMr2pEztItBNxgXH8In0bMim6@qWf17NSPLcYnuVSupOqAEK7Vn2@0FKtMuG9rzS0uvlKtvq9ubb6rb8CaBtw9YRY2v8bhqxS@5f29nfL/FdsKF4vMvHY1oinAv2xquH8/Opaalox1WBgfmMAdHCnwb8W7L6cjlH0Pa7Q2fFh1IxubZxpYpZTmRNSR0@dK/h5ffPaFtD8aR5LjbypqdWDccypJ5PEWCSBgQPfz@Pw)

### How it works

- Pxem is a stack-based procedure language.
- `.n` is `printf("%d",pop) unless empty`.
- `.e` calls subroutine (which is content).
- `.p` is `putc pop until empty`.
- Other non-command substrings are literal: pushed from backward.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 54 bytes

```
[`MSwgMi`,`OTksIDEwMA`].map(atob).join`, miss a few, `
```

*inspired by @arnauld 's answer

Answer (score 0):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 34 bytes

```
^!# ,@@^# ,wef a ssim ,(@)c# ,@@d#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P8/TlFZQcfBIQ5IlqemKSQqFBdn5iroaDhoJoMlUpT//wcA)

Explaination:

```
^!# ,@@^# ,wef a ssim ,(@)c# ,@@d# (implicit push 0)
^                                  Top of stack += 1
 !#                                Output Top of stack as number without popping
    ,@@                            Output ", "
       ^                           Top of stack += 1
        #                          Output Top of stack as number
          ,wef a ssim ,(@)         Output ", miss a few, "
                          c#       Push 99 onto the stack and output
                             ,@@   output ", "
                                d# Push 100 onto the stack and output
```