# Ways to add 1 to lists of lists

Tags: code-golf, array

*Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70002842/expand-list-of-lists-by-adding-element-once-to-every-list) StackOverflow question*

In this challenge you will take a list of lists of integers, e.g.

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
```

And an additional single integer (e.g. `n = 7`).  If you were to add `n` to the front of one of the lists in `A` there would be as many ways to do that as there are lists in `A`. In this example `4`:

```
A' = [[7,1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
A' = [[1,2],[7,3,4],[5],[]]
A' = [[1,2],[3,4],[7,5],[]]
A' = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[7]]
```

In this challenge you will output all possible ways to do this, in the order of how early `n` is inserted.  So for the example the output is just:

```
[ [[7,1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
, [[1,2],[7,3,4],[5],[]]
, [[1,2],[3,4],[7,5],[]]
, [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[7]]
]
```

This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf) so answer answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Test cases

```
9, [] -> []
9, [[]] -> [[[9]]]
10, [[1,2,3]] -> [[[10,1,2,3]]]
7, [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]] -> [[[7,1,2],[3,4],[5],[]],[[1,2],[7,3,4],[5],[]],[[1,2],[3,4],[7,5],[]],[[1,2],[3,4],[5],[7]]]
2, [[1,2],[2,2],[2]] -> [[[2,1,2],[2,2],[2]],[[1,2],[2,2,2],[2]],[[1,2],[2,2],[2,2]]]
```

Comment: The lists aren't guaranteed to be unique, right?

Answer (score 10):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>185</strike> 184 bytes

My first ever code golf submission

```
fn r(a:Vec<Vec<u8>>,n:u8){let mut x:Vec<Vec<Vec<u8>>>=Vec::new();for i in 0..a.len(){let mut b=a.clone();let c=&vec![n];b[i].splice(0..0,c.iter().cloned());x.push(b);}print!("{:?}",x)}
```

**Explanation**

This code copies the list for every sublist, then appends the number to the front of it, adds it to a final list which it then prints. We can also get away with returning the print statement to save a ;!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7dCoMwDIVfJe5ipFCK@2NSp3uL3YgX2nWsoFVquwnis7vqcLtI@EjOOYlxnZ2mhwaDBb9JcZnLRWlKNXcRGSppoXYW@t9yFaSJJ861fCOJH40BBUpDyFjBKqnxby2Tgomq0dLr5plIti8pgkzncZmpnHVtpYRE7wypYMpKg@RruCMhcc9a1z2xJPHYGqVtgJuBX8cN7ck4P14Xyl@DweCSurQdhX1OYeEDhePKpxVyD2efOH0A)

Edit: Kevin Cruijssen pointed out a space in my print.

Edit: @Bubbler showed me what it's like to truly golf in Rust and got it down to 90 bytes! I won't be updating the byte count in the header since I don't believe that his edits counts as "edits" rather an entire new submission and it doesn't reflect my work.

```
|a:&mut[Vec<_>],n|{for i in 0..a.len(){a[i].insert(0,n);print!("{:?}",a);a[i].remove(0);}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Submissions are required to make a serious effort to meet the winning criteria as much as possible, in this case code-golf. You did a pretty good job of that already with short variable names and things like that, but you should make sure to also remove unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: @AaroneousMiller I had realized shortly after posting that I left in some whitespace and it has been promptly removed! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Also, I don't know personally know anything about Rust, but you should check out our [tips for golfing in Rust](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74096/tips-for-golfing-in-rust) to see if there are any other golfs you could use. Happy golfing!

Comment: You forgot to remove 1 space in your print. :)

Comment: With lots of type and output format fiddling, it is possible to get down to [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##tVFda8MgFH3vr7AdlCs46b5YqUv2L/YSZBhjmWBMMKYtpP72zqTNxmAbhXUPyvVwzz3nelzb@MPVNBPGVFsolCheZVUozCdrixoQqxcln/rTLtOU2FW7xNfpiI142hnlUdl6tEs2Sk4zztaVQxppixaUCmqUBfzRlCeCSlNZBZj1mEzmA8tylmea06Y2WiqIzAWRVHvlAB8JBWDMdrRumzfIMQu70Nv0Z9uETzeYlqKGvd5fylYe4qsyRkkPePDVfuur@8evqZ22fgqzbvUcZiTHYfCx@ZuPQVjbRjkPC2J/UtlCTzxbSfw@VWA2dDhVVpu4cAw7HKKKi7vMo1B2kuCXlyiFjmzUTcbPiAmgBA05DNcNQbecHIE7gu7H@mEsOGeTr1oO5qdJ5DHmFA7v).

Comment: And [90](https://tio.run/##tZJda8MgFIbv@ytsB@UITrovVuqS/YvdFCnGWCYYExLTFpL89szYZh@wjcK6C0UP5/V9zjmWdeX6q@laGJPvIVUi3cg8VZhPthZVIFYvSj4Nq17GMbGreomv4zE2xuPGKIey2qFDtFNyuuZsm5dII23RglJBjbKA35OSSFBpcqsAsyEmo3lQWc6Stea0KoyWCrxyQSTVTpWAj4IUMGYHWtTVKySYdYduwHRnY8IHDaaZKKDV7aWwks7fcmOUdIADV/0tV/OPrSlKbd0UZs3quZuRBHeBY/c3jmCsbaVKBwtif3LZwyA820n8/qrALGSUKst3vmA/7OBS@lrm3mh9suCXt8iE9mrUTMZm@AmgCIU5hO2GoFtOjoE7gu7H88N44JwFse9ghaK@/YS8GYjbS@H2DH1NGhxhfoImj/5LdP0b) as a closure.

Comment: is there a reason why lang name is in all-caps?

Comment: @Bubbler wow this is next level, good stuff. Guess I've got a lot to learn!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
UεXšNǝ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/9NzWiKML/Y7P/f/fnCs62lDHKFYn2ljHBEiaAnFsLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZXF/0PPbY04uvDQumK/43P/1@poxvyPjrbUiY6N1VGINjTQiY421DHSMY4F880h3FidaGMdEyBpGgtSGBsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
U       # Pop the store the first (implicit) input-integer in variable `X`
 ε      # Map over the second (implicit) input-list of lists:
  Xš    #  Prepend `X` in front of the current part
    Nǝ  #  And replace the item at the current map-index in the second (implicit)
        #  input-list with this modified part
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

This is [Willem Van Onsem's SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70002937/4040600) with a couple of trivial golfs.

```
n!(a:b)=((n:a):b):map(a:)(n!b)
_!_=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P09RI9EqSdNWQyPPKlETyLLKTSwACmlq5CkmaXLFK8bbRsf@z03MzLMtKMrMK1ExV4yONtQxitWJNtYxAZKmQBwb@x8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 54 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.75 bytes

```
vJ¨2¹^Ȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwidkrCqDLCuV7IpiIsIiIsIltbMSwyXSxbMyw0XSxbNV0sW11dXG43Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
100010101100011111000100110100010110110111100010110010
```

Comment: [Alternate 9 byter](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%BA%8F%C6%9B%C2%B9n%E2%80%A1%E2%81%B0p%C2%A8M&inputs=%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C4%5D%2C%5B5%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%0A7&header=&footer=%3B%E2%81%8B)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 36 bytes

Prompts for the list of lists as a nested vector then the integer to be added. Index origin = 0

```
m←((⍴n)*2)⍴n←,⎕⋄m[(1+⍴n)×⍳⍴n]←⎕,¨n⋄m
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tfy6QqaHxqHdLnqaWkSaIBgroABU96m7JjdYw1AZLHZ7@qHcziBULlAVK6hxakQdS8B9oBtf/NK5HvWu4LLmAdFeToYKRgjGXoQGQpwFkaypoGCuYAElTIAYq0@Qy5@ICAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>22 17 21</sup> 20 bytes

```
(<@#"0~[:=#\),&.>"1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWwclJUM6qKtbJVjNHXU9OyUDGP/a3JxcaUmZ@QrmCukKRgqGCkYW1soWFobQgQNDYCiOlY2YAmEOpNqPaCItbGCibXpfwA)

Could save 4 bytes if we can assume each element of the input is unique.

Consider `7 f 1 2 3; 1 2; 4`:

- `[:=#\` Create an identity matrix whose sides equal our list length:

  ```
  1 0 0
  0 1 0
  0 0 1
  ```
- `<@#"0~` Use that as a mask to copy our new element, and box each result.  Zeros become empty boxes:

  ```
  ┌─┬─┬─┐
  │7│ │ │
  ├─┼─┼─┤
  │ │7│ │
  ├─┼─┼─┤
  │ │ │7│
  └─┴─┴─┘
  ```
- `,&.>"1]` For each row, join elementwise to the original input:

  ```
  ┌───────┬─────┬───┐
  │7 1 2 3│1 2  │4  │
  ├───────┼─────┼───┤
  │1 2 3  │7 1 2│4  │
  ├───────┼─────┼───┤
  │1 2 3  │1 2  │7 4│
  └───────┴─────┴───┘
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
t=>a=>a.map(u=>a.map(v=>u==v?[t,...u]:v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/E1i4RiPRyEws0SmGMMlu7UlvbMvvoEh09Pb3SWKsyTc3/yfl5xfk5qXo5@ekaaRqWmhrRsZqaXKiihgZA4WhDHSMd41hMWXOoZKxOtLGOCZA0BWIs6owQ6owgJEjRfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
(i=1;x##~Insert~{i++,1})/@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@18j09bQuuL9pIXKynWeecWpRSV11Zna2jqGtZr6Dspq/wOKMvNKHNKiq6sNdRSManUUqo11FExAtCmIqAUS5rH/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
≡⍜(⇌⊔⊡)⊂⇡⊃⧻¤
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4omh4o2cKOKHjOKKlOKKoSniioLih6HiioPip7vCpAoKZiB7fSA5CmYge1tdfSA5CmYge1sxIDIgM119IDEwCmYge1sxIDJdIFszIDRdIFs1XSBbXX0gNwpmIHtbMSAyXSBbMiAyXSBbMl19IDIK)

-1 thanks to Bubbler

```
≡⍜(⇌⊔⊡)⊂⇡⊃⧻¤
         ⊃⧻¤  # fix the array and get its length
        ⇡     # range (of length)
≡⍜(⇌⊔⊡)       # change each unboxed reversed row by...
       ⊂      # join (the integer input)
              # then unreverse, re-box, and put each item back
```

Comment: `⍜⊡(□⊂:⊔)` -> `⍜(⇌⊔⊡)⊂` to save 1.

Comment: @Bubbler Clever, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 33 bytes

```
L$`\[+(?=(.+),(.+))
$>`$2,$1
,]
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30clISZaW8PeVkNPW1MHRGhyqdglqBjpqBhy6cRyxf7/Hx1tqGMUqxNtrGMCJE2BODZWxxwA) Takes `n` as the second argument. Explanation:

```
L$`\[+(?=(.+),(.+))
```

Find the beginning of each list.

```
$>`$2,$1
```

For each occurrence, output the list with `n` moved to that position.

```
,]
]
```

Fix up the list if it was originally empty.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda a,L:[[[a][:l is k]+l for l in L]for k in L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BC8IwDIXv/RWhp1WjqFOKgwkeBcGLt9hDxQ3H6ja2IvjrZ@rUix4a3vteQpPm4a91Ffd5euqdvZ0vFizuEyKyhhIHRQelGTvI6xbYVbA3QZaD7MUxlVKuEcjAZMNVzGdsaI4LjM3A2M3wDYzQ79ggxbjkuuL37dT4G@GnX@NfPECNf3GAmv/lLadd4wofyVMlFe9NNLrZJsru1qH/ZGENqdTrRh9uPBoR9A4PL5fYrstaD3k02qk0PYimLSqe2zoHdSlV/wQ)

Will not work on lists with multiple references to the same object. I..e.: `L = [[10],[10]]` fine (same value but different objects) but `L = 2*[[10]]` fail (twice the same object)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 44 bytes** by replacing two `function` occurrences with `\`s.

```r
function(x,A)Map(function(i){A[[i]]=c(x,A[[i]]);A},seq(A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsJADEX3nmLATQIRrLUMIhXmAJ4gZCGDAwNSra0giGcfJ61KF13kJ7z/P@SeQp3Co/F9vDbwJIfH0w3@IOLLMUeR2qs5nLh3b@rOLTjEFGBH5hK7HhCXZnUwLIsAxfoLPRS0oRJ/JnO2BiSiQTvNIXkoaaurUpm0rJaEONtZqzySh0doaRaP0NIsVmjzD@kD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 47 bytes

```julia
n\l=(k=keys(l)).|>i->k.|>j->[fill(n,i==j);l[j]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc3BCsIwDAbg@54khU6sU6RI@yJZDwMV0oYy3AQHe/cu4mVCD38C@X5IfDMN5lNK7tlBcumxTMBKHVZPrU@yYuvxScyQNTkX1Y0xhlDuNI08LGB7DKoZX5RnzqCa3R1DVcxRyOiT7up@/XHQ2OmzzIuk3rT2@8WI/2dfLhs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 60 bytes

```ruby
->n,l{(0...t=l.size).map{|i|[*l[0,i],[n]+l[i],*l[i+1...t]]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NDoIwEIX3nqKJG5WhoQXSuICLTGahiSRNKiH@LBQ4e50KKFEW8zr93pt2Lvfjw1eFj8saXLtJpJS3wsmrfZ628nxo2s52uHOYgCXAmiKH3DCwkQpZor73jagwB0TFEc2VcmVEtArGHgQSrUVc8vkmQiXMUIGGlCaL7wlMaIiZMRVehIw155oGwoSBfxemEQOLeIAGFnGA5vO/0N8F9KCzdTX8ODDLLrFRifwL)

Answer (score 2):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 15 bytes

Beats J by 5 bytes, so I'm happy :)

```
],`"\:]:#":i:&#
```

## Explanation

```
           i:&#    Construct an NxN identity matrix (N = # lists)
        #":        Foreach num I in that, replace with left arg I times
      ]:           Convert that to a hook
    \:             For each item on the right and entirety of left
 ,`"               Concatenate left to back of right on an element x element basis
]                  Where the left is the list
```

Takes the number on the left and the list of lists on the right.

Answer (score 2):

## jq, 51 bytes

```
. as$a|[range(length)]|map(. as$i|$a|.[$i]|=[$n]+.)
```

Where `$n` is `n`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 21 bytes

```
n!(a++b:c)=a++(n:b):c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6FlvzFDUStbWTrJI1bYG0Rp5VkqZVMkRuf25iZp6CrYK5gqJCdLShjlGsTrSxjgmQNAXi2FiIKphJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＩＥηＥη⎇⁼κμ⮌⊞Ｏ⮌λθλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQCNDRwFKhaQW5SUWVWq4FpYm5hRrZOso5GrqKASllqUWFadqBJQWZ/gXpBYlluQXacAEc4AKCjWBRI4mCFj//x9trhMdbahjFKsTbaxjAiRNgTg2Nva/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  η                 Input list of lists
 Ｅ                  Map over each list
    η               Input list of lists
   Ｅ                Map over each list
       κ            Outer index
      ⁼             Equal to
        μ           Inner index
     ⎇              If true then
             λ      Current list
            ⮌       Reversed
              θ     Input `n`
          ⊞Ｏ        Appended
         ⮌          Reversed
               λ    Otherwise current list
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Charcoal's default output format might be a little tricky to read, so here's a 17-byte version with prettier output:

```
Ｅη⭆¹Ｅη⎇⁼κξ⮌⊞Ｏ⮌νθν
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpNC8IwEET/So4bWA/1Aw@ePYqlegs5LGUxYkjbTVr0168p6MAMvMf0gaQfKKq28kwFLjRCQHMrlR4rNGh@7s6SSD5wnmaKGV5o3hZNxwtLZmjnHK4jC5VB4C9TPUy2TrJrTqruiM41uPXodrive6j13utmiV8) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 48 bytes

```
(n,a)->matrix(#a,,i,j,concat([n][1..i==j],a[j]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7CoAwEEXRrQg2E3gK/rCKGxmmGARlAsYQUrj7qMU91U2arTtTPRpfKUJdt11asj3UKmAI2O@4ayGOwkPfm/dBoBzEuZqyxUIHrWAeMAp4wvy5fMk/vA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

Expects `(n)(list_of_lists)`.

#### Version 1

```javascript
n=>a=>a.map((v,i,[...b])=>(b[i]=[n,...v],b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrBCsIwEETvfskurIttFfGQ/siyh6S2EqlJaSW/H1foRYSZObw3T1/8NqxxeR9Tvo91cjW53lv45ReAQpGEmYOi6yFIVCeJDBSlgFiHnLY8jzznB0xwQxBFPPzS5mRYGmqp03973aWSdHS2vVi/v/oB)

#### Version 2

```javascript
n=>a=>a.map((_,i)=>a.map(v=>i--?v:[n,...v]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i4RiPRyEws0NOJ1MjVhnDJbu0xdXfsyq@g8HT09vbJYTc3/yfl5xfk5qXo5@ekaaRqWmhrRQFEuVFFDA6BwtKGOkY5xLKasOVQyVifaWMcESJoCMUjdfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xP`, 13 bytes

```
aRA_(BPEb)MEa
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWAUuyCpaUlaboWaxODHOM1nAJckzR9XRMhYlCp3dFK0dGG1kax1tHG1iZA0hSIY2OVdBTMYboB)

#### Explanation

The `-x` flag evaluates the inputs, meaning we can treat `[[1];[2;3]]` as a list rather than a string.

```
aRA_(BPEb)MEa
            a  First command-line input (the nested list)
          ME   Map the following function to that list, enumerated (first function arg
               is index, second function arg is sublist):
a               The whole list
 RA             Replace the element at index given by
   _            first function arg
    (    )      with
     B          second function arg
      PE        with the following value prepended:
        b       Second command-line input
```

The `-P` flag prints each sublist of the result, formatted as a list, on a separate line. Other formats that could work include `-p` and `-S`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->n,l{i=-1;l.map{|w|z=*l;z[i+=1]=[n]+w;z}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCoMwEITvfYpAb3UsJlpCkfgiyx7agyBYkUKR@vPsaVJNK62HnZBvZpK9P65PWxobFw3qoTKxzOvj7dIOYzf25lDnPVWRkWyo4ajL@2myrSjpBCLJIOUmdZMx884bZwhi3ou4cOebCJk4RhIKKQfL3RMENMf0kvIvInN6chMKvqHx7yJUNDbxDDU2sYf6879Q3wXUrKt1FX4crLJbbFFm@wI)

Comment: `->n,l{i=-1;l.map{z=*l;z[i+=1]=[n]+_1;z}}` to save 2 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 24 bytes

```
1svsa.*zi{{1gv+]}x/ap}^m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@Q@t@wuKw4UU@rKrO62jC9TDu2tkI/saA2Lvd/ccF/oJCCUa1CtbGCCZA0BeLaWgVLAA)

I'm sure there's a better way...

```
1sv    # Save input as 1
sa.*   # Repeat arr len(arr) times
zi     # Zip with indices
{
 {
  1gv  # Get input (value1)
  +]   # Prepend
 }
 x/    # Reorder local stack
 ap    # Apply function to index (from zip)
}^m    # Push and map each
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü↨○◘╞Q┐p☺Ç
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81170908c651bf700180&i=9,+%5B%5D%0A9,+%5B%5B%5D%5D%0A10,+%5B%5B1,2,3%5D%5D%0A7,+%5B%5B1,2%5D,%5B3,4%5D,%5B5%5D,%5B%5D%5D%0A2,+%5B%5B1,2%5D,%5B2,2%5D,%5B2%5D%5D&m=2)