# Extract and Divide

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, division

### Challenge

For a given positive integer \$n\$:

1. Repeat the following until \$n < 10\$ (until \$n\$ contains one digit).
2. Extract the last digit.
3. If the extracted digit is even (including 0) multiply the rest of the integer by \$2\$ and add \$1\$ ( \$2n+1\$ ). Then go back to `step 1` else move to `step 4`.
4. Divide the rest of the integer with the extracted digit (integer / digit) and add the remainder (integer % digit), that is your new \$n\$.

**Note**: In case `n < 10` at the very beginning obviously you don't move to step 2. Skip everything and print \$[n, 0]\$.

---

### Input

**n**: Positive integer.

---

### Output

**[o, r]**: `o`: the last `n`, `r`: number of repeats.

---

### Step-by-step example

For input `n = 61407`:

```
Repeat 1: 6140_7 -> 6140 / 7 = 877, 6140 % 7 = 1 => 877  + 1 = 878
Repeat 2: 87_8   -> 2 * 87 + 1 = 175 (even digit)
Repeat 3: 17_5   -> 17   / 5 = 3,   17   % 5 = 2 => 3    + 2 = 5 ( < 10, we are done )
```

The output is `[5, 3]` (last `n` is 5 and 3 steps repeats).

---

### Rules

There are really no rules or restrictions just assume `n > 0`. You can either print or return the output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most answers from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture-oeis-a006577?rq=1) can be trivially modified to answer this question.

Comment: @Arnauld No, the output needs to be two numbers (returned or printed). I guess you could convert the decimal number to string, replace `.` with whitespace and print it.

Comment: Do we enter step 2 if n<10?

Comment: @Arnauld That is not the same for n=2 and n=4.

Comment: @Arnauld Let me know if it's any better :)

Comment: Yes. It's much clearer now. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 93 bytes

```r
function(n,r=0,e=n%%10,d=(n-e)/10)"if"(n<10,c(n,r),"if"(e%%2,f(d%/%e+d%%e,r+1),f(d*2+1,r+1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoAwDADRuwiBxEbaiOjGnsYm0E2Eouevn@U8pnXL3W4/rno6OrecWLMDSOKS0SelKImGagP6/uLxTcQ/KMDMhgUiaCgAyi0IfTLOQf4g6oarLGmj/gA)

Comment: Save some bytes by getting rid of second "if", reversing `n<10` condition and using `%/%` in d definition : [TIO](https://tio.run/##FYxBCoAwDAT/IgQSG7AVUTzUj4intoFeIhR9f42nHWZgW5fY5dX01FtRuUXPJSpA8JxtJwMaqgyox86CCfM4u8DZSnEZoNBZAExd3FwgTv8JURdcw@I36h8)

Comment: agree with @KirillL.  . Also unfortunately `f=` needs to be included in the bytecount since the function is called recursively.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78 77 76</s> 73 bytes

Recursive version. Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).

```python
f=lambda n,r=0:n>9and f(n%2*sum(divmod(n/10,n%10))or n/10*2+1,-~r)or[n,r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctLCoAgFADAq7gJnmakEkVBXSRaGCIJ@Qz7QJuubrWcxWz3sQRUKdl@1X42miCPvehwaDUaYgEzxfbTg3GXDwawlIJjJgWlIZJfTOWSF0/8PH53Slt0eICFWlaioTS9)

## 74 bytes

Full program.

```python
n,i=input(),0
while n>9:i+=1;r,R=n/10,n%10;n=[r-~r,r/R+r%R][R&1]
print n,i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08n0zYzr6C0RENTx4CrPCMzJ1Uhz87SKlPb1tC6SCfINk/f0EAnT9XQwDrPNrpIt65Ip0g/SLtINSg2OkjNMJaroCgzr0QBaMz//2aGJgbmAA)

Comment: Since `2` divides `10`, is `n%10%2` not equivalent to `n%2`?

Comment: Great point by @JonathanFrech that will get you to 73 bytes.  I think the following form would also work, and is also 73 bytes: `def g(n,r=0):u,v=n/10,n%10;return u and g([u-~u,u/v+u%v][v&1],r+1)or(n,r)`

Comment: Somehow Jonathan's message did not appear in my inbox... Indeed, you're right, editing ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,r=0)=>(x=n/10|0)?f((n%=10)&1?x/n+x%n|0:x-~x,r+1):[n,r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoNADADA11gS1JpAURBSHyIeRN1SkaysIjmIX1@d@8z90W9D@K97rn6cYnQCmgUhlC@YaMF0EjYOQBNhwhc3VmhqiZ5UW35ZFlLGun1OFwevm1@m9@J/4KDkD1WI8QY)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (n, r = 0) =>         // n = input, r = number of iterations
  (x = n / 10 | 0) ?      // x = floor(n / 10); if x is not equal to 0:
    f(                    //   do a recursive call:
      (n %= 10) & 1 ?     //     n = last digit; if odd:
        x / n + x % n | 0 //       use quotient + remainder of x / n
      :                   //     else:
        x - ~x,           //       use x - (-x - 1) = x + x + 1 = 2x + 1
      r + 1               //     increment the number of iterations
    )                     //   end of recursive call
  :                       // else:
    [n, r]                //   return [ final_result, iterations ]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 19 bytes

```
[DgD–#ÁćDÈi\·>ë‰O]?
```

Explanation:

```
[                     Start infinite loop
 DgD                  Get the length
    –#                If it's 1, print the loop index and break.
      ÁćD             Extract: "hello" -> "hell", "o"
         Èi           if even,
           \·>        Double and increment
              ë       else,
               ‰O     Divmod, and sum the result (div and mod).
                 ]    End if statement & infinite loop
                  ?   Print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P8wNWFiMWX//1tEZ0TigJMjw4HEh0TDiGlcwrc@w6vigLBPXT///zYxNDA3)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```julia
function d(n,c=0)l,r=n÷10,n%10;n>9 ? d(r%2<1 ? 2l+1 : l÷r+l%r,c+1) : [n,c]end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7tCoIwFIZv5UAIG4q4ZR9W1oVE4JpTFuNMTkrdmRfgha35p3/v837A@5qcVeIbQjehHq1HaBlmui64y6jGZRZFhokoznit4BZDSuRFRCVdKuAEbpkpdQllOhU88j2OHwbbMJDF0SFrmZDbcrc/HCvOYQOdJ3jaHmJqekNv@JAaVvLQRL@B/xGT9/laZZ3SoyerHFuplJzz8AM)

- -1 (thanks Mr. Xcoder)

Comment: Whis is my first golfcode :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Save a byte using `<1` rather than `==0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,r=0{n>9?(a=n%10;n/=10;f[a%2<1?n-~n:n/a+n%a,r+1]):[n,r]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5Pp8jWoDrPztJeI9E2T9XQwDpP3xZIpkUnqhrZGNrn6dblWeXpJ2rnqSbqFGkbxmpaRQP1xNb@L1BIizYzNDEwj@UCMS1j/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 79 bytes

```
(\d+)[02468]$
;$.(_2*$1*
(\d+)(.)
$2*_;$1*
}`(_+);(\1)*(_*)
;$.($3$#2*
^;*
$.&;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxCoAwDEDRPdcwSJJCaWtRIUexWgUdXBzE1bNX7Prfv4/nvDZfCqXd8ORC7McZQdFSDoJeoAJZBgyS9S/vStmwUvIslIXrjR02QWBRAbStltL76IYP) Explanation:

```
(\d+)[02468]$
;$.(_2*$1*
```

If the last digit is even, multiply the rest of the integer by 2 and add 1. This always results in an odd number, so we don't need to repeat this.

```
(\d+)(.)
$2*_;$1*
```

Split off the last digit and convert to unary for the divmod.

```
}`(_+);(\1)*(_*)
;$.($3$#2*
```

Divide the rest of the integer by the last digit and add the remainder. Then repeat the whole program until there's only one digit left.

```
^;*
$.&;
```

Count the number of operations performed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 61 bytes

```perl6
{tail kv $_,{$1%2??$0/$1+$0%$1+|0!!$0*2+1}...{!/(.+)(.)/}: 2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTRCkAwFADQX7mrS5vp7m6JIvkUeaCEElKaffs4D2cfj7WM2wPpBG301zCvsNyAfe7RJq7rkA1ajZz8vywEcua0DUTkhZGklSRlQg0uxHN4YJKlLbhSTfwA)

Returns (r, o).

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>112</s> <s>104</s> <s>100</s> 93 bytes

```swift
var n=Int(readLine()!)!,r=0,p=n%10;while n>9{n=[n/10*2+1,n/10/p+n/10%p][n%2];r+=1};print(n,r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/LLFIIc/WM69Eoyg1McUnMy9VQ1NRU1GnyNZAp8A2T9XQwLo8IzMnVSHPzrI6zzY6T9/QQMtI21AHxNAv0AZRqgWx0XmqRrHWRdq2hrXWBUWZQOPydIo0//83MzQxMP8PAA)

Prints `n r`

- -7 (Thanks to Mr. Xcoder)

Comment: Very nice first answer (+1)! `var n=Int(readLine()!)!,r=0,p=n%10;while n>9{n=[n/10*2+1,n/10/p+n/10%p][n%2];r+=1};print(n,r)` should save you 7 bytes (golfing the conditional).

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 43 bytes

Feels messy and bad but here it is anyway

```
;0{hl1&|⟨{h⟨k{t%₂0&h×₂+₁|⟨÷+%⟩}t⟩}↰₁{t+₁}⟩}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39qgOiPHUK3m0fwV1RlAIru6RPVRU5OBWsbh6UBa@1FTI0ju8HZt1UfzV9aWgIhHbRuAwtUlIMlakMD//2aGJgbm/6MA)

Answer (score 2):

**VBA (Excel), <s>145?, 142, 139,</s> 123 bytes**

Condensed Form:

```vb
Sub t(n)
While n>10
e=Right(n, 1)
n=Left(n,Len(n)-1)
If e Mod 2=0Then n=n*2+1 Else n=Int(n/e)+n Mod e
c=c+1
wend
Debug.?n;c
End Sub
```

Expanded (with comments)

```vb
Sub test(n) 'For a given positive integer n
    'Repeat the following until n<10
    While n > 10
        'Extract the last digit
        e = Right(n, 1)
        'Remove the last digit
        n = Left(n, Len(n) - 1)
        'If the extracted digit is even...
        If e Mod 2 = 0 Then
            'Multiply the rest of the integer by 2 and add 1
            n = n * 2 + 1
        Else
            'Divide the rest of the integer with the extracted digit and add the remainder
            n = Int(n / e) + n Mod e
        End If
        'Keep count
        c = c + 1
    'End the Loop
    Wend
    'Give the output
    Debug.Print (n ; c)
End Sub
```

(Do excuse me, as this is my first post. I will happily edit! Right now, it looks like to test it you open the Immediate Window and type 't n' where n is your number to test :D)

Comment: If you use an inline if statement ( `IIf(..)` ), integer division (`\ `), and change the `n>10` to `n>9`, then you can get this down to an immediate window function worth 97 bytes. `n=[A1]:While n>9:e=Right(n,1):n=Left(n,Len(n)-1):n=IIf(e/2=e\2,n*2+1,n\e+n Mod e):c=c+1:Wend:?n;c`

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 machine code, 35 bytes

```
00000000  31 c9 31 d2 bb 0a 00 f7  f3 85 c0 74 14 f6 c2 01  |1.1........t....|
00000010  75 05 d1 e0 40 e2 eb 89  d3 88 f2 f7 f3 01 d0 e2  |u...@...........|
00000020  e1 f7 d9                                          |...|
00000023
```

Input: `AX = n`
Output: `DX = o`, `CX = r`

Assembled from:

```
        xor cx, cx
next:   xor dx, dx
        mov bx, 10
        div bx
        test ax, ax
        jz done
        test dl, 1
        jnz odd
        shl ax, 1
        inc ax
        loop next
odd:    mov bx, dx
        mov dl, dh
        div bx
        add ax, dx
        loop next
done:   neg cx
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
dd/Sɗ:Ḥ‘ɗḂ?Ƭ⁵ṖṖṪ,LƊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8lRT/45HSrhzuWPGqYcXL6wx1N9sfWPGrc@nDnNDBapeNzrOv///9mhiYG5gA)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 145 bytes

A function which takes the `n` provided and returns the list `(n r)`. Lisp syntax is fun.

```common-lisp
(defun f(n &optional(r 0))(if(< n 10)`(,n,r)(let((h(floor n 10))(l(mod n 10)))(if(evenp l)(f(1+(* 2 h))(1+ r))(f(+(mod h l)(floor h l))(1+ r)))))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site =D

Comment: Thankyou very much, Luis.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 78 bytes

```
f n|n<10=(n,0)|(d,m)<-divMod n 10=(1+)<$>f(last$2*d+1:[div d m+mod d m|odd n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hrybPxtDAViNPx0CzRiNFJ1fTRjcls8w3P0UhTwEkYaitaaNil6aRk1hcomKklaJtaBUNVKCQopCrnQtUBaRr8lOAqmM1/@cmZuYp2Cqk5HMpKBQUZeaVKKgopCmYGZoYmKOImP8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 131 bytes

```
func[n][s: 0 while[n > 9][r: do form take/last t: form n t: do t
n: either r % 2 = 1[t / r +(t % r)][2 * t + 1]s: s + 1]print[n s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xDsIwEAT7vGIbJCBF4giBsASPoD1dEWFbsQhOdD7E842Bbna2GPGu3LwjboIt4ZXulJiyRY/3FGdPCVecmcTCLQiLPKHjw3fzmBVq/yZ9qd7aJAsfdfICwQYDLjCk6Opqt1qN7JgG7KFoYbhm8g9WiUlrKjOXgKM59KfyAQ)

### More readable:

```
f: func [ n ] [
    s: 0
    while [ n > 9 ] [
        r: do form take/last t: form n
        t: do t
        n: either r % 2 = 1
            [ t / r + (t % r) ]
            [ 2 * t + 1 ]
        s: s + 1
    ]
    print [ n s ]
]
```