# Collatz's ice cream cone factory

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, integer, graphical-output

## The Collatz sequence

Given a positive integer \$a_1\$, the [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) with starting value \$a_1\$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} =
\begin{cases}
a_n/2 & \mathrm{if}\ a_n\ \mathrm{is}\ \mathrm{even} \\
3a_n+1 & \mathrm{if}\ a_n\ \mathrm{is}\ \mathrm{odd}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
It is [conjectured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) that, for any starting value, this sequence always reaches the number \$1\$. This challenge assumes that the conjecture is true.

## The challenge

Given an integer \$a_1 > 2\$, compute the Collatz sequence until \$1\$ is reached for the first time. Let \$N\$ be the number of sequence terms (including \$a_1\$ and \$a_N = 1\$). From the sequence of numbers
\begin{equation}
a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_N
\end{equation}
form a sequence of points in the plane by taking all pairs of consecutive terms
\begin{equation}
(a_1, a_2), (a_2, a_3), \ldots, (a_{N-1}, a_N)
\end{equation}
and plot these points on a 2D graph, joining consecutive points by a line segment.

## Example

For input \$12\$ the Collatz sequence is (\$10\$ terms);
\begin{equation}
12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.
\end{equation}
The sequence of points is (\$9\$ points):
\begin{equation}
(12, 6), (6, 3), (3, 10), (10, 5), (5, 16), (16, 8), (8, 4), (4, 2), (2, 1).
\end{equation}
The plot contains \$8\$ line segments, as shown in the following graph. Note that some of the segments partially overlap. For clarity, the plot includes markers at the \$9\$ points.

[image]

## Additional rules

- Graphical output is required, with output being [flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/default-acceptable-image-i-o-methods-for-image-related-challenges) as usual.
- Only the straight lines are required in the graph. Line width is flexible, as long as the plot can be seen reasonably well. Line color is also flexible, and may be different for each segment, as long as lines are distinguishable from the background.
- Other elements in the graph are not required, but are allowed (point markers, grid lines, axis labels, ...).
- Horizontal and vertical axis scales need not be the same. Axis limits are arbitrary, as long as the graph can be seen fully and clearly. The axes may be swapped, and each axis may be reversed.
- The code should work for any input given unlimited resources. It is acceptable if in practice it fails for large inputs due to time, memory or data-type limitations.
- If the input happens to be a counterexample for the Collatz conjecture the code can do anything, such as get stuck in an infinite loop or order a pizza.
- [Programs or functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) are accepted. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `3` | [image] |
| `4` | [image] |
| `27` | [image] |
| `649` | [image] |
| `650` | [image] |
| `46720` | [image] |
| `345435` | [image] |
| `63728127` | [image] |

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture-oeis-a006577)

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: Is an upside down y axis allowed?

Comment: @Nick Yes, no problem

Comment: "If the Collatz conjecture is false the code can do anything, such as get stuck in an infinite loop or order a pizza." – I guess you want to say "If you hit a counter example for the Collatz conjecture, ..."

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yes, you are right. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
r0×€:⁸
×3‘ƊHḂ?Ƭ;Ɲ_/AÞṪçƊ+ṪƲƝẎŒṬx€€3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/I4PD0R01rrB417uA6PN34UcOMY10eD3c02R9bY31sbry@4@F5D3euOrz8WJc2kD626djch7v6jk56uHNNBVAbEBn////fyAgA)

A pair of links that takes an integer argument and returns an RGB matrix on the (0 to 1) scale. Approach is the same as PBM output below but loses some bytes from the simpler output format.

---

## Previous PBM answer [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>49</s> 44 bytes

```
r0×€:⁸
×3‘ƊHḂ?Ƭ;Ɲ_/AÞṪçƊ+ṪƲƝẎŒṬµZL;L;FKṭ“P1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9qZWxsef//cjDDl@KCrDrigbgKw5cz4oCYxopI4biCP8asO8adXy9Bw57huarDp8aKK@G5qsayxp3huo7FkuG5rMK1Wkw7TDtGS@G5reKAnFAxIP///zIy)

A full program that takes an integer argument and prints the contents of a PBM file.

Thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing for some nice golfs totally 5 bytes!

### Example for 22:

[image: Example image for 22]

---

## Original SVG-based answer: [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 83 bytes

```
×3‘ƊHḂ?Ị¬$Ð¿µj”,$ƝKṭṀ,`$“¡×ȯFṗẓ"az⁺Ṭ*,ġẎlḣḂ⁷Ọ]Ẏɦ?÷hṖF.IØṣƘŻÇÄ<,Ḥ:ẆṡṂȮXȷḷ[eʂmJ]»Ỵ¤;"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AagAV/9qZWxsef//w5cz4oCYxopI4biCP@G7isKsJMOQwr/CtWrigJ0sJMadS@G5reG5gCxgJOKAnMKhw5fIr0bhuZfhupMiYXrigbrhuawqLMSh4bqObOG4o@G4guKBt@G7jF3huo7Jpj/Dt2jhuZZGLknDmOG5o8aYxbvDh8OEPCzhuKQ64bqG4bmh4bmCyK5YyLfhuLdbZcqCbUpdwrvhu7TCpDsi////NDU)

A full program taking an integer argument and printing an SVG.

For example, with 45:

```
<svg width="136" height="136"><path stroke="red" fill="none" d="M45,136 136,68 68,34 34,17 17,52 52,26 26,13 13,40 40,20 20,10 10,5 5,16 16,8 8,4 4,2 2,1"/></svg>
```

[image: Example SVG]

Comment: is upside-down y axis allowed?

Comment: Yes, it is (I just included it in the challenge)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//cjDDl@KCrDrigbgKw5cz4oCYxopI4biCP@G4isOQwr87xp1fL0HDnuG5qsOnxoor4bmqxrLGneG6jsWS4bmswrVaTDtMO0ZL4bmt4oCcUDEg////MjI)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##AVgAp/9qZWxsef//cjDDl@KCrDrigbgKw5cz4oCYxopI4biCP8asO8adXy9Bw57huarDp8aKK@G5qsayxp3huo7FkuG5rMK1Wkw7TDtGS@G5reKAnFAxIP///zIy) if we can assume the Collatz conjecture is true (which we can)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks! Yes of course. We have to assume the conjecture is true either way but I’d missed the fact that the input will always be >2 and so the only path to 1 goes via 4, 2, 1 and prevents a bounce back up to 4.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/) with turtle, <s>156</s> 127 bytes

Thanks to [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9) for catching a mistake!

```python
from turtle import*
def f(n,x=0):
 while~-n:goto(w:=n,n:=[n//2,3*n+1][n%2]);x<1!=clear();setworldcoordinates(0,0,x:=max(x,n),x)
```

Animation for \$a_1=27\$:

[image: animation of turtle for testcase 27]

Comment: It may just be my computer, but get weird outputs for \$3\$, \$4\$, and \$650\$. Also doesn't clear the screen in between runs.

Comment: @Noodle9 I thought `setworldcoordinates` would clear the screen, but apparently this isn't the case. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/5eRdqYY) are my outputs for 3, 4 and 650. For 3 and 4 there is a lot of padding to the bottom/left, but I think this is fine with the rule *Axis limits are arbitrary, as long as the graph can be seen fully and clearly*

Comment: Makes sense, also \$650\$ looks fine now.

Comment: Yes, no problem with padding

Answer (score 9):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 52 bytes

```
load 'plot'
f=:[:plot[:(}:;}.)(2&|{-:,1+*&3)^:(>&1)^:a:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/Pyc/MUVBvSAnv0SdK83WKtoKxIy20qi1sq7V09QwUqup1rXSMdTWUjPWjLPSsFMzBFKJVv//AwA)

Wasn't sure if loading the graphics lib counted towards byte count, so I included it.

Here's an image of calling `f 27` in the J console:

[image: 27]

Comment: Yes, you have to include any needed loads/imports/includes in the byte count, that's one of the big challenges golfing in Python.

Comment: Is the TIO link any use in this case?

Comment: Not much.  I mostly used it to count for me.  But you could delete `[:plot` and run it to verify that it was producing the correct x and y coord lists.

Comment: Is the `f=:` necessary? Can you not just have an anonymous function?

Comment: @caird I'm not counting those 3 bytes.  I just wanted it to be clear how it's intended to be used, ie, calling it like `f 27`.  If it were anonymous it would need parens around it to be called like that.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) >= 4.1, <s>81</s> 74 bytes

```r
\(x,y=x){while(x>1)y=c(y,x<-c(x/2,3*x+1)[x%%2+1]);plot(y,c(y[-1],NA),"l")}
```

[Try it at RDRR.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%20%3C-%20function(x%2Cy%3Dx)%7Bwhile(x%3E1)y%3Dc(y%2Cx%3C-c(x%2F2%2C3*x%2B1)%5Bx%25%252%2B1%5D)%3Bplot(y%2Cc(y%5B-1%5D%2CNA)%2C%22l%22)%7D%0Af(45))

Note this uses RDRR because TIO doesn’t support graphical output. It also uses `function` in place of `\` since RDRR doesn’t support R 4.1.0 yet.

Thanks to @DominicVanEssen for saving 7 bytes!

Comment: [74 bytes](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%20%3C-%0Afunction(x%2Cy%3Dx)%7Bwhile(x%3E1)y%3Dc(y%2Cx%3C-c(x%2F2%2C3*x%2B1)%5Bx%25%252%2B1%5D)%3Bplot(y%2Cc(y%5B-1%5D%2CNA)%2C%22l%22)%7D%0Af(45)) - ```\(x,y=x){while(x>1)y=c(y,x<-c(x/2,3*x+1)[x%%2+1]);plot(y,c(y[-1],NA),"l")}```

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 70 bytes

```
Graphics@Line@Last@Reap[#//.a_/;a>1:>Last@Sow@{a,If[2∣a,a/2,3a+1]}]&
```

-17 bytes from @att

`63728127`
[image]

Comment: `Graphics@Line@Partition[NestWhileList[If[OddQ@#,3#+1,#/2]&,#,#>1&],2,1]&` for 72

Comment: Another -1: `Graphics@Line@Partition[NestWhileList[If[2∣#,#/2,3#+1]&,#,#>1&],2,1]&`

Comment: 70 with `Sow`/`Reap`: `Graphics@Line@Last@Reap[#//.a_/;a>1:>Last@Sow@{a,If[2∣a,a/2,3a+1]}]&`

Answer (score 6):

## Julia using GR, <strike>121</strike> <strike>99</strike> 77 bytes

Even better version by @MarcMush:

```
using GR
!x=while(X=x[end])>1 plot([x;],(x=[x;X%2>0 ? 3X+1 : X/2])[2:end])end
```

Improved version thanks to the tips found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia):

```
using GR
c(a)=(i=1;while a[i]>1 a=[a;%(a[i],2)>0 ? 3a[i]+1 : a[i]/2];i+=1end;plot(a[1:i-1],a[2:i]))
```

What has been done:

- single-line notation for functions -10 bytes
- replace `push!` by array concatenation -3 bytes
- use input `a` as array - 6 bytes
- replace `end` by variable `i` that stores the length -3 bytes

Original version:

```
using GR
function c(x) a=[x]
while a[end]>1 push!(a,%(a[end],2)>0 ? 3a[end]+1 : a[end]/2)end
plot(a[1:end-1],a[2:end])end
```

Calling `c(27)` gives:
[image]

Comment: nice first answer! check out [Tips for golfing in Julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/tips-for-golfing-in-julia), you can reduce your answer a bit more

Comment: my turn to shave off 22 bytes ;) [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v7Q4My9dwT2IS7HCtjwjMydVI8K2Ijo1LyVW085QoSAnv0QjusI6VkejwhZIR6ga2Rko2CsYR2gbKlgpROgbxWpGG1mBlQOJ//8B "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: Wow, that's amazing what you did there ... seams like there is still a lot to learn then :D

Comment: feel free to include my improvements in your answer and to continue improving it

Answer (score 4):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/), <sup><s>81</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>74</s></sup> 71 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!

```python
f=lambda n,*r:n-1and f(c:=[n/2,3*n+1][n%2],*r,(n,c))or list_plot(r,1<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwFwUEKgCAQAMC7r_ASaG2EK1RIvkQkTBECW8P8P81kW8JzpcAJmnXe0KwCJZ5FNNbRgqBHmpR3NKCHNjlBEKWXtfFyf_18S-2igTpQMpbFqjfcFW7yB5BhGQ4=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

#### f(63728127)

[image: f(63728127)]

Comment: [71 bytes](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTI09EqssrTNUzMS1FI00i2so3O0zfSMdbK0zaMjc5TNYoFyuto5Okka2rmFynkZBaXxBfk5JdoFOkY2hhpcnGlaZgZmxtZGBqZawIAKicXtg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: @dingledooper Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <sup><s>230</s></sup> 212 bytes

```
func[n][a: to[]n while[n > 1][append a n: either odd? n[3 * n + 1][n / 2]]to-pair m: last sort copy a view[base 500x500 draw append[line]collect[while[a/2][keep as-pair a/1 / m * 500(first a: next a)/ m * 500]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BasQwDETv/Yo5dreUbFJ6yaH7D70KH9RYIaZe2TjuJv16VyWwAiEYaeapiG@f4sk9zW3@0YnUEY@oiZxiW0IUUnygNzVnUQ@GjpBQFylI3l@h9IYzFC//R4oOg3M1vWYOBbcRkdeKNZWKKeVfs9@DbPTFq@D9ctmt4QtvOOIpBhU3pRhlqnTwuRscfYtk8HrEctcb52ZYsz/PoRjCnlbZbZ4eG2fV2h8)

I don't know if red has a scalable plotting mechanism, but this was what I managed to get using the draw dialect. All outputs are scaled to 500x500 and there may be some inaccuracies for larger inputs due to downscaling and pairs being integers.

In the red interpreter, you will have to redefine the function before each run because the words get messed up.

-4 after using default axes.

-18 bytes from Galen Ivanov.

### Output(n=12) (old)

[image]

Comment: I cleaned up you code a little for [-18 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7BasQwDETv/Yo5dreUbFJ6yaH7D70KH9RYIaZe2TjuJv16VyWwAiEYaeapiG@f4sk9zW3@0YnUEY@oiZxiW0IUUnygNzVnUQ@GjpBQFylI3l@h9IYzFC//R4oOg3M1vWYOBbcRkdeKNZWKKeVfs9@DbPTFq@D9ctmt4QtvOOIpBhU3pRhlqnTwuRscfYtk8HrEctcb52ZYsz/PoRjCnlbZbZ4eG2fV2h8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `ui.gadgets.charts ui.gadgets.charts.lines math.unicode`, <sup><s>208</s> <s>204</s></sup> 199 bytes

```
[ [ [ 3 dupn , odd? [ 3 * 1 + ] [ 2/ ] if dup 1 ≠ ] loop , ] f make chart new over supremum 1 + '[ 0 _ ] dup 2array >>axes line new COLOR: red >>color rot 2 clump >>data add-gadget "" open-window ]
```

It's quotation (anonymous function) that accepts an integer from the data stack and opens a window with the chart in it. This only works in recent-ish builds of Factor, as the `chart` gadget is fairly new; I used build `2074`. Here's what it looks like for an input of `27`:

[image]

Unfortunately, the `chart` gadget doesn't come with any constructors. It requires us to manually calculate axes, and build its subcomponents which themselves don't come with any constructors. This leads to a bit of verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + matplotlib, 127 bytes

```python
def f(n,r=[]):
 k=n
 while ~-n:n=[n//2,3*n+1][n%2];r+=[n]
 p.plot(*zip(*[[k]+r,r]),'-o');p.show()
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
```

-5 bytes thanks to @ovs!!!

Comment: If you use `n//2` instead of `n/2`, you don't need to convert `n%2` to an integer and the loop condition can be changed to `~-n`.

Comment: And [`pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) can take x and y coordinates separately, so `p.plot([k]+r,r[:-1],'-o')` should work (I didn't test that)

Comment: @ovs thanks for the tips!!

Comment: Remove the space between while and ~. Maybe [[k,*r],r]?

Answer (score 3):

## HTML + JS, 166 bytes

JS: 156 bytes

HTML: 14 bytes

This is a pretty basic implementation that renders to the DOM using an HTML canvas. A good chunk of the code is spent scaling the output to fit within the canvas. Anyone got any better ideas to handle this?

The input is specified inline in the code, set the number inside `x=[...]`.

```js
x=[9];c=C.getContext`2d`;c.beginPath();while((z=x[0])-1)x.unshift(z%2?3*z+1:z/2);r=Math.max(...x)/99;x.map((a,i)=>c.lineTo(a/r,99-x[i-1]/r));c.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

Comment: -14: `c.beginPath();` is useless here, a path is started automatically at context's init. Now, it's unclear how your script is embedded in the HTML here, so take a +8 for `<script>` after the canvas opening tag and you end with 160. (Note that in the snippet you'd also need a </script> end tag, but I think it's not necessary if there is a true EOF, I'm on a phone rn and can't test myself.)

Comment: A snippet may not be valid in which case your best bet may be a function which takes `a` and a canvas element as input and outputs by drawing on the passed-in canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido I/O needs to be an image. A 2d context isn't itself an image.

Comment: (A typed array of RGB values would be OK though; that counts as an image.)

Comment: @Kaiido There are two rules at play here: 1) functions that produce output may do so by writing to an (optionally additional) input rather than producing a return value 2) an image object is an acceptable i/o format (see the list of acceptable graphical i/o formats linked in the question).

Comment: Alright, then if taking their input inside an Array is also legal, I guess it's 140: `(x,C)=>{c=C.getContext\`2d\`;while((z=x[0])-1)x.unshift(z%2?3*z+1:z/2),r=Math.max(...x)/99,x.map((a,i)=>c.lineTo(a/r,99-x[i-1]/r));c.stroke()}` with `x` being the integer input wrapped in an Array, and `C` an HTML canvas.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB 1999, <s>95</s> 84 bytes

-1 from Luis Mendo

```
n=input('');i=n;while i>1;i=(i+mod(i,2)*(5*i+2))/2;n=[n;i];end;plot([0/0;n],[n;0/0])
```

[image]

Even `A(2:)` and A(2:-1)` was unavailable at that time...

Comment: You can shorten `while(i>1)` to `while i>1`

Answer (score 1):

## Python + Pygame, 228 bytes

```py
from pygame import*
d=display
n=int(input())
k=[]
while n>1:k+=[[n,n:=[n//2,3*n+1][n%2]]]
M=max(k)[0]
S=500
g=lambda s:[S*s[0]/M,S*s[1]/M]
s=d.set_mode([S,S])
for i,j in enumerate(k):draw.line(s,[99]*3,g(k[i-1]),g(j))
d.update()
```

No TIO link because Pygame is not supported there.

Reversed y-axis.

I could save one byte by setting `S` to 99 or something, but I chose not to for easier viewing. I could also change `[99]*3` to `[9]*3` but I chose not to for easier viewing.

Here is an example for input 63728127:
[image: Example]